# How to globally tikzset styles

Tags: tikz-pgf, grouping, tikz-styles

I would like to set a `tikzstyle` from within a `tabular` environment, and use it after the table.  Adding the usual `\global` seems to have no effect.  The MWE below produces:

[image]

but I want the last line to be red not blue.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{MyStyle/.style={}}%

\newcommand*{\MyTikzPicture}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [MyStyle] (0,0) -- (2,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}%

\begin{document}
\MyTikzPicture

\tikzset{MyStyle/.style={ultra thick, blue}}%
\MyTikzPicture

\begin{tabular}{r l}
  a & b  \global\tikzset{MyStyle/.style={ultra thick, red}}
\end{tabular}

\MyTikzPicture
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I want to switch my comment to an answer.

First of all the command `tikzset` based on the package `pgfkeys`. To show the definition of the command you can use the following code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\expandafter\detokenize\expandafter{\tikzset}
\end{document}
```

The result of this small example is:

```
\pgfqkeys{/tikz}
```

Based on this information you can use a similar construct as shown in the question: [Is there a way to set a *global* key value using `pgfkeys`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15204/is-there-a-way-to-set-a-global-key-value-using-pgfkeys)

The trick based on the command `\globaldefs`. In the TeX Book at page 286 you can find the following hint:

> Incidentally, if the `\globaldefs` parameter is positive at the time of
>   the assignment, a prefix of `\global` is automatically implied; but if
>   `\globaldefs` is negative at the time of the assignment, a prefix of
>   `\global` is ignored. If `\globaldefs` is zero (which it usually is), the
>   appearance or nonappearance of `\global` determines whether or not a
>   global assignment is made.
>   In short:
>   default: `\globaldefs=0`

- `=0` The assignment is global if the prefix `\global` is used.
- `<0` All assignments are local and `\global` will be ignored.
- `>0` All assignments are global.

Based on the previous information you can create your own command:

```
\newcommand\gtikzset[1]{%
\begingroup%
 \globaldefs=1\relax%
 \pgfqkeys{/tikz}{#1}%
\endgroup%
}
```

The extra grouping is necessary to hold the definition of `\globaldefs` local.

Here the complete example:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{MyStyle/.style={}}%

\newcommand*{\MyTikzPicture}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [MyStyle] (0,0) -- (2,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}%

\newcommand\gtikzset[1]{%
\begingroup%
 \globaldefs=1\relax%
 \pgfqkeys{/tikz}{#1}%
\endgroup%
}
\begin{document}
\MyTikzPicture

\tikzset{MyStyle/.style={ultra thick, blue}}%
\MyTikzPicture

\begin{tabular}{r l}
  a & b  \gtikzset{MyStyle/.style={ultra thick, red}}
\end{tabular}

\MyTikzPicture
\end{document}
```

After this you get a last red line:

[image]

Comment: Yep, works. But don't think the `\begingroup`, `\endgroup` is necessary as I believe that there is already an implied grouping.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Have you seen the example that demostrate the necessary group.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Why does `\gtikzset` have to use `\pgfqkeys` and not directly `\tikzset`? Is it important to check what `\tikzset` is doing while not checking what `\pgfqkeys` is??

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/653795/access-pgfkeys-outside-environment#comment1629450_653797