# Tikz Timing change signal height of one signal

Tags: tikz-timing, timing-diagrams

I am currently drawing a timing diagramm and need to change the signal heigth of one signal. Is there a mechanism in tikz timing to do so?

This is my timing diagramm/ my minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\begin{document}
\scalebox{1.5}{%
\begin{tikztimingtable}
    clk & 29{c} \\
    data\_in & 0.1l [[timing/slope=0.7]]hhhhllllllhhhhhlllll 0.4lhhhhlllll\\
    error & lllhhhhhhhhllhhhhhhh hllhhhhhh\\
    error\_reg & lllllhhhhhhhhllhhhhh hhhllhhhh\\
    data & lhhhhhhllllhhhhhhlll lllhhhhll\\
    data\_reg & lllhhhhhhllllhhhhhhl lllllhhhh\\
    early & lllllllllllhhlllllll lllllllll\\
    late & llllllllllllllllllll lllhhllll\\
    \extracode
    \makeatletter
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \begin{scope}[gray,semitransparent,semithick]
            \foreach \x in {0.5,...,14.5}
                \draw (\x,1) -- (\x,-14);
            \draw(0,-1.1) -- (16,-1.1);
            \draw(0,-1.9) -- (16,-1.9);
            \node [anchor=south east,inner sep=0pt]
                at (18,-1.4) {\tiny Vrefp};
            \node [anchor= south east,inner sep=0pt]
                at (18,-2.2) {\tiny Vrefn};
        \end{scope}
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikztimingtable}
}%
\end{document}
```

The output looks like this, I want the data_in signal twice as high but all other signals should stay as they are:

[image: Resulting output]

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example?

Comment: Updated the example...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I use `y=2\yunit` to double the height of the `data\_in` row as desired.

The tricky part is handling the spacing. The problem is that by the time the next row is created (using the internal representation of `rowdist` as a skip amount), any key settings done in the previous row are out of scope.

Conversely, by the time the key settings in the current row are executed, the current row has already been placed with the old `rowdist`, which gives the wrong spacing.

In this solution, I use a global key setting macro `\gtikzset` as defined in the accepted answer to [How to globally tikzset styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47905/21344). This is used to globally set `timing/rowdist=3` at the end of the first row, which causes the second row to be created at the right spot. Then, at the beginning of the second row, I globally reset it to the original value, `timing/rowdist=2` which holds for the rest of the table.

Other notes about your code:

- `\vertlines` is provided by `tikz-timing` to place vertical grid lines, it can replace your `\foreach` loop for those.
- Instead of manually positioning your annotations, you can use the named nodes   provided by `tikz-timing` so you don't have to update them whenever the drawing changes. So

  ```
  \draw(0,-1.1) -- (16,-1.1);
  \draw(0,-1.9) -- (16,-1.9);
  \node [anchor=south east,inner sep=0pt]
      at (18,-1.4) {\tiny Vrefp};
  \node [anchor= south east,inner sep=0pt]
      at (18,-2.2) {\tiny Vrefn};
  ```

  becomes

  ```
  \draw (row2.high start) ++(0,-0.1) -- ++(16,0) node {Vrefp};
  \draw (row2.low start)  ++(0, 0.1) -- ++(16,0) node {Vrefn};
  ```

  where I have also specified `\tiny` as the `font` key within the scope.

Here's the complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\newcommand\gtikzset[1]{%
\begingroup%
 \globaldefs=1\relax%
 \pgfqkeys{/tikz}{#1}%
\endgroup}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikztimingtable}
  clk        & 29{c}@{\gtikzset{timing/rowdist=3}}\\
  data\_in   & @{\gtikzset{timing/rowdist=2}}[y=2\yunit]0.1l 
                 [[timing/slope=0.7]]hhhhllllllhhhhhlllll 0.4lhhhhlllll\\
  error      & lllhhhhhhhhllhhhhhhh hllhhhhhh\\
  error\_reg & lllllhhhhhhhhllhhhhh hhhllhhhh\\
  data       & lhhhhhhllllhhhhhhlll lllhhhhll\\
  data\_reg  & lllhhhhhhllllhhhhhhl lllllhhhh\\
  early      & lllllllllllhhlllllll lllllllll\\
  late       & llllllllllllllllllll lllhhllll\\
  \extracode \background
  \begin{scope}[gray,semitransparent,semithick,node font=\tiny,anchor=west]
    \vertlines{0.5,...,\twidth}
    \draw (row2.high start) ++(0,-0.1) -- ++(16,0) node {Vrefp};
    \draw (row2.low start)  ++(0, 0.1) -- ++(16,0) node {Vrefn};
  \end{scope}
  \endbackground
\end{tikztimingtable}
\end{document}
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: If the package author reads this answer: it might be nice to implement `\\[<extra-skip-amt>]` to make this adjustment easier in the rare case it needs to be done.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but is it enough to just add `yscale=2` to the relevant line?

```
 data\_in & 0.1l [[timing/slope=0.7,yscale=1.8]]hhhhllllllhhhhhlllll
```

This produces:

[image]

If the `date\_in` line shouldn't run into ythe `clk` line the changing this is `yscale=1.8` separates them, but then it is perhaps not quite what you want...

The full code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\begin{document}
\scalebox{1.5}{%
\begin{tikztimingtable}
    clk & 29{c} \\
    data\_in & 0.1l [[timing/slope=0.7,yscale=2]]hhhhllllllhhhhhlllll
    0.4lhhhhlllll\\
    error & lllhhhhhhhhllhhhhhhh hllhhhhhh\\
    error\_reg & lllllhhhhhhhhllhhhhh hhhllhhhh\\
    data & lhhhhhhllllhhhhhhlll lllhhhhll\\
    data\_reg & lllhhhhhhllllhhhhhhl lllllhhhh\\
    early & lllllllllllhhlllllll lllllllll\\
    late & llllllllllllllllllll lllhhllll\\
    \extracode
    \makeatletter
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \begin{scope}[gray,semitransparent,semithick]
            \foreach \x in {0.5,...,14.5}
                \draw (\x,1) -- (\x,-14);
            \draw(0,-1.1) -- (16,-1.1);
            \draw(0,-1.9) -- (16,-1.9);
            \node [anchor=south east,inner sep=0pt]
                at (18,-1.4) {\tiny Vrefp};
            \node [anchor= south east,inner sep=0pt]
                at (18,-2.2) {\tiny Vrefn};
        \end{scope}
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikztimingtable}
}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this is a first approach in the right direction. The main problem now is that the spacing between clk and data_in is not correct...

Comment: @TM90 What should the spacing look like?

Comment: Basically exactly like the spacings between the other unmodified signals

Answer (score 0):

Distance can be changed by adding this short piece of code to the preamble....

```
\makeatletter
    \def\tikztiming@rowdist{3}%
\makeatother
```

Comment: But this would apply to every row or am I misunderstanding this solution?

Comment: You are absolut right. But in this case the space of each row is identically. Sure, the distance between the rows is unequal...

Comment: For me as mentioned the spacing between the signals is important.

Comment: You can also do this with `\begin{tikztimingtable}[timing/rowdist=3]...`. The manual suggests that one should be able to add `timing/rowdist=3` into the row specifications but this doesn't have any effect:(