# Access pgfkeys outside environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, environments, pgfkeys, scoping

I find that the value of a key defined by `\pgfkeys` inside an `environment` can not be invoked outside this environment.

In the following example, I want to typeset the value of the key `aaa` outside the environment `minipage` and fail.

How to make this kind of keys be "seen" outside environment?

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{1.0\linewidth}
  \pgfkeys{aaa/.initial=aaa,bbb/.initial=bbb}
  Inside minipage, the value of the key "aaa" is \pgfkeysvalueof{/aaa}
\end{minipage}
Outside minipage, the value of the key "aaa" is |\pgfkeysvalueof{/aaa}|

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is due to scoping. You will get the same effect with using `\def` inside the `minipage`.

Comment: Is this correct for all environment? I mean scoping.

Comment: In general, yes, since virually all environments use scoping. But scoping is a very basic thing: You will aready get an error if you try `{\def\hello{hello}} \hello`. In your case, you would need to assign the key gloablly (or outside of the scope). See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15204/47927

Comment: @lyl Yes, all(*) LaTeX environments form a group. (* `document` avoids a group for technical reasons, but as the LaTeX run ends with `\end{document}` is this not really an issue.)

Comment: Currently `pgfkeys` has no provisions to set keys globally. It is recommended to instead move the keys definition to the global scope (usually the document preamble).

Comment: I suggest either the "hack" adding global handlers like [in the answer by Qrrbrbirlbel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/653809/117050), or use another key=value implementation that supports global assignments out of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the other answer and comments explain why your code behaves the way it does, here's a `.ginitial` handler that *is* global.

That means that both the initialization `aaa/.ginitial = aaa` as well as just assigning a new value via `aaa = AAA` will be global.

However, the handlers `.add`, `.prefix`, `.append`, `.get` and `.link` will not change the value globally.
(We'll need `.gadd`, `.gprefix`, … for that.)

In the code below, the key `/bbb` remains local.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\long\def\pgfkeysgdef#1#2{%
  \long\def\pgfkeys@temp##1\pgfeov{#2}%
  \pgfkeysglet{#1/.@cmd}{\pgfkeys@temp}%
  \pgfkeyssetgvalue{#1/.@body}{#2}%
}
\long\def\pgfkeysglet#1#2{%
  \expandafter\global\expandafter\let\csname pgfk@#1\endcsname#2%
}
\long\def\pgfkeyssetgvalue#1#2{%
  \pgfkeys@temptoks{#2}\expandafter\xdef\csname pgfk@#1\endcsname{\the\pgfkeys@temptoks}%
}
\pgfkeys{
  /handlers/.ginitial/.code=%
    \edef\pgfkeys@temp{% \pgfkeysgdef is basically /.gcode
      \noexpand\pgfkeysgdef{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}%
        {\noexpand\pgfkeyssetgvalue{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}{####1}}}%
    \pgfkeys@temp
    \pgfkeyssetgvalue{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}{#1}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{1.0\linewidth}
\pgfkeys{aaa/.ginitial = aaa, bbb/.initial = bbb, aaa = AAA}
Inside minipage, the values of the keys --/aaa--/bbb-- are --\pgfkeysvalueof{/aaa}--\pgfkeysvalueof{/bbb}--
\end{minipage}
Outside minipage, the values of the key --/aaa--/bbb-- are --\pgfkeysvalueof{/aaa}--\pgfkeysvalueof{/bbb}--
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: That said, the point and power of PGFkeys is to only have keys/styles be local. Maybe there's a better solution if we'd know the real world application.

Answer (score 1):

Due to scoping, the keys you set inside the `minipage` are only defined inside this environment. Therefore, you would need to define the key outside of the environment or define it gobally somehow.

You could apply the approach in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47918/47927) and create a global version of the `\pgfkeys` macro. However, this approach is probably risky because everything `\pgfkeys` does internally will be global. This may lead to unintended results in certain cases and break other code (thanks to Skillmon and David Carlisle for pointing to this).

For very simple assignments, you could maybe also use `\global\pgfkeyslet`, but using this approach, things like `.initial` would not be applicable. Also, the same warning as above applies here. So, do not use this if you plan to have others use your code!

I'd recommend, therefore, to restructure the logic of your document and define the keys outside of the environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

%%% not recoomended!
\newcommand\gpgfkeys[1]{%
\begingroup%
 \globaldefs=1\relax%
 \pgfkeys{#1}%
\endgroup%
}
%%%

\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{aaa/.initial=aaa}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{1.0\linewidth}
  
  \def\mybbbkey{bbb}                   %%%
  \global\pgfkeyslet{/bbb}{\mybbbkey}  %%% 
                                       %%%
  \gpgfkeys{ccc/.initial=ccc}          %%% not recommended!
  
  Inside minipage, the value of the key "aaa" is \pgfkeysvalueof{/aaa} \\
  Inside minipage, the value of the key "aaa" is \pgfkeysvalueof{/bbb} \\
  Inside minipage, the value of the key "ccc" is \pgfkeysvalueof{/ccc}
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\noindent
Outside minipage, the value of the key "aaa" is ---\pgfkeysvalueof{/aaa}--- \\
Outside minipage, the value of the key "bbb" is ---\pgfkeysvalueof{/bbb}--- \\
Outside minipage, the value of the key "ccc" is ---\pgfkeysvalueof{/ccc}---

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd not recommend switching on `\globaldefs` on code you haven't completely written yourself and have not absolute control over!

Comment: @Skillmon Wouldn't your concerns then also apply to the linked answer?

Comment: pgfkeys makes hundreds of internal definitions parsing the structure and this makes all of them global, it might work in some cases but only accidentally, and it may break arbitrary other code with global settings to interal registers.

Comment: Yes comments apply to that answer too

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Would `\global\pgfkeyslet` be a better way then?

Comment: that would make the top level macro holding the key global but if the key has any additional structure or properties such as .initial, they would still be local

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok, thank you! I updated my answer to include a warning.

Comment: I'd have made the warning stronger, "do not use this in production" for example. `\global\pgfkeyslet` is like `\global\newcommand` if it ever does what you expect either your are very lucky or you know every line of code executed and your expectations are acurate