# Arrows underneath numbers (Part 2 question)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need the code for arrows underneath numbers going in the right direction. I've looked up the commands online and all I have `\uarrow` which goes to the left and not right.:

[image]

Thank you Hendrik. My problem is solved!

Comment: Have you tried replacing `\curvearrowbotleft` with `\curvearrowbotright` in the [code you've got](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97498)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous solution at [Getting arrows underneath numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97470/getting-arrows-underneath-numbers/97508#97508) allows one to provide options to the `\DrawArrow` which you can use to reverse the direction of the arrow. You could either change the arrow style for all subsequent `\DrawArrow` calls from:

```
\tikzset{BottomArrowStyle/.style={thin, -stealth}}
```

where the `-stealth` option draws a `stealth` style arrow from left to right, to

```
\tikzset{BottomArrowStyle/.style={thin, stealth-}}
```

which draws the arrow from right to left as shown in the first line on the right hand side.

Alternatively, you could specify `<-` for each `\DrawArrow` so you can then mix and match as desired the direction, as shown by the right hand side of the second line, where the `olive` and `magenta` are drawn in opposite directions. Not that I think you want to do this, but rather to illustrate its use.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


%% Set these if you want to globally atler the arrow styles
%% for the top and bottom arrows.
\tikzset{TopArrowStyle/.style={}}%
\tikzset{BottomArrowStyle/.style={}}%


\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline] \node [anchor=base] (#1) {\phantom{#2}};#2%
}

\newcommand*{\XShift}{0.5ex}%
\newcommand*{\ArcDistance}{0.075cm}%
\newcommand*{\OutAngle}{}%
\newcommand*{\InAngle}{}%
\newcommand*{\AnchorPoint}{}%
\newcommand*{\ShortenBegin}{}%
\newcommand*{\ShortenEnd}{}%
%
\NewDocumentCommand{\DrawArrow}{s O{} m m}{%
    \IfBooleanTF {#1} {% starred variant - draw arrows below
        \renewcommand*{\OutAngle}{-95}%
        \renewcommand*{\InAngle}{-85}%
        \renewcommand*{\AnchorPoint}{south}%
        \renewcommand*{\ShortenBegin}{-3.5pt}%
        \renewcommand*{\ShortenEnd}{-3.5pt}%
        \tikzset{Arrow Style/.style={BottomArrowStyle}}%
    }{% non-starred - draw arrows above
        \renewcommand*{\OutAngle}{95}%
        \renewcommand*{\InAngle}{85}%
        \renewcommand*{\AnchorPoint}{north}%
        \renewcommand*{\ShortenBegin}{-3.5pt}%
        \renewcommand*{\ShortenEnd}{-3.5pt}%
        \tikzset{Arrow Style/.style={TopArrowStyle}}%
    }%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \draw[
                ->, thick, distance=\ArcDistance,
                shorten <=\ShortenBegin, shorten >=\ShortenEnd,
                out=\OutAngle, in=\InAngle, Arrow Style, #2
            ] 
                ($(#3.\AnchorPoint)+(2.0*\XShift,0)$) to 
                ($(#4.\AnchorPoint)+(0.4*\XShift,0)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{BottomArrowStyle/.style={thin, -stealth}}% change arrow style
10.\tikzmark{Three}{5}\tikzmark{Two}{6}\tikzmark{One}{6}%
\DrawArrow*[red]{One}{One}%
\DrawArrow*[brown]{Two}{Two}%
\DrawArrow*[blue]{Three}{Three}%
%
\hspace*{0.25cm}%
%
\tikzset{BottomArrowStyle/.style={thin, stealth-}}% change arrow style
10.\tikzmark{Three}{5}\tikzmark{Two}{6}\tikzmark{One}{6}%
\DrawArrow*[olive]{One}{One}%
\DrawArrow*[green]{Two}{Two}%
\DrawArrow*[magenta]{Three}{Three}%
\tikzset{BottomArrowStyle/.style={}}% restore to default

\bigskip
10.\tikzmark{ThreeB}{5}\tikzmark{TwoB}{6}\tikzmark{OneB}{6}%
\DrawArrow*[red]{OneB}{OneB}%
\DrawArrow[brown]{TwoB}{TwoB}%
\DrawArrow*[blue]{ThreeB}{ThreeB}%
%
\hspace*{0.25cm}%
%
10.\tikzmark{ThreeB}{5}\tikzmark{TwoB}{6}\tikzmark{OneB}{6}%
\DrawArrow*[olive,<-]{OneB}{OneB}%
\DrawArrow[green,<-]{TwoB}{TwoB}%
\DrawArrow*[magenta,->]{ThreeB}{ThreeB}%

\bigskip
10.\tikzmark{Three}{5}\tikzmark{Two}{6}\tikzmark{One}{6}%
\DrawArrow*[red,in=-85, out=-95, distance=0.2cm]{One}{Three}%
%
\hspace*{0.25cm}%
%
10.\tikzmark{Three}{5}\tikzmark{Two}{6}\tikzmark{One}{6}%
\DrawArrow*[magenta,in=-85, out=-95, distance=0.2cm, <-]{One}{Three}%
\end{document}
```