# Add a curved arrow and a bracket to a table

Tags: tables

I'm a beginner to LaTeX. I want to add a curved arrow pointing from one row to another. And I also want to add a `{` on the other side of the table to mark several rows.

```
\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{ | l | l |}
  \hline
   letter & number \\ \hline
   A &  1 \\ \hline
   A &  2 \\ \hline
   A &  1 \\ \hline
   B &  1 \\ \hline
   B &  2 \\ \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

So my idea is to add a curved arrow outside the table to mark the first line and the third line as "duplicated" on the right and add two `{` to mark the first 3 rows as "A" and the last 2 rows as "B" on the left.

Any suggestion on how can I do it?

Comment: There are many questions that tackles this on this site. You can search for `math tikzmark [tikz-pgf]` on the top right corner. An example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47610/how-to-draw-arrows-from-cell-to-cell-at-the-borders-of-a-table

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As percusse said in his comment, the most convenient way to go is to exploit the `tikzmark` macro (just one reference: [Adding a large brace next to a body of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1570/13304)).

This solution allows to draw both braces and arrows through:

1. `\drawbrace` command;
2. `\drawcurvedarrow` command,

as well as to put some annotations via `\annote` and it exploits a variant of  `tikzmark` macro in which it is possible to customize a bit the position of the marker via shifts.

The code:

```
\documentclass[border=20pt,png]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2][-3pt]{\tikz[remember picture, overlay, baseline=-0.5ex]\node[#1](#2){};}

\tikzset{brace/.style={decorate, decoration={brace}},
 brace mirrored/.style={decorate, decoration={brace,mirror}},
}

\newcounter{brace}
\setcounter{brace}{0}
\newcommand{\drawbrace}[3][brace]{%
 \refstepcounter{brace}
 \tikz[remember picture, overlay]\draw[#1] (#2.center)--(#3.center)node[pos=0.5, name=brace-\thebrace]{};
}

\newcounter{arrow}
\setcounter{arrow}{0}
\newcommand{\drawcurvedarrow}[3][]{%
 \refstepcounter{arrow}
 \tikz[remember picture, overlay]\draw (#2.center)edge[#1]node[coordinate,pos=0.5, name=arrow-\thearrow]{}(#3.center);
}

% #1 options, #2 position, #3 text 
\newcommand{\annote}[3][]{%
 \tikz[remember picture, overlay]\node[#1] at (#2) {#3};
}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tabular}{ | l | l |}
  \hline
   letter & number \\ \hline
   \tikzmark[xshift=-8pt,yshift=1ex]{x}A &  1\tikzmark[xshift=3.5em]{a} \\ \hline
   A &  2 \\ \hline
   \tikzmark[xshift=-8pt,yshift=-1ex]{y}A &  1\tikzmark[xshift=3.5em]{b} \\ \hline
   \tikzmark[xshift=-8pt,yshift=1ex]{w}B &  1 \\ \hline
   \tikzmark[xshift=-8pt,yshift=-1ex]{z}B &  2 \\ \hline
 \end{tabular}
\drawcurvedarrow[bend left=60,-stealth]{a}{b}
\drawbrace[brace mirrored, thick]{x}{y}
\drawbrace[brace mirrored, thick]{w}{z}
\annote[right]{arrow-1}{Duplicate}
\annote[left]{brace-1}{A}
\annote[left]{brace-2}{B}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Remember to compile at least twice to get the result and to put annotations refer to the order in which braces or arrows have been deployed to identify their position (i.e. second brace: `brace-2`, fourth arrow: `arrow-4`).

Comment: Minor comment: If I understand the OP correctly, he wants the braces left, and the arrow right. Should be a trivial fix though.

Comment: Can I add text for the arrow and the braces? "Duplicated" for the arrow and "A" and "B" for the braces.

Comment: @MikeShaw: please see my updated answer. `:)`

Comment: @MikeShaw: you're welcome!

Answer (score 5):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (and TikZ).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
 \begin{NiceTabular}{ll}[hvlines]
   letter & number \\ 
   A &  1 \\ 
   A &  2 \\ 
   A &  1 \\ 
   B &  1 \\ 
   B &  2 \\ 
 \CodeAfter
   \tikz \draw [->] (2.5-|last) to [bend left, out= 60, in=120] node [right] { Duplicate } (4.5-|last) ; 
   \SubMatrix{\{}{2-1}{4-1}{.}[xshift=0.5em]
 \end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because of the PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]