# How do I vary the height of braces without varying the width?

Tags: math-mode, formatting, width

I am trying to highlight pieces of a formula with some text on the side, but one of those pieces is multiple lines.  The solution that I came up with was to use braces in an array to highlight the groups.

Unfortunately, the result doesn't look very good because the small brace is much narrower and has a different weight than the big brace.  How can I fix this so it doesn't look so strange?

One option is to find a different kind of brace that doesn't vary in width when it varies in height.  I hoped that `]` would do this, but indeed it varies in width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{ll@{}l}
  w & \}                       & \textrm{one element} \\
  x & \multirow{2}{*}{\bigg\}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textrm{two elements}} \\
  y &                          & \\
  z & \}                       & \textrm{another element} 
\end{array}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Here is the result of the code.  I would like for the left and right edges of all three braces to be aligned.  Here the gap between the brace and `one element` is much larger than the gap between the brace and `two elements`.

[image: strange width of braces]

Comment: You can easily adapt the solution in [Add a curved arrow and a bracket to a table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117873/13304) putting markers in the equation.

Answer (score 1):

The `scalerel` package allows one to stretch glyphs to fit the size of a second item.  Also, I used a TABstack to create the assembly.  If you wish the vertical spacing to be the same as your original, edit `\setstackgap{S}{1pt}` to be 0pt.  I just thought that the small extra gap looked better.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}
\[
\setstackgap{S}{1pt}
\alignShortstack{%
\strut$w\mkern-1mu$\quad\}& one element\\
\stretchleftright{.}{\stackanchor{\strut$x$}{\strut$y$}\quad}{\}}& two elements\\
\strut$z$\quad\}& another element
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion.  Unfortunately it doesn't look quite right.  The stretched symbols look different from the unstretched symbols.  Additionally, I have no familiarity with TABstack, which confuses the answer, I think.

Your comment about more space is absolutely correct, however.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I adapted this using the suggestions of Claudio in [Add a curved arrow and a bracket to a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117884/17211) to my purposes.  The advantage of using tikz over stretching symbols is that tikz produces a uniform look for all of the braces by actually generating an arbitrarily sized brace.  By setting the `amplitude` parameter in the code below I am able to control how wide a brace is.

It is also possible to solve this problem by placing markers in the table, but this solution seemed easier.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\vcenteredbox}[1]{\begingroup
\setbox0=\hbox{#1}\parbox{\wd0}{\box0}\endgroup}

\newcommand{\braceone}{%
  \vcenteredbox{\tikz{%
      \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=2pt},xshift=0pt, yshift=0pt] (0,0) -- (0,-1em);
  }}
}
\newcommand{\bracetwo}{%
  \vcenteredbox{\tikz{%
      \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=2pt},xshift=0pt, yshift=0pt] (0,0) -- (0,-2em);
  }}
}


\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{ll@{}l}
  w & \braceone                  & \textrm{one element} \\
  x & \multirow{2}{*}{\bracetwo} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textrm{two elements}} \\
  y &                            & \\
  z & \braceone                  & \textrm{another element} 
\end{array}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Correctly aligned braces]