# Connect three floating tables with arrows

Tags: tables, arrows

In a word document I have three tables connected by arrows, as in the figure below, that I would like to reproduce with Latex. My question is 1) how to create these three tables so I can position them more or less as in the figure and 2) how to draw arrows connecting cells of different tables.

[image]

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. You can also insert your image directly in here instead of a link

Comment: A job for [`tikzmark`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) if I've ever seen one! `:-)`

Comment: [Annotating Tables With Tikz; Adding Arrows](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/167000) might be helpful for you or someone else tackling this

Comment: `pst-node` could also be helpful here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer uses `tikzmark` as mentioned in the comments on your question. Basically, the idea is to typeset the tables as normal and then overlay them with a `tikzpicture` which draws the connecting arrows.

I've created one `tabular` for the top two tables and another for the third. The only use of `tikz` here is to create the arrows in the second column.

```
\newcommand*{\myarrow}[1][50]{\tikz{\draw [black!#1, {Stealth[length=7.5pt]}-, thick] (0,0) -- (.35,0);}}
```

defines a macro, `\myarrow[]`, which takes a single optional argument which determines how dark or heavy the arrow will be as a percentage. The default is `50` and I've also used `85` in the example.

The `tabular` environments use the packages `array` and `dcolumn` and two customised columns:

```
\newcolumntype{d}{D{.}{.}{2}}
\newcolumntype{o}{>{$}c<{$}}
```

The first centres the column on the decimal point for numbers with at most 2 decimal places. This also uses maths mode. The second just creates a centred maths mode.

`\tikzmark{}` is used in the `tabular` environments to mark coordinates for use when drawing the arrows later. This code does not affect the typesetting of the tables themselves, however.

The marks are then used in a `tikzpicture` which overlays the tables. This picture includes the commands to draw the arrows connecting the tables.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, arrows.meta, calc, bending}
\usepackage{array, dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}{D{.}{.}{2}}
\newcolumntype{o}{>{$}c<{$}}
\newcommand*{\myarrow}[1][50]{\tikz{\draw [black!#1, {Stealth[length=7.5pt]}-, thick] (0,0) -- (.35,0);}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{oco|d!{$\dots$}d}
      \textbf{l}    &   &   t   &   \multicolumn{1}{o!{$\dots$}}{P_{L1}}    &   \multicolumn{1}{o}{P_{Ln}}\\\cline{1-1}\cline{3-5}
      \tikzmark{p1}1    &   \myarrow    &   1   &   0.40    &   0.58\\
      \tikzmark{p2}1    &   \myarrow    &   2   &   0.41    &   0.60\\
      \tikzmark{p3}2    &   \myarrow[85]    &   3   &   0.20    &   0.41\\
      \tikzmark{p4}1    &   \myarrow    &   4   &   0.39    &   0.60\\
        \vdots  &   &   \vdots  &   \multicolumn{1}{o}{\vdots}  &   \vdots\\
      \tikzmark{p5}2    &   \myarrow[85]    &   M   &   0.21    &   0.43\\
    \end{tabular}\\[\bigskipamount]
    \begin{tabular}{o|d!{$\dots$}dd}
      c_i   &   \multicolumn{1}{o!{$\dots$}}{P_{L1}}    &   \multicolumn{1}{o}{P_{Ln}}  &   \multicolumn{1}{o}{Q_{L1}}\\\hline
      \tikzmark{c1}c_1  &   0.40    &   0.59    &   0.10\\
      \tikzmark{c2}c_2  &   0.21    &   0.42    &   0.05\\
      \vdots    &   \multicolumn{1}{o}{\vdots}  &   \vdots  &   \vdots\\
      c_k   &   0.32    &   0.33    &   0.02\\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, -{Stealth[length=7.5pt]}, draw]
    \coordinate (c1coord) at ($({pic cs:c1}) + (-.25em,.25em)$);
    \coordinate (c2coord) at ($({pic cs:c2}) + (-.25em,.25em)$);
    \foreach \i in {1,...,5}
        \coordinate (p\i1) at ($({pic cs:p\i}) + (-.25em,.25em)$);
    \coordinate (p12) at ($(p11) + (-1em,-1em)$);
    \coordinate (p13) at ($(c1coord) + (-1em,1em)$ -| p12);
    \coordinate (p22) at ($(p21) + (-1.5em,-1em)$);
    \coordinate (p23) at ($(c1coord) + (-1.5em,1em)$ -| p22);
    \coordinate (p32) at ($(p31) + (-2.5em,-1em)$);
    \coordinate (p33) at ($(c2coord) + (-2.5em,1em)$ -| p32);
    \coordinate (p42) at ($(p41) + (-2em,-1em)$);
    \coordinate (p43) at ($(c1coord) + (-2em,1em)$ -| p42);
    \coordinate (p52) at ($(p51) + (-3em,-1em)$);
    \coordinate (p53) at ($(c2coord) + (-3em,1em)$ -| p52);
    \foreach \i in {1,2,4}
      \draw [black!50] (p\i1) to[out=-180, in=90] (p\i2) -- (p\i3) to[out=-90, in=180] (c1coord);
    \foreach \i in {3,5}
      \draw [black!85, dashed] (p\i1) to[out=-180, in=90] (p\i2) -- (p\i3) to[out=-90, in=180] (c2coord);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: tables with <code>tikzmark</code>]

Answer (score 6):

How about [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkf/pgf) and a `matrix of math nodes`?

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% The matrix entries
\matrix[
  matrix of math nodes,
  nodes in empty cells,
  text depth=0.5ex,
  text height=2ex,
] (mat)
{
l &  & t & P_{L_{1}} & \cdots & P_{L_{n}} \\
1 & & 1 & 0.40 & \cdots & 0.58 \\
1 & & 2 & 0.40 & \cdots & 0.58 \\
2 & & 3 & 0.40 & \cdots & 0.58 \\
1 & & 2 & 0.40 & \cdots & 0.58 \\
\vdots & &  \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
2 & & 5 & 0.40 & \cdots & 0.58 \\
\\[10pt]
\mathbf{c}_{j} & P_{L_{1}} & \cdots & P_{L_{n}} & Q_{L_{1}} \\
\mathbf{c}_{1} & 0.32 & \cdots & 0.34 & 0.10 \\
\mathbf{c}_{2} & 0.32 & \cdots & 0.34 & 0.10 \\
\vdots &  \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots \\
\mathbf{c}_{k} & 0.32 & \cdots & 0.34 & 0.10 \\
};

% The arrows in the second column
\begin{scope}[line width=1.5pt,<-,shorten >= -2pt,shorten <= -2pt]
\foreach \Fila in {2,3,5}
\draw[gray]
  (mat-\Fila-2.west) -- (mat-\Fila-2.east);
\foreach \Fila in {4,7}
\draw 
  (mat-\Fila-2.west) -- (mat-\Fila-2.east);
\end{scope}

% The rules for the matrices
\draw (mat-1-1.south west) -- (mat-1-1.south east);
\draw (mat-1-3.south west) -- (mat-1-6.south east);
\draw (mat-1-4.north west) -- (mat-1-4.north west|-mat-7-4.south west);
\draw (mat-9-2.north west) -- (mat-9-2.north west|-mat-13-2.south west);
\draw (mat-9-1.south west) -- (mat-9-5.south east);

% The curved arrows connecting entries
\begin{scope}[
  >=latex,
  rounded corners
]
\foreach \Fila/\Corr in {2/8pt,3/15pt,5/22pt}
\draw[->,gray]
  (mat-\Fila-1.west) -- ++(-\Corr,0) |- (mat-9-1.west);
\foreach \Fila/\Corr in {4/30pt,7/37pt}
\draw[->,dashed]
  (mat-\Fila-1.west) -- ++(-\Corr,0) |- (mat-11-1.west);
\end{scope}  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```