# tikz matrix: color entire row

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

Goal: I would like to color entire rows of a tikz matrix.

Background: I did some googling, and I got the following.

Debugging: I know what is wrong (it's only coloring the individual nodes, rather than the entire row). However, I'm not sure how to fix it.

Code

```
    \documentclass{beamer}

    \usetheme{default}

    \usepackage{txfonts}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{graphicx}

    \tikzset{align at top/.style={baseline=(current bounding box.north)}}

    \usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc, shapes.multipart, chains, arrows, matrix, decorations.markings}

    \begin{document}


    \begin{frame}[fragile, t]{sample failure}

    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \vspace*{0.3cm}
    \hspace*{\fill}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix [matrix of nodes,
      row sep = 0.5cm,
      every even row/.style = { nodes={fill=blue!5}},
      every odd row/.style = { nodes={fill=red!5}}
      ] {
      \node {blah1}; & \node{$\sum_{i=1}^n i $}; & \node{\begin{tabular}{c}line1 \\ line2 \end{tabular}}; \\
      \node {blah2}; & \node{$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}{b_i}$}; & \node{\begin{tabular}{c}expalination 2\\ exp 3 \\ exp 4\end{tabular}}; \\
      \node {blah and more}; & \node{$\log ^{d+4} \frac{M}{\epsilon}$}; & \node{\begin{tabular}{c}no idea\\ and more \end{tabular}}; \\
      \node {blah4}; & \node{$\log ^{d-1} \frac{M}{\epsilon}$}; & \node{\begin{tabular}{c}blah blah and more info\end{tabular}}; \\
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \hspace*{\fill}
    \end{minipage}

    \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

[image: output of my code]

Comment: First: if you use `matrix of nodes` you don't need to say every time `\node{}`, see the documentation chapter 38 Matrix Library. For your purpose, there are some solutions on the site; a couple of examples (not exhaustive at all): [Highlight elements in the matrix](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40028/13304) and [Array cell highlighting tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83323/13304) (both refer to blocks, but it's quite easy to extend it to a single row or column).

Comment: You might want to have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14061/86 which deals with a similar problem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First of all, as you're using `matrix of nodes`, you don't need to specify `node`s manually. each `node` is only as big as it needs to be, so one (far from elegent or automatic way) is to specify `minimum height`s and `minimum width`s:

### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{sample failure}

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix
    [   matrix of nodes,
      row sep = 0.1cm,
      every even row/.style = {nodes={fill=blue!50}},
      every odd row/.style = {nodes={fill=red!50}},
      nodes={anchor=west},
      column 1/.style = {nodes={minimum width=2.8cm}},
      column 2/.style = {nodes={minimum width=1.7cm}},
      column 3/.style = {nodes={minimum width=4.5cm}},
      row 1/.style={nodes={minimum height=1.2cm}},
      row 2/.style={nodes={minimum height=1.8cm}},
      row 3/.style={nodes={minimum height=1.2cm}},
      row 4/.style={nodes={minimum height=0.8cm}},
    ] 
    { blah1 & $\sum_{i=1}^n i $ & \begin{tabular}{c}line1 \\ line2 \end{tabular} \\
      blah & $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}{b_i}$ & \begin{tabular}{c}expalination 2\\ exp 3 \\ exp 4\end{tabular} \\
      blah and more & $\log ^{d+4} \frac{M}{\epsilon}$ & \begin{tabular}{c}no idea\\ and more \end{tabular} \\
      blah4 & $\log ^{d-1} \frac{M}{\epsilon}$ & \begin{tabular}{c}blah blah and more info\end{tabular} \\
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
\end{minipage}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

---

**Edit 1:** here's a version requiring much less tweaking: it determines heights and width automatically. You only need to manually pass the matrix name, the number of rows and colums and the colors you'd like to use to `\colorfillrows`. I borrowed the `[on background layer]` from **Ignasi**, thanks for that:

### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit,backgrounds}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\newcommand{\getdim}[1]% name of node
{ \path (#1.south west);
  \pgfgetlastxy{\xsw}{\ysw}
  \path (#1.north east);
  \pgfgetlastxy{\xne}{\yne}
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\nodewidth}{\xne-\xsw}
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\nodeheight}{\yne-\ysw}
  \xdef\widthofnode{\nodewidth}
  \xdef\widthofnode{\nodeheight}
}

\newcommand{\colorfillrows}[5]% 1:matrixname, 2:numrows, 3:numcols, 4:oddcolor, 5:evencolor
{ \xdef\maxwidth{0}
  \foreach \myrow in {1,...,#2}
  { \getdim{#1-\myrow-#3}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\biggerwidth}{\nodewidth>\maxwidth ? \nodewidth : \maxwidth}
    \xdef\maxwidth{\biggerwidth}
  }
  \foreach \myrow in {1,...,#2}
  { \xdef\maxheight{0}
    \xdef\myfit{}
    \foreach \mycol in {1,...,#3}
    {   \getdim{#1-\myrow-\mycol}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\biggerheight}{\nodeheight>\maxheight ? \nodeheight : \maxheight}
        \xdef\maxheight{\biggerheight}
            \xdef\myfit{\myfit(#1-\myrow-\mycol)}
    }
    \node[right,minimum width=\maxwidth,inner sep=0] (extra-\myrow) at (#1-\myrow-#3.west) {};
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\oddrow}{mod(\myrow,2)}
        \ifthenelse{\oddrow=1}{\xdef\mycolor{#4}}{\xdef\mycolor{#5}}
            \node[inner sep=2pt,fit=\myfit(extra-\myrow),fill=\mycolor,inner sep=0pt] {};
        \end{scope}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{sample almost automatic success}
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
      \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix (mydata)
        [   matrix of nodes,
          row sep = 0.1cm,
          nodes={anchor=west},
        ] 
        { blah1 & $\sum_{i=1}^n i $ & \begin{tabular}{c}line1 \\ line2 \end{tabular} \\
          blah & $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}{b_i}$ & \begin{tabular}{c}expalination 2\\ exp 3 \\ exp 4\end{tabular} \\
          blah and more & $\log ^{d+4} \frac{M}{\epsilon}$ & \begin{tabular}{c}no idea\\ and more \end{tabular} \\
          blah4 & $\log ^{d-1} \frac{M}{\epsilon}$ & \begin{tabular}{c}blah blah and more info\end{tabular} \\
        };
        \colorfillrows{mydata}{4}{3}{orange!55}{blue!30!cyan}% 1:matrixname, 2:numrows, 3:numcols, 4:oddcolor, 5:evencolor
        \end{tikzpicture}
      \end{center}
    \end{minipage}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: I added an almost automatic version.

Answer (score 12):

Another possibility would be to fill columns and rows once the matrix is finished. You can `fill` a region and place it on the `background layer`. As Tom's solution, this one is also far from elegant or automatic. It's even less automatic because you have to define all corners knowing the tallest and widest cells for the row and column.

Next code shows two solutions, one `fill` a rectangle and the second one uses `fit` library.

Two more remarks about the code:

1.- I've `drawn` the matrix border to show that it's different from exterior cells borders. 
2.- You if you define a `text width` and a `align` option, you don't need to use `tabular` inside cells, just with `{first line\\ second line}` is enough.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,backgrounds,fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{sample failure}

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (A)
    [   matrix of nodes, draw,
      row sep = 0.1cm,
      nodes={anchor=west},
      column 3/.style = {nodes={text width=4.5cm, align=center}},
    ] 
    { blah1 & $\sum_{i=1}^n i $ & {line1 \\ line2} \\
      blah & $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}{b_i}$ & {explanation 2\\ exp 3 \\ exp 4} \\
      blah and more & $\log ^{d+4} \frac{M}{\epsilon}$ & {no idea\\ and more} \\
      blah4 & $\log ^{d-1} \frac{M}{\epsilon}$ & {blah blah and more info} \\    };

    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \fill[blue!30] (A-1-1.west|-A-1-3.north) rectangle (A-1-3.south-|A-4-3.east);
    \node[fit=(A-2-1.west|-A-2-3.north) (A-2-3.south-|A-4-3.east),fill=red!30, inner sep=0pt] {};
    \fill[green!30,opacity=.5] (A-1-2.west|-A-1-3.north) rectangle (A-4-2.south east);
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
\end{minipage}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]