# The simplest way to fill a matrix of nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, nodes, tikz-matrix, tikz-node

Code:

```
           \tikzstyle{matrici}=[
       matrix of math nodes, 
      nodes in empty cells,
      column sep=-\pgflinewidth, % to avoid double borders in contiguous cells
   nodes={
    draw, 
   align=center, 
  inner sep=0pt, 
    text width=1cm, 
    minimum height=1cm
}
]

               \begin{tikzpicture} 
\matrix[matrici, 
column 1/.style={nodes={fill=blue!10}},  
column 2/.style={nodes={fill=blue!10}},
column 3/.style={nodes={fill=blue!10}},
column 4/.style={nodes={fill=blue!10}},
]  (X)  {&&&&&&&\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

output:

[image]

there is no way ti fill the first 4 cells with a "cicle for"? Im forced to write 
this?

```
   column 1/.style={nodes={fill=blue!10}},  
    column 2/.style={nodes={fill=blue!10}},
   column 3/.style={nodes={fill=blue!10}},
     column 4/.style={nodes={fill=blue!10}},
```

it will be fine somethig like

```
   \foreach \x in {1,2,3,4} 
   fill the node (X-1-\x) with this color
```

Comment: You can define a style with column number as parameter and define a `.list` which will use it. More clear at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175616/tikz-matrix-style-for-combination-or-rows-and-columns

Comment: if you define `mycols/.style={column #1/.style={nodes={fill=blue!10}}` then you can call it with `mycols/.list={1,...,4}`

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

You can do add a `\fill` to the `background` layer:

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,backgrounds}
\tikzset{ % \tikzstyle is considered deprecated
  matrici/.style={
    matrix of math nodes, 
    nodes in empty cells,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth, % to avoid double borders in contiguous cells
    nodes={
      draw, 
      align=center, 
      inner sep=0pt, 
      text width=1cm, 
      minimum height=1cm
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\matrix[matrici]  (X)  {&&&&&&&\\};

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\foreach \x in {1,...,4}
  \fill [blue!10] (X-1-\x.south west) rectangle (X-1-\x.north east);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}   

\end{document}
```

Another option is to do something similar to what Loop Space did in his answer to [How can I set the background color of the rows and columns of a matrix node in Tikz?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14061/how-can-i-set-the-background-color-of-the-rows-and-columns-of-a-matrix-node-in-t/14070#14070):

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,backgrounds}
\tikzset{
  matrici/.style={
    matrix of math nodes, 
    nodes in empty cells,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth, % to avoid double borders in contiguous cells
    nodes={
      draw, 
      align=center, 
      inner sep=0pt, 
      text width=1cm, 
      minimum height=1cm
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\matrix[
  matrici,
  nodes={
   execute at begin node={
       \pgfmathparse{\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn<5 ? "blue!10" : "white"}
        \xglobal\colorlet{nodebg}{\pgfmathresult}},
        preaction={fill=nodebg}
}
]  (X)  {&&&&&&&\\};


\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pardon my ignorance of understanding your question but if you are looking for creating a colored box then you can do the following (i.e. please correct me if I misunderstood your question because it is not totally clear to me).

```
\documentclass[border={10pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        colorbox/.style={rectangle,fill=blue!10,draw=black,thick, minimum size=1cm},
        box/.style={rectangle,draw=black,thick, minimum size=1cm},
    ]%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\foreach \x in {0,...,3}
    \node[colorbox] at (\x,0){};

\foreach \x in {4,...,7}
    \node[box] at (\x,0){};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]