# Highlight elements in the matrix

Tags: math-mode, matrices, framed, highlighting

I have a matrix and need to highlight some elements in the matrix. I have found how to highlight a single element (I want to put the cell in the square):

```
$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
\fbox{0} & \fbox{0} & 0 \\ 
\fbox{0} & \fbox{0} & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$
```

But how can I outline elements of the submatrix like in the picture below? I need just a frame where some elements are located.

[image: Submatrix]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)    Please make sure that all images are uploaded using the official stackexchange interface, i.e. the image icon on top of the text field (shortcut: CTRL+G). This ensures that all images are always accessible and do not expire.

    As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again.

Comment: Related : [Highlighting the diagonal of a square matrix](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30032/highlighting-diagonal-of-a-square-matrix)

Comment: I need put some elements in the square, not highlight. See the picture

Answer (score 54):

You could use TikZ, and

- the `fit` library for creating nodes fitting the desired area,
- a style for the highlighted node, so separated from the code and easy to change,
- the TikZ options `overlay` and `remember picture`, so you can later refer to those nodes, for example for drawing arrows and annotations later.

To demonstrate why it's useful to have nodes for reference, I created an example, which shows transposing a matrix, highlights a submatrix both in the original matrix and the result, connected by an arrow and annotated:

[image: Transposing a matrix]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\tikzset{%
  highlight/.style={rectangle,rounded corners,fill=red!15,draw,
    fill opacity=0.5,thick,inner sep=0pt}
}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,
  baseline=(#1.base)] \node (#1) {#2};}
%
\newcommand{\Highlight}[1][submatrix]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{
    \node[highlight,fit=(left.north west) (right.south east)] (#1) {};}
}
\begin{document}
\[
  M = \left(\begin{array}{*5{c}}
    \tikzmark{left}{1} & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
    11 & 12 & \tikzmark{right}{13} & 14 & 15 \\
    16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20
  \end{array}\right)
  \Highlight[first]
  \qquad
  M^T = \left(\begin{array}{*5{c}}
    \tikzmark{left}{1} & 6 & 11 & 16 \\
    2 & 7 & 12 & 17 \\
    3 & 8 & \tikzmark{right}{13} & 18 \\
    4 & 9 & 14 & 19 \\
    5 & 10 & 15 & 20
  \end{array}\right)
\]
\Highlight[second]
%
\tikz[overlay,remember picture] {
  \draw[->,thick,red,dashed] (first) -- (second) node [pos=0.66,above] {Transpose};
  \node[above of=first] {$N$};
  \node[above of=second] {$N^T$};
}
\end{document}​
```

Comment: Nice solution, but you can only highlight a single selection per matrix. Isn't it?

Comment: @GM It's just a demonstration. The point is using `\tikzmark`. You can use it many times and use different labels, like left1 or left2 etc. The `\Highlight` helper macro is mad just to use left and right, but you can change that for example to have labels as arguments and repeat to highlight several selections in the same matrix.

Comment: This fails for me when the second row, first column of the highlighted box extends to the left of the first row, first column (i.e., it is longer and these are centered). Then the element starts before the left edge of the highlighted box. Need something like `\hphantom`, but that doesn't work.

Comment: The numbers look lighter because of the overlay. Is it possible to have the rectangle in the background, so the numbers look as usual?

Answer (score 48):

I recommend TikZ. The result:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,matrix,positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=)] (m)
        {
            8 &8 &1 &6 \\               
            3 &8 &5 &7 \\               
            4 &8 &9 &5 \\           
        };  
        \draw[color=red] (m-1-1.north west) -- (m-1-3.north east) -- (m-2-3.south east) -- (m-2-1.south west) -- (m-1-1.north west);
        \draw[color=red,double,implies-](m-1-2.north) -- +(0,0.3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that, if all the array elements aren't the same width, this box won't be square. It'll be trapezoidal or some such nonsense. Which is disappointing, if understandable.

Answer (score 41):

You can use `\tikzmark` from [this answer by Andrew Stacey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/adding-a-large-brace-next-to-a-body-of-text/1570#1570) to mark the endpoints where you want the box.  This allows you to do the matrix in the usual way (outside of `tikz`).  Since this is very similar to Werner's solution that used `pstricks`, I adapted that code to use `\tikzmark`:

[image]

### Notes:

- This does require two runs: the first to compute the positions of the box, and the second to draw it in the correct spot.
- Since this is using `tikz`, you automatically get all the flexibility inherent in `tikz`, such as line styles, line thickness, line color, fill, etc. These can be passed to the `\DrawBox` macro to customize each instance or provided as default options to maintain consistency.

### Update:

- An enhanced version of this is available at [How can I add some enhancement to the matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47765/how-can-i-add-some-enhancement-to-the-matrix) which allows you to have more than one boxed region in a matrix, and also the option to add labels below each of the boxes.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\newcommand{\DrawBox}[1][]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{
    \draw[red,#1]
      ($(left)+(-0.2em,0.9em)$) rectangle
      ($(right)+(0.2em,-0.3em)$);}
}

\begin{document}
\[
  M = \left[\begin{array}{*{13}{c}}
    \tikzmark{left}0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0\tikzmark{right} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0
  \end{array}\right]
\]
\DrawBox[thick]
\end{document}​
```

Answer (score 35):

Here is a solution using TikZ. You may also want to read the solution suggested by percusse in his comment, although I think my solution is simpler to understand for a newcommer to TikZ.

**comment**: My original solution included an align command in the matrix, this actually turned everything in the matrix into text, not math stuff. I removed the align instruction, so now if you compile the code, the stuff is actually in math mode and the minus signs are correct. I did not change the image.

The code is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter = (,right delimiter = ),row sep=10pt,column sep = 10pt] (m) {
1&3&-8\\    2&0&1\\    -7&9&1\\    };

\draw (m-1-1.north west) -- (m-1-1.south west) -- (m-3-3.south west) -- (m-3-3.south east)
      -- (m-3-3.north east) -- (m-1-1.north east) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter = (,right delimiter = ),row sep=10pt,column sep = 10pt] (m) {
1&3&-8\\    2&0&1\\    -7&9&1\\    };

\draw (m-1-1.north west) -- (m-2-1.south west) -- (m-2-2.south east) -- (m-1-2.north east) -- cycle;
%the previous line can be replaced by \draw (m-1-1.north west) rectangle (m-2-2.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]

Comment: Very interesting solution. Is there a way of forcing the numbers of the matrix to be in math mode automatically, so that the minus signs in front of "8" and "7" aren't typeset as short dashes?

Comment: @Mico: see change to solution. The "matrix of math nodes" instruction does what you want.

Comment: That's pretty awesome.

Answer (score 31):

Here's a method that uses only LaTeX's "built-in" commands `\cline` and `\multicolumn` to create the frame around the upper-left 3x3 submatrix.

By the way, because your matrix has more than 10 columns, I believe it's necessary to either use the `array` environment instead of the `bmatrix` environment (`bmatrix` is essentially a "wrapper" around the `array` construct) *or* to increase the counter `MaxMatrixCols` in order to avoid unwelcome surprises while setting up a 13-column matrix via `bmatrix`.

Separately, for the case at hand, I would not load the `array` package; if you were to load the `array` package, you'd get as a (presumably unwelcome) side-effect a widening of the inter-column space between columns 3 and 4 by the width of the frame line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[ M = \left[ \: 
     % \: serves as a spacer between the left-hand bracket of 
     % the matrix and the left-hand side of the inner frame
\begin{array}{*{13}{c}}
\cline{1-3}
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{0} & 1 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0} 
  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{1} & 0 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} 
  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{0} & 1 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0}
  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
\cline{1-3}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
\end{array}
\right] \] 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `bmatrix` is a wrapper that uses `array` internally, so `\multicolumn` and `\cline` work.

Answer (score 31):

Another approach always using TikZ.

Since the `backgrounds` library was not exploited so far, I made use of it; first I defined two commands that allow to `fill` the background of the elements highlighted or not:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\highlight}{O{blue!40} m m}{%
\draw[mycolor=#1] (#2.north west)rectangle (#3.south east);
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\fhighlight}{O{blue!40} m m}{%
\draw[myfillcolor=#1] (#2.north west)rectangle (#3.south east);
}
```

corresponding to the `styles`:

```
\tikzset{mycolor/.style = {line width=1bp,color=#1}}%
\tikzset{myfillcolor/.style = {draw,fill=#1}}%
```

Inside the document, to highlight some elements of the matrix, it must be used the environment `pgfonlayer` with a dedicated background layer `myback`:

```
\pgfdeclarelayer{myback}
\pgfsetlayers{myback,background,main}
```

Then it is possible to call:

```
\fhighlight{m-1-1}{m-3-3}
```

or

```
\highlight[red]{m-2-2}{m-4-5}
```

The complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,backgrounds}
\pgfdeclarelayer{myback}
\pgfsetlayers{myback,background,main}

\tikzset{mycolor/.style = {line width=1bp,color=#1}}%
\tikzset{myfillcolor/.style = {draw,fill=#1}}%

\NewDocumentCommand{\highlight}{O{blue!40} m m}{%
\draw[mycolor=#1] (#2.north west)rectangle (#3.south east);
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\fhighlight}{O{blue!40} m m}{%
\draw[myfillcolor=#1] (#2.north west)rectangle (#3.south east);
}

\begin{document}

Using the \verb!myfillcolor style! (\verb!\fhighlight! command):
\[P=
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax ]
\matrix (m)[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=)]
{
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
};

\begin{pgfonlayer}{myback}
\fhighlight{m-1-1}{m-3-3}
\fhighlight[green!30]{m-3-9}{m-5-13}
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\]

Using the \verb!mycolor style! (\verb!\highlight! command):
\[P=
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax ]
\matrix (m)[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=)]
{
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
};

\begin{pgfonlayer}{myback}
\highlight[red]{m-2-2}{m-4-5}
\highlight[orange]{m-5-7}{m-6-9}
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\]

It is even possible to highlight single elements:
\[P=
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax ]
\matrix (m)[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=)]
{
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
};

\begin{pgfonlayer}{myback}
\foreach \element in {m-1-1,m-6-5,m-5-3}{
\highlight[violet]{\element}{\element}
}
\foreach \element in {m-3-10,m-4-8,m-5-12}{
\fhighlight[violet!20]{\element}{\element}
}
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: +1 for joining the party late and the idea to use `backgrounds` :-)

Answer (score 23):

Here is a [`pstricks`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pstricks)-related approach that requires [`pst-node`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-node):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{pst-node}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-node
\begin{document}
\[
  M = \left[\begin{array}{*{13}{c}}
    \pnode(-.5ex,2ex){left}0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0\pnode(.5ex,-.5ex){right} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0
  \end{array}\right]
\]

\psframe[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=red!60,linewidth=1pt](left)(right)% Draw frame
\end{document}​
```

`\psframe[<option>](<ll>)(<ur>)` draws a frame from the lower-left coordinate `<ll>` to the upper right coordinate `<ur>` with `<options>`. [`xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) provides colour shades (`red!60` or 60% red in this case). This requires a `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf` or `xelatex` compile sequence, due to `pstricks`.

For more information on colouring or boxing `array` cells, see Herbert Voß' [`mathmode` document](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf). In particular, sections **62.5 Colored cells** and **62.6 Boxed rows and columns** (p 107) as part of the discussion on **62 Arrays**.

Comment: This example, as is, gives me a GPL Ghostscript 9.55.0: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1 when compiling with xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "test".tex. I am on ubuntu linux using TeXstudio.

Comment: @Matsmath: No problem on my end, with an up-to-date TL 2023.

Answer (score 23):

run with `xelatex` or `latex=>dvips=>ps2pdf`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}
\[
  M = \left[\begin{array}{*{13}{c}}
    \rnode[lt]{left}{0} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & \rnode[rb]{right}{0} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0
  \end{array}\right]
\]
\psframe[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red,opacity=0.2,linecolor=red,framearc=0.1]%
  ([nodesep=3pt,angle=135]left)([nodesep=3pt,angle=-45]right)% Draw frame

\end{document}​
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

[`easybmat`](http://ctan.org/pkg/easybmat) offers an alternative syntax for math tabulars and also includes the command `addpath` which allows to draw a path between matrix elements.

`BMAT` syntax is

```
\begin{BMAT}{ccccc}{ccccc}...\end{BMAT}
```

where first parameter represents alignment in columns and second alignment in rows. It also offers other optional parameters to define relation between columns widths and/or rows heights.

Inside a `BMAT` environment it's possible to use command `addpath` to draw a line between matrix elements. As an example:

```
\addpath{(0,1,1)rruulldd}
```

starts a path from `0,1` (being 0,0 the bottom left corner, each unit moves one row to the right or column to top), `1` defines the kind of line to draw, and `rruulldd` defines the path, each letter draws one column/row to `r`ight, `u`p, `l`eft or `d`own.

An example of use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{easybmat}

\begin{document}

\[P=
\left(
\begin{BMAT}{ccccc}{ccccc}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 
\addpath{(0,1,1)rruulldd}
\addpath{(1,5,1)drrdrdrdld}
\end{BMAT}
\right)
\]

\end{document}
```

and the result

[image]

Answer (score 9):

It seems that [Claudio Fiandrino](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/13304/claudio-fiandrino) forgot to mention his `hf-tikz` package as an option for this question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hf-tikz}

\begin{document}

\[P=
\left(
\begin{array}{*{13}{c}}
\tikzmarkin{a}(0.1,-0.1)(-0.1,0.35)0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\tikzmarkend{a} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \tikzmarkin{b}(0.1,-0.1)(-0.1,0.35)0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\tikzmarkend{b}  & 1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Now, when the `nicematrix` package is available, the following solution is also possible:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
\[ 
M = \begin{bNiceArray}{*{10}{c}}[margin=0.5em]
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
\CodeAfter
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (A) [draw=red, thick, fit=(1-1) (4-3)] {} ;
    \node (B) [draw=red, thick, fit=(6-7) (8-10)] {} ; 
    \path[draw=blue,thick,->] (A) -| (B) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{bNiceArray}
\]
\end{document}
```

After two compilation the result is:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## Simple tikz solution

I prefer to use pure tikz without defining new commands or importing packages, using a rectangle that takes the lower left corner and the upper right corner as input. In this case, we use the index of the matrix `m` that we define previously:

```
\draw (lower left coordinates) rectangle (upper right corner);
```

In the matrix I wrote the coordinates of the elements so it is easier to understand which are the starting and ending points.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,matrix,positioning}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=)] (m)
        {
           i_{1,1} & i_{1,2} & i_{1,3} & i_{1,4} & i_{1,5} & i_{1,6} \\ 
            i_{2,1} & i_{2,2} & i_{2,3} & i_{2,4} & i_{2,5} & i_{2,6} \\ 
            i_{3,1} & i_{3,2} & i_{3,3} & i_{3,4} & i_{3,5} & i_{3,6} \\ 
            i_{4,1} & i_{4,2} & i_{4,3} & i_{4,4} & i_{4,5} & i_{4,6} \\ 
            i_{5,1} & i_{5,2} & i_{5,3} & i_{5,4} & i_{5,5} & i_{5,6} \\ 
            i_{6,1} & i_{6,2} & i_{6,3} & i_{6,4} & i_{6,5} & i_{6,6} \\ 
        };
        %simple rectangle
        \draw (m-3-1.south west) rectangle (m-1-3.north east);
        %fancy blue rectangle
        \draw[rounded corners,ultra thick, draw=black, fill=blue, opacity=0.3] (m-6-4.south west) rectangle (m-4-6.north east);             
    \end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

## Compared to other answers

This answer is similar to [someonr answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40044/33846) however his answer will output trapezoidal shape if the matrix elements have different lengths, compared to [Stephen answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40333/33846) it can handle multiple selections without modifying the code.

For reference I post also a Python 2.7 script for generating the matrix which can be quite a tedious task to perform manually:

```py
size = 6
for i in range(1,size+1):
    for j in range(1,size+1):
        if j%size != 0 or j == 0:
            print "i_{%s,%s} &" %(i,j),
        else: 
            print r"""i_{%s,%s} \\ """ %(i,j)
```

Answer (score 2):

With `nicematrix` (≥ 5.12), you can stroke and fill a portion of a matrix with the command `\Block`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}
\[ 
M = \begin{bNiceArray}{*{10}{c}}[margin=0.7em]
\Block[name=A,draw=red]{4-3}{}
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \Block[name=B,draw=red]{3-4}{}
                        1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
\CodeAfter
    \tikz \draw [blue,->] (A) -| (B) ;
\end{bNiceArray}
\]
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]