# Vertically align the cell of a table with the baseline of surrounding text

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I have a table like this:

```
\begin{tabular}[b]{c}
A \\
B \\
C \\
D \\
\end{tabular}E
```

The code above places "D" and "E" on the same baseline, no matter what size any of the letters are.

Without changing "E" (I can't make changes to this text), how can I adjust the table, such that "C" and "E" are on the same baseline, no matter what size any of the letters are?

Comment: Try `\begin{tabular}[c]{c}`.

Comment: That centers the content so that "E" is approximately between ""B" and "C". I need the bottom of "C" and the bottom of "E" to be aligned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming no `\hline` and that the table cells have "normal" size, this should work (the setting of `\arraystretch` is just to show that it can be done):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newsavebox{\lowertabularbox}
\newenvironment{lowertabular}[1][0]
  {\newcommand{\lowertabulararg}{#1}\begin{lrbox}{\lowertabularbox}
   \begin{tabular}[b]}
  {\end{tabular}\end{lrbox}%
   \raisebox{-\dimexpr\arraystretch\baselineskip*\lowertabulararg\relax}{\usebox{\lowertabularbox}}}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\begin{lowertabular}[0]{c}
A \\
B \\
C \\
D \\
\end{lowertabular}E
\begin{lowertabular}[1]{c}
A \\
B \\
C \\
D \\
\end{lowertabular}E
\begin{lowertabular}[2]{c}
A \\
B \\
C \\
D \\
\end{lowertabular}E
\begin{lowertabular}[3]{c}
A \\
B \\
C \\
D \\
\end{lowertabular}E

some text below to ensure that all is going well
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

A much simpler solution, using TeX commands. Remember that for TeX everything are boxes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\mbox{}\raise-6.0pt\hbox{
\begin{tabular}[c]{c}
A \\
B \\
C \\
D \\
\end{tabular}}E
\end{document}
```

Comment: How did you know it is "-6.5 pt"?

Comment: Why not `\raisebox{-6.5pt}{\begin{tabular}...}` that would dispense with a mysterious `\mbox{}` and foreign syntax?

Comment: @Vilage It should be half the baseline. Actually it should be 6pt. I edited my post for this. One could incorporate the calculation in the code.

Comment: @egreg originally I had a `\leavevmode`, which I thought would confuse the OP. I am not too sure if I agree with your  statement of `foreign syntax`. When I started with programming we always learned the primitives and started building abstractions on top of them. A lot of new programmers start from the abstractions and then learn the primitives. The reason I offered this solution, is that a lot of newcomers to (La)TeX don't think in boxes. One needs to think in`boxes` to understand TeX.

Comment: That's why `\raisebox` does automatically a `\leavevmode`: where doesn't it lead to "think in boxes"?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution using TikZ nodes for positioning on baselines. In the example, we align at the third row.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,
    baseline=(#1.base)] \node (#1) {#2};}
\begin{document}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline=(cell.base)]{
  \node (table) {\begin{tabular}{c}
  A \\
  B \\
  \tikzmark{cell}{C} \\
  D \\
  \end{tabular}};}
\quad text aligned with the third row
\end{document}
```

[image: table with customized alignment]

The macro `\tikzmark` produces a node we called `cell`. The whole table has been put into a node contained in a TikZ environment, and we defined that the baseline of this environment (with the table) should be the base of this node. This way the table gets the desired baseline, matching the baseline of the following text.

Once having such TikZ nodes, it gives you further possibilities, such as drawing arrows or braces or using it for further alignment. Have a look at [Highlighting elements in a matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40028/highlight-elements-in-the-matrix/40333#40333) to see what I mean.