# Compiling errors in a matrix that correctly show up?

Tags: matrices, arrays

I have a little problem with nested arrays.

The following examples give the correct matrix after a Latex=>PDF run but generate LaTeX errors `! missing $ inserted. <inserted text>`, that I would like to get rid of.

Any idea about the problem?

First Example:

```
\begin{equation}
g_{22}=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}\fbox{\begin{array}{ccc}\frac{1}{E-E_1^1} & & \\ & \ddots & \\ & & \frac{1}{E-E_1^N}\end{array}} & & \\ & \ddots & \\ & &  \fbox{\begin{array}{ccc} \frac{1}{E-E_n^1} & & \\ & \ddots & \\ & & \frac{1}{E-E_n^N}\end{array}}\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}
```

Second example:

```
\begin{equation}
    H=\left[\begin{array}{cc}H_{N-n}&\begin{array}{cl}B\qquad & 0 \end{array}\\ \begin{array}{c}B^{\dag}\\ 0 \end{array} & \fbox{\begin{array}{cc}H_{n}&\quad S\\S^{\dag}&\quad\hsub\end{array}}\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 2):

The problem goes away if the contents of the `\fbox` is typeset in the mathmode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
g_{22}=\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
\fbox{$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{1}{E-E_1^1} & & \\ 
& \ddots & \\ 
& & \frac{1}{E-E_1^N}
\end{array}$} & & \\ 
& \ddots & \\ 
& &  \fbox{$
           \begin{array}{ccc} 
           \frac{1}{E-E_n^1} & & \\
            & \ddots & \\ 
            & & \frac{1}{E-E_n^N}
           \end{array}$}
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One can also make use of the answers given in [Highlight elements in the matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40028/highlight-elements-in-the-matrix)