# Matrix with arrow - problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

I am using the following code from this question:
[Highlight elements in the matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40028/highlight-elements-in-the-matrix)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\tikzset{%
  highlight/.style={rectangle,rounded corners,fill=red!15,draw,
    fill opacity=0.5,thick,inner sep=0pt}
}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,
  baseline=(#1.base)] \node (#1) {#2};}
%
\newcommand{\Highlight}[1][submatrix]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{
    \node[highlight,fit=(left.north west) (right.south east)] (#1) {};}
}
\begin{document}
\[
  M = \left(\begin{array}{*5{c}}
    \tikzmark{left}{1} & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
    11 & 12 & \tikzmark{right}{13} & 14 & 15 \\
    16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20
  \end{array}\right)
  \Highlight[first]
  \qquad
  M^T = \left(\begin{array}{*5{c}}
    \tikzmark{left}{1} & 6 & 11 & 16 \\
    2 & 7 & 12 & 17 \\
    3 & 8 & \tikzmark{right}{13} & 18 \\
    4 & 9 & 14 & 19 \\
    5 & 10 & 15 & 20
  \end{array}\right)
\]
\Highlight[second]
%
\tikz[overlay,remember picture] {
  \draw[->,thick,red,dashed] (first) -- (second) node [pos=0.66,above] {Transpose};
  \node[above of=first] {$N$};
  \node[above of=second] {$N^T$};
}
\end{document}​
```

But my result is:

[image]

Comment: You need to compile at least two times.

Comment: I am using WinEdt 7.0 , I try to compile two times but I see the same ressult

Comment: try to star compilation in WinEdt with hit the key F9. (this cause compilation of a file at list twice). i receive correct result

Comment: Thanks, I am new in WinEdt so sorry for the question. It's work