# Highlight elements in the matrix (continued)

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, framed, highlighting

Using @Stefan Kottwitz's solution of  [Highlight elements in the matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40028/), is it possible to
select one single entry in the matrix? Where does one need to place the left and the right marks?

Comment: For one element you don't need to `\tikzmark` it, put directly the entry inside a tikz node, say, `\tikz[baseline] \node {<the node content>};`, possibly adjusting the `inner sep` of the node etc.

Answer (score 4):

For a single element you don't need to use external mechanisms but a node option instead via `|[....]|`. This will pass the options to the cell as node options. A simple example taken from the linked question:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=)] (m)
        {
            8 &8 &1 &6 \\
            3 &8 &5 &7 \\
            4 &8 &9 &|[draw=red,fill=blue!10,outer sep=0,inner sep=2pt]|5 \\
        };  
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]