# How to make frame in matrix?

Tags: arrays

I want to draw :
[image]

I have tried to make this by the following command :

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{geometry,tikz,amsmath}



\begin{document}

$$J_5=\left(\begin{array}{ccc} \lambda & 1 & 0\\ 0 & \lambda & 0\\ 0 & 0 & \frame{$\lambda$} \end{array}\right)
$$

\end{document}
```

But this gives :
[image]
How can I do so ?

Comment: Since the "what you want" picture is not there, I can only guess.  Do you want a `\fbox` instead of a `\frame`

Comment: I want to make the matrix shown in the first picture.How can I use \fbox.Plese give an example with array.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but I just noticed that even though you have up-voted answers, you still haven't accepted any of the answers to your questions (up-voting and accepting are two different actions). Please consider revisiting your questions and accepting, for each of them, the answer that you consider best solved your problem. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Comment: FYI: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40028/highlight-elements-in-the-matrix

Comment: I had in mind literally replacing the `\frame` with a `\fbox`.  That will frame a single entry with a border that frame did not provide, but is not directly usable when multi-element blocks of the array are to be framed.

Comment: I don't think you can frame some items in the array with such a syntax. Note how all answers, both here and in Papiro's link, either draw the frame line by line, or draw the matrix first and the frame afterwards. The reason is that the framing command will hide the alignment characters from the bigger `array` environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are loading `tikz`, I assume a tikz solution is fine.

It makes use of two `tikz` libraries: `matrix` for the matrix (the syntax is very close to the usual syntax for tabulars, arrays or matrices, with a lot of optional parameters to tweak the final output), and `fit` to draw rectangles around sets of nodes.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{geometry,tikz,amsmath}

\usetikzlibrary{fit,matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  J_{5}=
  \tikz[baseline=(M.west)]{%
    \node[matrix of math nodes,matrix anchor=west,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=),ampersand replacement=\&] (M) {%
      \lambda \& 1 \& 0 \\
      0 \& \lambda \& 0 \\
      0 \& 0 \& \lambda \\
    };
    \node[draw,fit=(M-1-1)(M-2-2),inner sep=-1pt] {};
    \node[draw,fit=(M-3-3),inner sep=-1pt] {};
  }
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

A TikZ-free possibility:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
J_5=
\left(
\begin{array}{|cc|c@{}c|} 
\cline{1-2}
\lambda & 1 & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} \\
0 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\lambda} & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} \\
\cline{1-2}\cline{4-4}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} & & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\lambda} \\
\cline{4-4}
\end{array}
\right)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for a solution that doesn't require too many packages and that should work on any latex install. The drawbacks appear when you notice that you have accidentally swapped the big and small rectangles, though. `;)`

Comment: @T.Verron hehe! Fixed.