# Is there any way to get something like pmatrix with customizable grid lines between cells?

Tags: math-mode, diagrams, matrices

In the document I have to describe a series of transformations, made with a matrix. Each transformation works only on 2x2 or 1x1 block, so I want to visually select this block in the matrix like this:

[image: pmatrix with a rectangle selected]

I can type the matrix using the pmatrix environment, but I don't know, how to draw the rectangle. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Perhaps the following is helpful/sufficient/duplicate: [Highlight elements in the matrix](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40028/5764)

Comment: @Werner, the link you provided was indeed very helpful. I managed to edit the code, provided in the question you linked to do what I wanted. For the sake of reference I wrote thus obtained code in the answer below. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

My question was indeed close to duplicate as was hinted by @Werner .
For the sake of reference I provide the code, which draws what I wanted. The code was created after analyzing [the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40044/475), linked by @Werner.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
    \matrix [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=)] (m)
    {
        \!1 & 0 & 0\!\!\! \\ \!0 & {P_\theta \otimes P} & 0\!\!\! \\ \!0 & 0 & 0\!\!\! \\
    };
    \draw (m-1-1.north west) -- (m-1-3.north west) -- (m-3-3.north west) -- (m-3-1.north west) -- (m-1-1.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The following code should be included in the preamble.

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,matrix,positioning}
```

This gives the following.

[image: the resulted image is good enough]