# putting frame on a column of a matrix

Tags: equations

I have a matrix written as following:

```
\begin{equation}
 A={
 \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & -1 & 0  & 0 & 0 & \dots\\
0 &  1 & -1 & 0 & 0 &\dots\\ 
1 &  0 & -1 & 0 & 0 &\dots\\
0 &  0 &  1 & -1 & 0 &\dots\\
1 &  0 &  0 & -1 & 0 &\dots\\
0 &  0 &  0 &  1 & -1 &\dots\\
. &  . &  . & . &  . &\dots\\
. &  . &  . & . &  . &\dots\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

I would like to have a box which frames the content of the forth column from its forth row to the end. I am wondering how it should be done?! I will appreciate for a help.

Comment: Possible duplicate -- http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40028/34618

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way with using a `\smash`ed `\fbox` around a dropped `\rule`.  EDITED to provide a colored box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor}
\fboxrule=1pt
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 A=
 \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & -1 & 0  & 0 & 0 & \dots\\
0 &  1 & -1 & 0 & 0 &\dots\\ 
1 &  0 & -1 & 0 & 0 &\dots\\
0 &  0 &  1 & \smash{\color{red}\fbox{\color{black}\rule[-50pt]{0pt}{1pt}$-1$}} & 0 &\dots\\
1 &  0 &  0 & -1 & 0 &\dots\\
0 &  0 &  0 &  1 & -1 &\dots\\
. &  . &  . & . &  . &\dots\\
. &  . &  . & . &  . &\dots\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And if you wanted the matrix entries right aligned, you could use a `tabstack`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine,xcolor}
\def\mykern{\kern-\fboxsep\kern-\fboxrule}
\def\cfbox#1{\mykern\smash{\color{red}\protect\fbox{\color{black}#1}\mykern}}
\fboxrule=1pt
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 A=
\setstacktabbedgap{1.5ex}
\renewcommand\stackalignment{r}
 \parenMatrixstack{ 
1 & -1 & 0  & 0 & 0 & \dots\\
0 &  1 & -1 & 0 & 0 &\dots\\ 
1 &  0 & -1 & 0 & 0 &\dots\\
0 &  0 &  1 & \cfbox{\protect\rule[-50pt]{0pt}{1pt}$-1$} & 0 &\dots\\
1 &  0 &  0 & -1 & 0 &\dots\\
0 &  0 &  0 &  1 & -1 &\dots\\
. &  . &  . & . &  . &\dots\\
. &  . &  . & . &  . &\dots
}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Looks like exactly what I am looking for, but is there any way to change the colour of the box too?

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes: You also can  have a right-aligned matrix with the `pmatrix*` environment from `mathtools`.

Answer (score 4):

With `tikzmark`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node[minimum width=1.5em] (#1) {#2};}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 A=
 \begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0  & 0 & 0 & \dots\\
0 &  1 & -1 & 0 & 0 &\dots\\
1 &  0 & -1 & 0 & 0 &\dots\\
0 &  0 &  1 & \tikzmark{a}{$-1$} & 0 &\dots\\
1 &  0 &  0 & -1 & 0 &\dots\\
0 &  0 &  0 &  1 & -1 &\dots\\
. &  . &  . & . &  . &\dots\\
. &  . &  . & \tikzmark{b}{.} &  . &\dots\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]\draw[thick,red] (a.north west) rectangle (b.south east);
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was able to get the correct vertical alignment by adding `anchor=base` in the node options: `tikzmark` is then defined as `\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node[anchor=base] (#1) {#2};` (I also removed the minimum width for my purposes)