# Drawing braces in equations

Tags: equations, braces

I am pretty new in this forum. It's my first post. So I hope I don't break any rules or so.

My Question is:
I have an equation, which contains already a pics, because I wanted to mark some stuff in my equation. Now I want to underbrace some parts of my equation but I can't put the brace on the right spot, even if I change the coordinates. The code for the equation is given below.

Thank You for your help!

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,matrix,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\bm{Bu}=    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-.5ex]current bounding box.center)},vertex/.style={anchor=base,
    circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=18pt,inner sep=2pt}]  
    \matrix [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter={[},right delimiter={]}] (m)
    {
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\ 
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\ 
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
        \times & \times & \times & \times  \\ 
        \times & \times & \times & \times  \\ 
        \times & \times & \times & \times  \\ 
        \times & \times & \times & \times  \\
    };
    \draw[color=red] (m-1-3.north west) -- (m-1-3.north east) -- (m-8-3.south east) --              (m-8-3.south west) -- (m-1-3.north west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-.5ex]current bounding box.center)},vertex/.style={anchor=base,
    circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=18pt,inner sep=2pt}]
    \matrix [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=)] (m)
    {
    0 \\
    0 \\ 
    \times \\ 
    0 \\
    };
    \draw[color=red] (m-3-1.north west) -- (m-3-1.north east) -- (m-3-1.south east) --              (m-3-1.south west) -- (m-3-1.north west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [thick, black,decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt,mirror},xshift=0.4pt,yshift=-0.4pt](0,10) -- (10,10) node[black,midway,yshift=-0.6cm] {\footnotesize $Form aus der\\Literatur$};  
    \end{tikzpicture}
    =
    \underbrace{
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \times \\ \times \\ \times \\ \times
    \end{pmatrix}
    \times}_{\substack{\text{Ausgabe aus} \\ \text{Simpack}}}
\label{eq:problem-state}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I removed your tikz constructs and replaced them with something I found in  [another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218152/putting-frame-on-a-column-of-a-matrix) and everything worked fine by using the normal `\underbrace`

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\def\mykern{\kern-\fboxsep\kern-\fboxrule}
\def\cfbox#1{\mykern\smash{\protect\fbox{#1}\mykern}}
\fboxrule=1pt
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\bm{Bu}=
\underbrace{
    \left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
    0 & 0 & \cfbox{\protect\rule[-96pt]{0pt}{1pt}$0$} & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0  & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0  & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0  & 0 \\
    \times & \times & \times & \times \\
    \times & \times & \times & \times \\
    \times & \times & \times & \times \\
    \times & \times & \times & \times \\
\end{array}\right]
\left(\begin{array}{c}
    0\\0\\ \cfbox{\protect\rule[0pt]{0pt}{1pt}$\times$}\\0
    \end{array}\right)}_{\footnotesize \text{Form aus der Literatur}}
=\underbrace{\left(\begin{array}{c}
0\\0\\ 0\\0\\\times\\\times\\\times\\\times
\end{array}\right)\times}_{\footnotesize\text{Ausgabe aus Simpack}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It looks really neat, the only thing I would like to change is to put the Matrix in square brackets. I can't find a was to do that.

Comment: Oh yes, I changed it. The matrix is now more intuitiv set using array.

Answer (score 4):

Following solution uses your `TikZ` code but with some minor corrections.
Now both matrices are inside the same figure and also the lower braces. To correctly align them inside the equation, `(m1.west)` is the `baseline` point.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,matrix,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\bm{Bu}=    
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(m1.west),vertex/.style={anchor=base,
    circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=18pt,inner sep=2pt}]  
    \matrix [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter={[},right delimiter={]}] (m1)
    {
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\ 
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\ 
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
        \times & \times & \times & \times  \\ 
        \times & \times & \times & \times  \\ 
        \times & \times & \times & \times  \\ 
        \times & \times & \times & \times  \\
    };
    \draw[color=red] (m1-1-3.north west) rectangle (m1-8-3.south east);
    \matrix [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=), right= 7mm of m1] (m2)
    {
    0 \\
    0 \\ 
    \times \\ 
    0 \\
    };
    \draw[color=red] (m2-3-1.north west) rectangle (m2-3-1.south east);
    \draw [thick, black,decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt,mirror}]([shift={(-2mm,-1mm)}]m1.south west) -- ([shift={(2mm,-1mm)}]m1.south-|m2.east) node[black,midway,yshift=-0.7cm, font=\footnotesize, align=center] {Form aus der\\Literatur};  
    \end{tikzpicture}
    =
    \underbrace{
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \times \\ \times \\ \times \\ \times
    \end{pmatrix}
    \times}_{\substack{\text{Ausgabe aus} \\ \text{Simpack}}}
\label{eq:problem-state}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]