# Referencing parts of equations within a tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have an equation in a tikz environment and I would like to be able to highlight part of it. For example the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,latexsym}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}


\tikzstyle{block} = [draw,fill=blue!60,minimum width=1.1 em, minimum height= 1em, rounded corners= 4pt]

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate  (Eq1) at (1,2);
    \coordinate  (Eq2) at (1,1);

    \node[block] at (1,2) (block1) {};
    \node at (Eq1) {$A =  B + C$};
    \node at (Eq2) {$D = E + F$};

    \node[block] at (0, -0.5) (block2) {Blah};
    \draw[->] (block1) -- (block2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

However, it is a huge pain to by hand play around with the node placement of the blocks to highlight the corresponding part of the equation. I'd like a way to specify the node. Attempting to do such, I played around with \tikz{\node} within the equation but to no avail as follows

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,latexsym}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}


\tikzstyle{block} = [draw,fill=blue!60,minimum width=1.1 em, minimum height= 1em, rounded corners= 4pt]

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate  (Eq1) at (1,2);
    \coordinate  (Eq2) at (1,1);

%\node[block] at (1,2) (block1) {};
    \node at (Eq1) {$A =  \tikz{ \node[fill=blue!60, rounded corners = 4pt, minimum size = 1 em]
        (block1) {$B$};} + C$};
    \node at (Eq2) {$D = E + F$};

    \node[block] at (0, -0.5) (block2) {Blah};
    \draw[->] (block1) -- (block2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The B is no longer aligned with the other parts of the equation and the arrow is stuck in the second block. Can you suggest a good way to go about doing this? Thanks!

**EDIT**
Based on the first response (Thanks by the way!) I want to add that at this point I'd like to still do this all within a tikz picture. For my paired down example below I know it make senses to just do \begin\end{equation} but for my actual application I'm hoping to have a lot more going on and just this one equation arbitrarily placed in a bigger diagram. Maybe this can be done still using the usual latex equation commands but it seems more natural to approach having it within a tike picture

Comment: Looks like you could use the infamous `\tikzmark`, or at the very least, add `remember picture` to your `tikzpicture` environment. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40333/18228

Comment: Never load `latexsym` along with `amssymb`.

Comment: You can also use [`hf-tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hf-tikz) package to highlight parts of equations, arrays, ... It uses `tikzmark` and offers easily customizable boxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following answer builds on your second attempt, and uses a `\tikzmark`-like command to achieve the annotation effect.

## Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\mytikzmark[3][]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#2.base)]{\node(#2)[outer sep=0pt,#1]{#3};}%
}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{block/.style={draw,fill=blue!60,minimum width=1.1 em, minimum height= 1em, rounded corners= 4pt}}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \draw[help lines](-2,-1)grid(3,3); % shows background

    \coordinate  (Eq1) at (1,2);
    \coordinate  (Eq2) at (1,1);

    \node at (Eq1) {$A = \mytikzmark[block]{block1}{$B$}+ C$};
    \node at (Eq2) {$D = E + F$};

    \node[block] at (0, -0.5) (block2) {Blah};
    \draw[->] (block1) -- (block2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

I can also refer to \verb+(block1)+ outside of the figure like \mytikzmark[block]{block3}{this}.
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\draw[->](block3)to[bend right](block1);}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

---

By the way, it's recommended that you use `\tikzset` instead of the deprecated `\tikzstyle`.

Comment: (+1) But the `tikzmark` library is handy....

Comment: @cfr: Thanks. I have to confess that I'm not very familiar with the `tikzmark` library, as I don't use it on a regular basis. In this case, however, the `\subnode` command from the library doesn't allow styling such as `fill`. So I decided to create my own variant `:p`

Comment: Ah. That makes sense. I've not used the `\subnode` facility - only the `\tikzmark` which I think uses coordinates, and wrappers thereof.

Comment: Thanks, I will play round with this today. I think this is what I am looking for!

Comment: Awesome, I got to try it out and this is exactly what I was hoping for! For alignment purposes (i.e. that the two equations weren't left justified above) I found setting the same anchor helped, i.e. [anchor = west] on both. Is there any reason I shouldn't use that in combination with everything else? Thanks so much

Comment: @Fractal20: Glad it worked. I don't think there is any reason that setting anchors would cause conflicts.

Answer (score 3):

1. Don't use nodes to manually align stuff that LaTeX already knows how to align. Put equations into `align` environments. It's ok to put `tikzpicture`s into equations. You don't need them to be in a `figure`.
2. As Herr K. points out, use `overlay` and `remember picture`. You can read about these options in `pgfmanual.pdf`, section 17.13.1.

Here is my solution:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}


\tikzset{
    block/.style = {draw,fill=blue!60,rounded corners= 4pt}
}

\begin{align}
    A &= \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(B.base)] \node[block] (B) at (0,0) {B}; + C\\
    D &= E + F
\end{align}


\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[block] (Blah) at (0,0) {Blah};
    \draw (B) -- (Blah);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do this within a tikz picture? For example, say I wanted this original set of equations in an arbitrary place (not centered as equation will do). I'd still like to have the freedom to be able to specify the location of the equations using a node or something similar. Thanks, this is certainly already helpful!

Comment: @Fractal20 I wouldn't know how to do that. It doesn't seem a good idea and try to put the `align` inside of a `\node`. The only thing that comes to my mind is using matrices. Look at the question linked in Herr K.'s answer, and at section 57 in the pgfmanual. It would help if you could say how arbitrary you need to place them. For example if it's just a matter of having 2 or 3 sets of equations next to each other, that's something `align` can still manage.