# How to make box in a row of a table

Tags: tables

I want to make a box in second row. That is on 1 & 3 & 24 & 42 & 43.
Also on part of forth row 5 & 16 & 26 & 34.

```
 \begin{tabular}{| c | c  c  c  c | } 
      \hline
      Location & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Rounds}\\ 
       \hline
        0 &  2 &  23 &  41 &  42\\
    1 &  3 &  24 &  42 &  43\\
    2 &  4 &  25 &  43 &  44\\
    3 &  5 &  16 &  26 &  34\\
    4 &  6 &  17 &  27 &  35\\
    \hline
   \end{tabular}
```

Comment: This is actually no different from [Highlight elements in the matrix](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40028/5764). Could you use some of those techniques and get back to us?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are better ways, as Werner alludes to, but here is a quick way, if you don't need to use it often (since the box width must be tailored to the content).

I have stuffed it into a macro `\boxit{<width>}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\boxit#1{%
  \smash{\fboxsep=0pt\llap{\rlap{\fbox{\strut\makebox[#1]{}}}~}}\ignorespaces
}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tabular}{| c | c  c  c  c | } 
      \hline
      Location & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Rounds}\\ 
       \hline
        0 &  2 &  23 &  41 &  42\\
    \boxit{1.52in} 1 &  3 &  24 &  42 &  43\\
    2 &  4 &  25 &  43 &  44\\
    3 &  5 &  \boxit{0.81in} 16 &  26 &  34\\
    4 &  6 &  17 &  27 &  35\\
    \hline
   \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If your `tabular` data is purely numeric, one could trim the height of the box to be symmetric about the numerals (the above solution uses a `\strut` which allows extra depth for descenders).  I also make the box in red, with a thicker (1pt) rule.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\boxit#1{%
  \smash{\color{red}\fboxrule=1pt\relax\fboxsep=2pt\relax%
  \llap{\rlap{\fbox{\vphantom{0}\makebox[#1]{}}}~}}\ignorespaces
}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tabular}{| c | c  c  c  c | } 
      \hline
      Location & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Rounds}\\ 
       \hline
        0 &  2 &  23 &  41 &  42\\
    \boxit{1.47in} 1 &  3 &  24 &  42 &  43\\
    2 &  4 &  25 &  43 &  44\\
    3 &  5 &  \boxit{0.77in} 16 &  26 &  34\\
    4 &  6 &  17 &  27 &  35\\
    \hline
   \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it possible to make it red box?

Comment: @user12290 I have to depart at the moment, but will do so upon my return.

Comment: @user12290  But to do so is easy.  `\usepackage{xcolor}` in the preamble, and add `\color{red}` just inside the `\smash` argument, as in `\smash{\color{red}...}`

Comment: @user12290 ... and `\fboxrule=1pt\relax` will make the box rule thicker.