# How to create a box spanning across rows and columns of a table

Tags: tables, box

Starting from this thread [How to make box in a row of a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237325/how-to-make-box-in-a-row-of-a-table). I'm also aware of [Highlight elements in the matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40028/highlight-elements-in-the-matrix) I'm just wondering if there is any quick way like this to create a box spanning across rows and columns rather than having to use `TikZ`

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\boxit#1{%
  \smash{\color{red}\fboxrule=1pt\relax\fboxsep=2pt\relax%
  \llap{\rlap{\fbox{\vphantom{0}\makebox[#1]{}}}~}}\ignorespaces
}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tabular}{| c | c  c  c  c | } 
      \hline
      Location & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Rounds}\\ 
       \hline
        0 &  2 &  23 &  41 &  42\\
    \boxit{1.47in} 1 &  3 &  24 &  42 &  43\\
    2 &  4 &  25 &  43 &  44\\
    3 &  5 &  \boxit{0.77in} 16 &  26 &  34\\
    4 &  6 &  17 &  27 &  35\\
    \hline
   \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you look at the question the question you linked is a duplicate of? It's right there..

Comment: Many thanks. I'm aware of [Highlight elements in the matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40028/highlight-elements-in-the-matrix) I'm just wondering if there is any quick way like this to create a box spanning across rows and columns rather than having to use  `TikZ`.

Comment: What do you mean? There are many different solutions there, not all of them using TikZ. The fact that all of the top voted ones use TikZ is not a coincidence though, it's just very easy with TikZ. Why do you not want to use TikZ? Why are the alternatives in the other question not adequate?

Comment: I'm just a bit curious as how to modify the provided code to make a box spanning across both rows and columns rather than just columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifying the given macro to accept a height in addition to a width is easy enough. I do not understand why you would want to do this, though. It is much easier to follow the approaches given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40028/highlight-elements-in-the-matrix) than to manually specify width and height of the box, which is subject to change depending on factors like font, font size, table content etc. But if you insist..

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\def\boxit#1#2{%
    \smash{\color{red}\fboxrule=1pt\relax\fboxsep=2pt\relax%
    \llap{\rlap{\fbox{\phantom{\rule{#1}{#2}}}}~}}\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{| c | c  c  c  c | } 
    \hline
    Location & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Rounds}\\ 
    \hline
    0 &  2 &  23 &  41 &  42\\
    \boxit{1.47in}{.1in} 1 &  3 &  24 &  42 &  43\\
    2 &  4 &  25 &  43 &  44\\
    3 &  5 &  16 &  26 &  34\\
    4 &  6 &  \boxit{0.77in}{.26in}17 &  27 &  35\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: Many thanks for this. I don't need to use it often so I simply prefer a quick way like this.