# How to create a multirow red box for highlighting table results?

Tags: tables

I am trying to create a red box that covers multiple rows and columns for highlighting sections of a table.

I have created a MWE using @Steven B. Slegetes [answer to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237325/how-to-make-box-in-a-row-of-a-table). The code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}

%Create Red Boxes, Thanks Steven
\def\boxit#1{%
  \smash{\color{red}\fboxrule=1pt\relax\fboxsep=2pt\relax%
  \llap{\rlap{\fbox{\vphantom{0}\makebox[#1]{}}}~}}\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{Red Box Test}
    \vspace{0.5em}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
                          & A & B & C \\\toprule
                        I & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
         \boxit{0.4in}  J & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
                        K & 7 & 8 & 9 \\\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Which creates the following table:

[image]

Question: How do I get this to cover the row that begins with K *as well as* the row with J? I figured it must have something to with the multirow package, hence my including it. I have tried playing around with it to no avail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to use `tikz` with its `tikzmark` library, which can mark arbitrary points on a page and then draw pictures based on the coordinates of the marked points. An example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Red Box Test}
\vspace{0.5em}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
  & A & B & C \\\toprule
I & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\tikzmark{J}J & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
K & 7\tikzmark{7} & 8 & 9 \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \draw[red] ([shift={(-1ex,2ex)}]pic cs:J) rectangle ([shift={(1ex,-0.5ex)}]pic cs:7);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I have **edited** this answer because, since version 5.5 (2020-10-20), one must no longer write `\omit\CodeAfter` here (now, `\CodeAfter` works in all circonstancies).

---

You can do that with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. This environment creates PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells of the array and it's possible to use that nodes after the construction of the array.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Red Box Test}
\vspace{0.5em}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}
  & A & B & C \\\toprule
I & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
J & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
K & 7 & 8 & 9 \\\bottomrule
\CodeAfter
\tikz \node [draw=red, fit = (3-1) (4-2)] { } ;
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Why is the omit needed here ?

Comment: @projetmbc: Without the `\omit`, there is, in fact, a complete row after the `\bottomrule`. I have not found yet the solution to avoid the need of that `\omit` in all the situations...

Comment: Ok. Merci beaucoup.

Answer (score 5):

A (very) small variation of the @Sergei Golovan [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/566174/how-to-create-a-multirow-red-box-for-highlighting-table-results/566176#566176). From the `tikzmark` library is used `\tikzmarknode` macro, box is drawn by node which fit marked nodes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,            % new
                tikzmark}       % new
\tikzset{FIT/.style = {draw=red, thick, inner ysep=2pt, fit=#1}} % new
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[skip=0.33\lineskip]{caption} % new

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Red Box Test}
\label{tab:redbox}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
                    & A                 & B & C \\
    \toprule
I                   & 1                 & 2 & 3 \\
\tikzmarknode{J}J   & 4                 & 5 & 6 \\  % <---
K                   & 7\tikzmarknode{7} & 8 & 9 \\  % <---
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node[FIT=(J) (7)] {};  % <---
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A solution with `pstricks`: two empty nodes, and a `\psframe` joining these nodes.

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{Red Box Test}
    \vspace{0.5em}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
                          & A & B & C \\\toprule
                      I & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
          \pnode[-1.5ex, 2.5ex]{A}J & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
                        K & 7\pnode[1.5ex, -1ex]{B} & 8 & 9 \\\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\psframe[linecolor=Coral](A)(B)
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]