# Highlighting inside NiceTabular causes boxes to go outside rules

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, nicematrix

I tried to duplicate the result of the table in [How to create a multirow red box for highlighting table results?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/566174/how-to-create-a-multirow-red-box-for-highlighting-table-results/566177#566177) using `NiceTabular` and `tikz`. The solution works well as long as `cell-space-limits` is small. When increasing it, the result becomes

[image]

As you see, the box is very close to the contents of the second row and exceeds the bottomrule. One workaround is to add `\addlinespace`, but this is suboptimal solution because sometimes we might clearly see how rows spacing differs. Is it possible to get a better one?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits=1.1mm}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{Box Test}
    \centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}
          & A & B & C \\ \toprule
        I & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
        J & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
        K & 7 & 8 & 9 \\ \bottomrule
        \CodeAfter
        \tikz \node [draw=Coral3, fit = (3-1) (4-2)] { } ;
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{Box Test}
    \centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}
          & A & B & C \\ \toprule
        I & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \addlinespace
        J & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
        K & 7 & 8 & 9 \\ \addlinespace \bottomrule
        \CodeAfter
        \tikz \node [draw=Coral3, fit = (3-1) (4-2)] { } ;
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use the key `inner ysep` of Tikz in the node:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits=1.1mm}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{Box Test}
    \centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}
          & A & B & C \\ \toprule
        I & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
        J & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
        K & 7 & 8 & 9 \\ \bottomrule
        \CodeAfter
        \tikz \node [inner ysep = -0.9mm, draw=Coral3, fit = (3-1) (4-2)] { } ;
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]