# Highlight the upper or lower triangular portion of a matrix

Tags: matrices, highlighting

I previously asked this question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283677/how-to-shade-or-highlight-the-upper-or-lower-triangular-part-in-a-matrix), but now would like to achieve the same goal with a matrix under a different construction. More specifically, how can I highlight or shade the upper or lower triangular part of the following matrix?

[image]

The corresponding Latex code is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\begin{document}
$R = 
\begin{blockarray}{cccccc}
& S_1 & S_2 &  S_3 & ... & S_n \\
\begin{block}{c(ccccc)}
S_1 &  1 & r_{12} & r_{13} & ... & r_{1n} \\
S_2 &  r_{21} & 1 & r_{23} & ... & r_{2n} \\
S_3 &  r_{31} & r_{32} & 1 & ... & r_{3n} \\
\vdots &  \vdots & \vdots &\vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
S_n &  r_{n1} & r_{n2} & r_{n3} & ... & 1 \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray},$
\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the desired effect with TikZ(mark). I define the following variant of TikZmark:

```
\newcommand\tm[2][]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt]\node(#1){$#2$};}
```

It takes two arguments: the first sets the name and the second specifies the content. If you want to highlight the lower triangle of the matrix, use `\tm` at the top left, bottom left and bottom right element of the matrix. Then fit two nodes to these three elements and `\filldraw` the shaded triangle.

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\newcommand\tm[2][]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt]\node(#1){$#2$};}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\begin{document}
$R = 
\begin{blockarray}{cccccc}
& S_1 & S_2 &  S_3 & ... & S_n \\
\begin{block}{c(ccccc)}
S_1 &  \tm[a]{1} & r_{12} & r_{13} & ... & r_{1n} \\
S_2 &  r_{21} & 1 & r_{23} & ... & r_{2n} \\
S_3 &  r_{31} & r_{32} & 1 & ... & r_{3n} \\
\vdots &  \vdots & \vdots &\vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
S_n &  \tm[b]{r_{n1}} & r_{n2} & r_{n3} & ... & \tm[c]{1} \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray},$
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
  \node(x)[fit=(a) (b),inner sep=0pt]{};
  \node(y)[fit=(b) (c),inner sep=0pt]{};
  \filldraw[rounded corners,opacity=.2,green](x.north west)--(x.south west)--(y.south east)--(y.north east)--(x.north east)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: This is great! Thanks a lot. How can I modify your code so that the diagonals are excluded?

Comment: @bluepole: use `\tm` at `r_{21}` and `\dots` at the bottom row instead of the two `1`s.

Comment: Got it! Thanks again for the wonderful solution.

Answer (score 3):

I often highlight matrix parts by using different colors for the elements.
You can use the xcolor package and simplify the process with \newcommand.

[Minimal Working Example](https://www.latex4technics.com/?note=7yc0f):

```
 \documentclass{article}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \usepackage{blkarray}
    \usepackage{xcolor}

    \newcommand\RED{\color{red}}
    \newcommand\BLUE{\color{blue}}

    \begin{document}
    $R = 
    \begin{blockarray}{cccccc}
    & S_1 & S_2 &  S_3 & ... & S_n \\
    \begin{block}{c(ccccc)}
    S_1 &  1 & \BLUE r_{12} & \BLUE r_{13} & \BLUE ... & \BLUE r_{1n} \\
    S_2 &  \RED r_{21} & 1 & \BLUE r_{23} & \BLUE ... &  \BLUE r_{2n} \\
    S_3 &  \RED r_{31} & \RED r_{32} & 1 &  \BLUE... & \BLUE r_{3n} \\
    \vdots &  \RED \vdots & \RED \vdots &\RED \vdots & \vdots & \BLUE \vdots\\
    S_n &  \RED r_{n1} & \RED r_{n2} & \RED r_{n3} & \RED ... & 1 \\
    \end{block}
    \end{blockarray}$
    \end{document}
```

If you want to change the background color, we have to think probably about a tikz solution

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. It looks good even though I prefer the background highlight.

Answer (score 1):

I created and saved a generic `tikz` triangle with opacity as `\lowertriangle`.  I then used `\stackinset` to lay it atop the `blockarray`, with suitable (empirically derived) scaling and clipping.

EDITED to add `\uppertriangle` with the upper part of the matrix highlighted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray,stackengine,tikz,trimclip}
\savestack\lowertriangle{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[outer sep=1in] (earmark) {};
  \draw[blue!40, fill, opacity=0.20] (earmark.south west) -- (earmark.south east) -- 
    (earmark.north west)-- (earmark.south west);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\savestack\uppertriangle{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[outer sep=1in] (earmark) {};
  \draw[blue!40, fill, opacity=0.20] (earmark.north west) -- (earmark.south east) -- 
    (earmark.north east)-- (earmark.north west);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
$R = 
\stackinset{r}{8pt}{b}{12pt}{%
\clipbox{0pt 0pt 12pt 7pt}{\scalebox{0.81}[0.48]{\lowertriangle}}}{$
\begin{blockarray}{cccccc}
& S_1 & S_2 &  S_3 & ... & S_n \\
\begin{block}{c(ccccc)}
S_1 &  1 & r_{12} & r_{13} & ... & r_{1n} \\
S_2 &  r_{21} & 1 & r_{23} & ... & r_{2n} \\
S_3 &  r_{31} & r_{32} & 1 & ... & r_{3n} \\
\vdots &  \vdots & \vdots &\vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
S_n &  r_{n1} & r_{n2} & r_{n3} & ... & 1 \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}$},$


$R = 
\stackinset{r}{7pt}{b}{12pt}{%
\clipbox{12pt 7pt 0pt 0pt}{\scalebox{0.81}[0.48]{\uppertriangle}}}{$
\begin{blockarray}{cccccc}
& S_1 & S_2 &  S_3 & ... & S_n \\
\begin{block}{c(ccccc)}
S_1 &  1 & r_{12} & r_{13} & ... & r_{1n} \\
S_2 &  r_{21} & 1 & r_{23} & ... & r_{2n} \\
S_3 &  r_{31} & r_{32} & 1 & ... & r_{3n} \\
\vdots &  \vdots & \vdots &\vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
S_n &  r_{n1} & r_{n2} & r_{n3} & ... & 1 \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}$},$
\end{document}
```

[image]