# How to have a dotted line separate a matrix into upper and lower part

Tags: matrices, tikz-matrix

So, here is what I want to do: 
I have created a matrix C and another Matrix D. And I have labelled the columns and rows. Now, I want to join these two matrices together, keeping the labels. But I want - I hope this is posssible - to have a dotted line go through the matrix, indicating where labels 'TX^C' end and where labels 'TX^D' start.

This is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\[\mathbf{J} = 
\begin{blockarray}{cccccc}
RB_1 & RB_2 & RB_3 & \dots & RB_m \\
\begin{block}{(ccccc)c}
1 & 0 & 1 & \dots & 0 & TX_1^C \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & TX_2^C \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots &  \\
&   &   &  &  &  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & TX_{max}^C \\
1 & 0 & 1 & \dots & 0 & TX_1^D \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & TX_2^D \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots &  \\
&   &   &  &  &  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & TX_{max}^D \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\]

\end{document}
```

Only the dotted line is missing. Alternatively, shading the background of the upper matrix in a light color would be nice as well. I have just read a similar question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283677/how-to-shade-or-highlight-the-upper-or-lower-triangular-part-in-a-matrix). But since I don't know LaTeX so well, I don't know if I want to overcomplicate things by making use of tikz.

Small Edit: 
What, if I want two vertical labels? I was trying this, for example:

```
\[\mathbf{Pairs} = 
\begin{blockarray}{cc}
Transmitter & Receiver \\
\begin{block}{c(cc)c}
TX_1^C & (x,y) & (x,y) & BS   \\
TX_2^C & (x,y) & (x,y) & BS     \\
&\vdots & \vdots  \\
TX_{max}^C & (x,y) & (x,y) & BS  \\
\BAhhline{......} 
TX_1^D & (x,y) & (x,y) &RX_1^D   \\
TX_2^D & (x,y) & (x,y) &RX_2^D   \\
&\vdots & \vdots   \\
TX_{ax}^D & (x,y) & (x,y) &RX_{max}^D  \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `blkarray` already offers several commands for different lines. One of them is `\BAhhline` where you can define the kind of line

```
\documentclass[a4paper12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\[\mathbf{J} = 
\begin{blockarray}{cccccc}
RB_1 & RB_2 & RB_3 & \dots & RB_m \\
\begin{block}{(ccccc)c}
1 & 0 & 1 & \dots & 0 & TX_1^C \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & TX_2^C \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots &  \\
&   &   &  &  &  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & TX_{max}^C \\
\BAhhline{......}
1 & 0 & 1 & \dots & 0 & TX_1^D \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & TX_2^D \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots &  \\
&   &   &  &  &  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & TX_{max}^D \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thx so much, Ignasi! This is exactly what I want. Just - see my edit - what if I only label the columns and not the rows? It doesn't seem to work the way I am trying to do it. I have included the extra `&` before the `\\` , because this is where usually there would be the labels. If I leave the `&`, at least I don't get an error. But the left bracket is far to much to the left

Comment: hmm... actually, let me correct this: Can you tell me a way of how to have two vertical labels? One on the right and one on the left ?

Comment: ok, nevermind. I have opened a new question for this. Thx so much for your help, again!

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`, you have keys `first-row`, `last-row`, `first-col` and `last-col` to specify exterior rows and columns and you can add a dashed rule by using `\Hline[tikz=dashed]` which draws the rule with TikZ.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\[\mathbf{J} = 
\begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-row,last-col=6]
RB_1 & RB_2 & RB_3 & \dots & RB_m \\
1 & 0 & 1 & \dots & 0 & TX_1^C \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & TX_2^C \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots &  \\
&   &   &  &  &  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & TX_{max}^C \\
\Hline[tikz=dashed]
1 & 0 & 1 & \dots & 0 & TX_1^D \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & TX_2^D \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots &  \\
&   &   &  &  &  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & TX_{max}^D \\
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the first code]

By default, the rules are not drawn in the exterior rows and columns. If you want the dashed rule in the last column also, you have to use another technic. Using `{NiceArray}` and specify the position of the rounded brackets directly in the preamble of that `{NiceArray}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\[\mathbf{J} = 
\begin{NiceArray}{(ccccc)c}[first-row]
RB_1 & RB_2 & RB_3 & \dots & RB_m \\
1 & 0 & 1 & \dots & 0 & TX_1^C \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & TX_2^C \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots &  \\
&   &   &  &  &  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & TX_{max}^C \\
\Hline[tikz=dashed]
1 & 0 & 1 & \dots & 0 & TX_1^D \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & TX_2^D \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots &  \\
&   &   &  &  &  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & TX_{max}^D \\
\end{NiceArray}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

If you want more space on both sides of the dashed, you have to use the key `total-width` for the command `\Hline`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\[\mathbf{J} = 
\begin{NiceArray}{(ccccc)c}[first-row]
RB_1 & RB_2 & RB_3 & \dots & RB_m \\
1 & 0 & 1 & \dots & 0 & TX_1^C \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & TX_2^C \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots &  \\
&   &   &  &  &  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & TX_{max}^C \\
\Hline[tikz=dashed,total-width=2mm]
1 & 0 & 1 & \dots & 0 & TX_1^D \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & TX_2^D \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots &  \\
&   &   &  &  &  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & TX_{max}^D \\
\end{NiceArray}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

The package `nicematrix` provides also tools to improve the dotted rules.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions{xdots/shorten=6pt}

\[\mathbf{J} = 
\begin{NiceArray}{(ccccc)c}[first-row,renew-dots]
RB_1 & RB_2 & RB_3 & \dots & RB_m \\
1 & 0 & 1 & \dots & 0 & TX_1^C \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & TX_2^C \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots &  \\
&   &   &  &  &  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & TX_{max}^C \\
\Hline[tikz=dashed,total-width=2mm]
1 & 0 & 1 & \dots & 0 & TX_1^D \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & TX_2^D \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots &  \\
&   &   &  &  &  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & TX_{max}^D \\
\end{NiceArray}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]