# Dividing a matrix with lines

Tags: amsmath, matrices

What do I use to divide the matrix into a vertical line and a horizontal line?

```
\begin{equation*}
 A= 
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
d & e & f & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
g & h & i & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
a & b & c & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
d & e & f & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
a & b & c & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
d & e & f & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
g & h & i & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
a & b & c & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
d & e & f & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
d & e & f & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
g & h & i & a & b & c & a & a & a & a 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
```

Comment: Please remember to post only code, which compiles when we copied it. Thank you

Comment: does this help - https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/459295/how-to-have-a-dotted-line-separate-a-matrix-into-upper-and-lower-part?rq=1

Comment: Where should the vertical and horizontal lines be placed?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you switch from the `bmatrix` environment to an `array` environment. The third matrix in the following screenshot has vertical lines after columns 3 and 6, and horizontal lines after rows 3, 6, and 9.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' env.

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
A &= 
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
d & e & f & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
g & h & i & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
a & b & c & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
d & e & f & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
a & b & c & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
d & e & f & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
g & h & i & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
a & b & c & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
d & e & f & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
d & e & f & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
g & h & i & a & b & c & a & a & a & a 
\end{bmatrix} \\
&= 
\left[ \begin{array}{@{} *{10}{c} @{}} % switch to an 'array' setup
a & b & c & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
d & e & f & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
g & h & i & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
a & b & c & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
d & e & f & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
a & b & c & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
d & e & f & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
g & h & i & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
a & b & c & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
d & e & f & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
d & e & f & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
g & h & i & a & b & c & a & a & a & a 
\end{array} \right] \\
&\approx 
\left[ \begin{array}{@{} ccc | ccc | cccc @{}} % add vertical and horizontal lines
a & b & c & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
d & e & f & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
g & h & i & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
\hline
a & b & c & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
d & e & f & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
a & b & c & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
\hline
d & e & f & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
g & h & i & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
a & b & c & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
\hline
d & e & f & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
d & e & f & a & b & c & a & a & a & a \\
g & h & i & a & b & c & a & a & a & a 
\end{array} \right]
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```