# Divide a matrix into two regions in latex by line and color

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, tikz-matrix

I have a matrix whose elements belong to two different classes, and I need to distinguish them by color. Something like this figure:
[image]

Any tutorial or instruction?

Comment: have you checked http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40028/highlight-elements-in-the-matrix ?

Comment: That's almost what I needed. Thanks.
Shall I remove this question, or what?

Comment: Ah glad that it is useful. We can close as duplicate if you agree

Comment: yeap, let's close it