# Draw border for just one cell in a table

Tags: tables, rules

How can I draw border for just one cell in a simple table?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{booktabs ,float}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Test Set }
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
        \hline\hline

        \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Train}}&  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Test}}\\
        \cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(r){3-4} 
        \textbf{A}  & \textbf{\# D} & \textbf{\# E} & \textbf{\# E} \\
        \hline
        B & 9.6 & 62.8& 62.8 \\
        C & 12.0 & 78.9 & 62.8 \\
        C & 12.0 & 78.9 & 62.8 \\           
        \hline
    \end{tabular}       
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{booktabs ,float}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
    \caption{Test Set }
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
        \hline\hline

        \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Train}}&  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Test}}\\
        \cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(r){3-4}
        \textbf{A}  & \textbf{\# D} & \textbf{\# E} & \textbf{\# E} \\
        \hline
        B & 9.6 & 62.8& 62.8 \\
        C & 12.0 & \fbox{78.9} & 62.8 \\
        C & 12.0 & 78.9 & 62.8 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

i would use rules from `booktabs` for all horizontal rules in table not just one ...

Comment: You might increase \arraystretch (macro, not length).  I believe the default for tabular is 1.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, you have right. i will add `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}` .  tank you very much for point.

Answer (score 1):

You can box the content with `\fbox`. To ensure vertical alignment doesn't change

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\newcommand{\boxnum}[2][table-format=2.1]{\smash{\fbox{\vphantom{#2}\tablenum[#1]{#2}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ c *{3}{S[table-format=2.1]} }
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Train}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Test}} \\
  \cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(l){3-4}
  {\textbf{A}} & {\textbf{\# D}} & {\textbf{\# E}} & {\textbf{\# E}} \\
  \midrule
  B & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\boxnum{9.6}} & 62.8 & 62.8  \\
  C & 12.0 & 78.9 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\boxnum{62.8}} \\
  C & 12.0 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\boxnum{78.9}} & 62.8 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

You can also use `tabular` rules to frame an element:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ c *{3}{S[table-format=2.1]} }
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Train}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Test}} \\
  \cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(l){3-4}
  {\textbf{A}} & {\textbf{\# D}} & {\textbf{\# E}} & {\textbf{\# E}} \\
  \midrule
  \cline{2-2}
  B & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\tablenum[table-format=2.1]{9.6}} & 62.8 & 62.8  \\
  \cline{2-2}
  C & 12.0 & 78.9 & 62.8 \\
  \cline{4-4}
  C & 12.0 & 78.9 & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{62.8} \\
  \cline{4-4}
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Related: [Highlight elements in the matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40028/5764)