# Beautiful matrices in latex when having bigger equations (alignment)

Tags: matrices

I'm new to LaTeX and was wondering if there is a more beautiful way to have the matrices aligned than below?

Below is a sample code from the picture above[image]:

```
\begin{alignat*}{2}
&\!\begin{aligned}
&\ro{r_1 \rightarrow r_1 - r_2a }\\
&\ro{r_3 \rightarrow r_3 - r_2(3-a) }\\
\end{aligned}
\begin{sysmatrix}{rrr|r}
 1 &  0 & 2 & -\frac{2a}{a^2-2}  \\
 0 &  1 & 0 & \frac{a^2}{a^2-2} \\
 0 &  0 & -2 & \frac{1}{a^2-2}(-a^2+2a-4)
\end{sysmatrix}
&\!\begin{aligned}
&\ro{r_1 \rightarrow r_1 + r_3 }\\
\end{aligned}
\begin{sysmatrix}{rrr|r}
 1 &  0 & 2 & -\frac{a^2+4}{a^2-2}  \\
 0 &  1 & 0 & \frac{a^2}{a^2-2} \\
 0 &  0 & -2 & \frac{1}{a^2-2}(-a^2+2a-4)
\end{sysmatrix}
\end{alignat*}


\begin{alignat*}{2}
&\!\begin{aligned}
&\ro{r_3 \rightarrow \frac{r_3}{-2} }\\
\end{aligned}
\begin{sysmatrix}{rrr|r}
1 &  0 & 0 & -\frac{a^2+4}{a^2-2}  \\
 0 &  1 & 0 & \frac{a^2}{a^2-2} \\
 0 &  0 & 1 & \frac{\frac{a^2}{2}-a+2}{a^2-2}
\end{sysmatrix}
\end{alignat*}


\begin{alignat*}{2}
\begin{sysmatrix}{rrr|r}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3
\end{sysmatrix}
&\!\begin{aligned}
&{=}\\
\end{aligned}
\begin{sysmatrix}{rrr|r}
-\frac{a^2+4}{a^2-2}  \\
\frac{a^2}{a^2-2} \\
\frac{\frac{a^2}{2}-a+2}{a^2-2}
\end{sysmatrix}
\end{alignat*}
```

Comment: It helps us greatly if you make this into a minimal working example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`  as things stand, `\ro` appears to be a custom command of yours, and `sysmatrix` an environment from some package.  Giving us a MWE helps us understand what you have so far, and gives us a starting point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highlight elements in the matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40028/highlight-elements-in-the-matrix)

Comment: This may be a duplicate of something, but the suggested question is not it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what your `sysmatrix` environment does but I would just use an `align*` environment for this and instead of your custom `\ro` command I suggest `\xrightarrow`, which is an arrow that expands to fit the width of the material written above (or below) it.

You have a lot of unnecessary `alignat` environments that can be omitted. In addition, for row operations like these I use a modification of the [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) matrix environments that allow you to specify column alignment and add `|`s etc.

With this in place you can typeset your matrices as:

[image]

using the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
% put line in augmented matrices (code from
% http://texblog.net/latex-archive/maths/amsmath-matrix/ )
% Example: \begin{bmatrix}[cc|c] 1&2&3\\ 2&3&1 \end{bmatrix}
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{%
  \hskip -\arraycolsep%
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar%
  \array{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

  \begin{align*}
    \begin{array}{r}
      \xrightarrow{r_1 \rightarrow r_1 - r_2a }\\ \\
      \xrightarrow{r_3 \rightarrow r_3 - r_2(3-a) }
    \end{array}
    \begin{pmatrix}[rrr|c]
     1 &  0 & 2 & -\frac{2a}{a^2-2}  \\
     0 &  1 & 0 & \frac{a^2}{a^2-2} \\
     0 &  0 & -2 & \frac{1}{a^2-2}(-a^2+2a-4)
    \end{pmatrix}
   \begin{array}{r}
     \xrightarrow{r_1 \rightarrow r_1 + r_3 }\\ \\
   \end{array}
   &\begin{pmatrix}[rrr|c]
       1 &  0 & 2 & -\frac{a^2+4}{a^2-2}  \\
       0 &  1 & 0 & \frac{a^2}{a^2-2} \\
       0 &  0 & -2 & \frac{1}{a^2-2}(-a^2+2a-4)
     \end{pmatrix}
  \\
   \begin{array}{r}\\ \\
      \xrightarrow{r_3 \rightarrow \frac{r_3}{-2} }
    \end{array}
  & \begin{pmatrix}[rrr|c]
    1 &  0 & 0 & -\frac{a^2+4}{a^2-2}  \\
     0 &  1 & 0 & \frac{a^2}{a^2-2} \\
     0 &  0 & 1 & \frac{\frac{a^2}{2}-a+2}{a^2-2}
    \end{pmatrix}
  \\
  \Longrightarrow\qquad
    \begin{pmatrix} x_1\\ x_2\\ x_3 \end{pmatrix}
    =&
    \begin{pmatrix}
    -\frac{a^2+4}{a^2-2}  \\
    \frac{a^2}{a^2-2} \\
    \frac{\frac{a^2}{2}-a+2}{a^2-2}
    \end{pmatrix}
  \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Note that the outer `align*` environment has a single alignment character `&` which is a the right hand matrices. In the `array` environments for the row operations I have put blank lines so that the row operation roughly aligns with the corresponding row.