# Selecting columns and rows in a matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I am trying to draw what's on the picture:

[image]

How can I draw the ellipses?

mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{blkarray, bigstrut}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
          &  & V1  & V2 & V3  \\ \hline
        U1& 6 &    2 &   2    \\ \hline
        U2& 8 &     3&    5  \\ \hline
        U3& 4 &    2 &    6 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

= 

\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
 & Comedy & Tragedy  \\
2 &  &  \\ \hline
3 &  &  \\ \hline
2 &  & \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\times

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
 & V1 &V2  &V3  \\ \hline
 Comedy & 3 & 1 &1  \\ \hline
 Tragedy & 1 & 0 &-2 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Highlight elements in the matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40028/5764)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With use of the `nicematrix` package, designed as unnumbered equation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{highlight/.style={ellipse, draw=red, semithick, inner sep=1pt}}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{NiceMatrix}[hvlines]
    & V1    & V2    & V3    \\ 
U1  & 6     & 2     & 2     \\ 
U2  & 8     & 3     & 5     \\ 
U3  & 4     & 2     & 6     \\ 
    \end{NiceMatrix}
\quad=\quad
\begin{NiceMatrix}[hvlines]
    & \text{Comedy}
            & \text{Tragedy}\\  
U1  & 6     & 2             \\  
U2  & 8     & -1            \\  
U3  & 4     & -2            \\  
\CodeAfter
\tikz \node [highlight, fit=(4-1) (4-3),
             label=below:User Features Vector] {} ;
\end{NiceMatrix}
\quad\times\quad
\begin{NiceMatrix}[hvlines]
    & V1    & V2    & V3    \\  
\text{Comedy}
    & 3     & 1     & 1     \\  
\text{Tragedy}
    & 1     & 0     & -2    \\  
\CodeAfter
\tikz \node [highlight, fit=(1-2) (3-2),
             label=below:Item Features Vector] {};
\end{NiceMatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Note: for the showed result you need to compile MWE at least twice!

**Addendum:***

- From your comments follows, that you like to have such solution in documents using `standalone` document class. Unfortunately this document class not support well images or writing equations which are based on `remember picture` and `overlay` options (as far as i know).
- On the other hand, it is not clear what benefits are expected to have one equation (combined with `tikz` drawings in form of `nicematrix` or for example with `tikzmark` nodes). To include it as `pdf` or `png` file which you can simple scale?
- Reason, that you can include in other environments, for example in float, is not convincing. this can be done directly. For example in `figure` float:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{highlight/.style={ellipse, draw=red, semithick, inner sep=1pt}}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \[
\begin{NiceMatrix}[hvlines]
    & V1    & V2    & V3    \\ 
U1  & 6     & 2     & 2     \\ 
U2  & 8     & 3     & 5     \\ 
U3  & 4     & 2     & 6     \\ 
    \end{NiceMatrix}
\quad=\quad
\begin{NiceMatrix}[hvlines]
    & \text{Comedy}
            & \text{Tragedy}\\  
U1  & 6     & 2             \\  
U2  & 8     & -1            \\  
U3  & 4     & -2            \\  
\CodeAfter
\tikz \node [highlight, fit=(4-1) (4-3),
             label=below:User Features Vector] {} ;
\end{NiceMatrix}
\quad\times\quad
\begin{NiceMatrix}[hvlines]
    & V1    & V2    & V3    \\  
\text{Comedy}
    & 3     & 1     & 1     \\  
\text{Tragedy}
    & 1     & 0     & -2    \\  
\CodeAfter
\tikz \node [highlight, fit=(1-2) (3-2),
             label=below:Item Features Vector] {} ;
\end{NiceMatrix}
\]
\caption{For some reason this equation is present as figure}
\label{fig:nicematrix}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

- In the case, that the equation is to big (as it is now, it is wider than default text width defined by `article` document class), you can use for it smaller fonts or macro `\medmath` defined in the `nccmath` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,
                shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{highlight/.style={ellipse, draw=red, semithick, inner sep=1pt}}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{equation}\medmath{
\begin{NiceMatrix}[hvlines]
    & V1    & V2    & V3    \\ 
U1  & 6     & 2     & 2     \\ 
U2  & 8     & 3     & 5     \\ 
U3  & 4     & 2     & 6     \\ 
    \end{NiceMatrix}
\quad=\quad
\begin{NiceMatrix}[hvlines]
    & \text{Comedy}
            & \text{Tragedy}\\  
U1  & 6     & 2             \\  
U2  & 8     & -1            \\  
U3  & 4     & -2            \\  
\CodeAfter
\tikz \node [highlight, fit=(4-1) (4-3),
             label=below:User Features Vector] {} ;
\end{NiceMatrix}
\quad\times\quad
\begin{NiceMatrix}[hvlines]
    & V1    & V2    & V3    \\  
\text{Comedy}
    & 3     & 1     & 1     \\  
\text{Tragedy}
    & 1     & 0     & -2    \\  
\CodeAfter
\tikz \node [highlight, fit=(1-2) (3-2),
             label=below:Item Features Vector] {} ;
\end{NiceMatrix}
    }
\medskip
    \end{equation}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

- If you for some reason like to retype this equation meny times in document, you can store equation code in file and simple call it with for example

  ```
     \input{equations/nicematrix-1}
  ```

  where `nicematrix-1` is name of the file with equation code stored in `equations` sub folder in your document folder.
- if there is still some reason to have this equation as `standalone` document, than might be solution to draw it with plain `tikz` using `matrix` library. Code for such image can be "slightly" more complicated (see second mine answer).

Comment: Zarko is an astronomical genius

Comment: @Delan, I doubt in this (regardless that astronomy is one of my hobbies) ... :-).  I'm pretty sure that during day you will receive more, maybe better  answers.

Comment: @Zarko How can I make it a standalone document?

Comment: @naveganTeX, simple replace `\documentclass{article}` with `\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}` doesn't work as expected (what probably you found out yourself) . It cut-off labels defined in nodes highlight as well part of left and right side of equation. How to solve this we should ask the package author, so the best what can be done now is ask new question with this problem.

Comment: @naveganTeX ,the closest approximation is use of the `preview` package, for example `\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{minipage}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2pt}
` and than insert equation in `minipage` as: `\begin{minipage}{1.1\textwidth}
\vspace*{-0.8\baselineskip} <... equation ...>\vspace*{0pt}
\end{minipage}` and than use result as pdf file.

Comment: Thank you. Also I could try by reducing the space between cells or something like that

Comment: @naveganTeX, I don't know why you like to have equation in `standalone` version. The best is include into your document as it is. Anyway, I would be ask new question about this problem. It might already exist some clever workaround how to solve this. Now I will go away and haven't time for searching site for solution or ask new question.

Comment: Because in when I include into the document it asks me for an environment. I need to give it a `\caption` and `label`. And I do not know which environment to use.

Comment: @naveganTeX, see addendum to my answer. For eventual  further help i will have spare time late in evening again.

Comment: @Zarko Always my compliments for your work. It is very nice ...nicematrix :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your equation as `tikz` picture. Used is `standalone` document class as you request in your comments:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=1pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,
                matrix,
                positioning,
                shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{
highlight/.style args={#1/#2}{ellipse, draw=red, semithick, 
                              inner xsep=#1, inner ysep=#2},
 mymatrix/.style={matrix of nodes,
                  nodes in empty cells,
                  nodes={minimum height=3ex, minimum width=2em, 
                         inner sep=2pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=center,
                         draw},
                  column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
                  row sep=-\pgflinewidth
                  }
        }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0pt]
\matrix (m1) [mymatrix] 
{
    & V1    & V2    & V3    \\
U1  & 6     & 2     & 2     \\
U2  & 8     & 3     & 5     \\
U3  & 4     & 2     & 6     \\
};
\node (times) [right=of m1] {$\times$};
\matrix (m2) [mymatrix, 
              column 2/.style={nodes={minimum width=4em}},
              column 3/.style={nodes={minimum width=4em}},
              right=of times]
{
    & Comedy    & Tragedy   \\
U1  & 6         & 2         \\
U2  & 8         & $-1$      \\
U3  & 4         & $-2$      \\
};
\node (equal) [right=of m2] {$=$};
\matrix (m3) [mymatrix,
              column 1/.style={nodes={minimum width=4em}},
              right=of equal]
{
        & V1    & V2    & V3    \\  
Comedy  & 3     & 1     & 1     \\  
Tragedy & 1     & 0     & $-2$  \\  
};
\node[highlight=-9pt/0pt, fit=(m2-4-1) (m2-4-3),
      label=below:User Features Vector] {};  
\node[highlight=0pt/-3pt, fit=(m3-1-2) (m3-3-2),
      label=below:Item Features Vector] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or if you delete line line `nodes in empty cells,` in `mymatrix` style definition:

[image]

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you so much for taking the time, Zarko. Someone said earlier that you’re an astronomical genius and I agree! :)

Comment: How can I make the tables (matrices) look bold? Something related to `\textbf`

Comment: To definition of nodes add `\text=\bfseries`. After this you probably need to increase cells minimum width.