# Add grid on matrix for any input text length

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

Below example will draw matrix from a array, but I wish to draw grid on it as well just like a table for any list text (longer or shorter)!

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning,calc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\JLST}{%
{0,1,2},
{a,b,c},
{f,juice,white rice}%
}
\newcommand{\TBL}[3][M] {%[#1]{name}{list}
    \let\desc\empty
\foreach \col in #3 {%
    \foreach \row [count=\nc] in \col {
        \ifnum\nc > 1%
           \expandafter\gappto\expandafter\desc\expandafter{\&}
         \fi%
        \expandafter\gappto\expandafter\desc\expandafter{\row}%
    }%
    \xappto\desc{\\}%  
}%
\matrix [#1,
    nodes={minimum size=1em,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=1pt},
    append after command={
        \pgfextra{
            \draw ($(\tikzlastnode.north west)$) rectangle ($(\tikzlastnode.south east)$);
        }
    },
    nodes in empty cells,
    column sep=-0.5pt, row sep=-0.5pt,
    matrix of nodes,ampersand replacement=\&] (#2) {
    \desc
};
}
\begin{document}
    \tiny\begin{tikzpicture}
    \TBL[]{M}{\JLST}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved with `eqparbox`, which allows us to make sure that the nodes in each column have the same width, which is the maximal width of a given column. All this can be made a style, `center align per column`. (You could also have left or right align, which mimics the column types `l` and `r`, respectively.)

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning,calc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newbox\matrixcellbox
\tikzset{center align per column/.style={nodes={execute at begin
 node={\setbox\matrixcellbox=\hbox\bgroup},
 execute at end
 node={\egroup\eqmakebox[\tikzmatrixname\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn][c]{\copy\matrixcellbox}}}},
}
\newcommand{\JLST}{%
{0,1,2},
{a,b,c},
{f,juice,white rice}%
}
\newcommand{\TBL}[3][M] {%[#1]{name}{list}
    \let\desc\empty
\foreach \col in #3 {%
    \foreach \row [count=\nc] in \col {
        \ifnum\nc > 1%
           \expandafter\gappto\expandafter\desc\expandafter{\&}
         \fi%
        \expandafter\gappto\expandafter\desc\expandafter{\row}%
    }%
    \xappto\desc{\\}%  
}%
\matrix [#1,
    nodes={minimum size=1em,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=1pt},
    draw,thick,inner sep=0pt,
%     append after command={
% %         \pgfextra{
% %             \draw ($(\tikzlastnode.north west)$) rectangle ($(\tikzlastnode.south east)$);
% %         }
%     }, % replaced this by draw
    nodes in empty cells,
    nodes={draw,thin,anchor=center,inner sep=2pt,
    text depth={depth("g")},text height={height("H")}}, %<-added
    center align per column,% <-added
    column sep=-0.4pt, row sep=-0.4pt, % <-changed
    matrix of nodes,ampersand replacement=\&] (#2) {
    \desc
};
}
\begin{document}
    \tiny\begin{tikzpicture}
    \TBL[]{M}{\JLST}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use the styles from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/497285). Then you only need to add `matrix dividers,matrix frame=thick,`.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning,calc,fit}
\makeatletter
\long\def\ifnodedefined#1#2#3{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85531
    \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}{#3}{#2}%
}
\tikzset{matrix vlines/.style={execute at end matrix={
\foreach \XX in {1,...,\the\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns}
{\xdef\FitList{}
\foreach \YY in {1,...,\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow}
{\ifnodedefined{\tikzmatrixname-\YY-\XX}{\xdef\FitList{\FitList (\tikzmatrixname-\YY-\XX)}}{}
}
\node[fit=\FitList,draw=none,fill=none,inner sep=0pt,draw=none] (\tikzmatrixname-col-\XX) {};
}
\foreach \XX in {2,...,\the\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns}
{\draw[#1] ($(\tikzmatrixname-col-\XX.west)!0.5!(\tikzmatrixname-col-\the\numexpr\XX-1\relax.east)$)
coordinate (aux) (aux|-\tikzmatrixname.north)
 --  (aux|-\tikzmatrixname.south);
}
}},matrix hlines/.style={execute at end matrix={
\foreach \YY in {1,...,\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow}
{\xdef\FitList{}
\foreach \XX in {1,...,\the\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns}
{\ifnodedefined{\tikzmatrixname-\YY-\XX}{\xdef\FitList{\FitList (\tikzmatrixname-\YY-\XX)}}{}
}
\node[fit=\FitList,draw=none,fill=none,inner sep=0pt,draw=none] (\tikzmatrixname-row-\YY) {};
}
\foreach \XX in {2,...,\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow}
{\draw[#1] ($(\tikzmatrixname-row-\XX)!0.5!(\tikzmatrixname-row-\the\numexpr\XX-1\relax)$)
coordinate (aux) (aux-|\tikzmatrixname.west)
 --  (aux-|\tikzmatrixname.east);
}
}},
matrix dividers/.style={matrix vlines=#1,matrix hlines=#1},
matrix frame/.style={execute at end matrix={
\draw[#1] (\tikz@fig@name.south west) rectangle (\tikz@fig@name.north east);
}}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\JLST}{%
{0,1,2},
{a,b,c},
{f,juice,white rice}%
}
\newcommand{\TBL}[3][M] {%[#1]{name}{list}
    \let\desc\empty
\foreach \col in #3 {%
    \foreach \row [count=\nc] in \col {
        \ifnum\nc > 1%
           \expandafter\gappto\expandafter\desc\expandafter{\&}
         \fi%
        \expandafter\gappto\expandafter\desc\expandafter{\row}%
    }%
    \xappto\desc{\\}%  
}%
\matrix [#1,
    nodes={minimum size=1em,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=1pt},
    matrix dividers,matrix frame=thick,
    nodes in empty cells,
    column sep=-0.5pt, row sep=-0.5pt,
    matrix of nodes,ampersand replacement=\&] (#2) {
    \desc
};
}
\begin{document}
    \tiny\begin{tikzpicture}
    \TBL[]{M}{\JLST}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You may want to adjust the `inner sep` to `0pt` to get

[image]

**ADDENDUM** (per request): this defines the additional styles `left align per column` and `right align per column`. (One only needs to change the alignment in `\eqmakebox`.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newbox\matrixcellbox
\tikzset{center align per column/.style={nodes={execute at begin
            node={\setbox\matrixcellbox=\hbox\bgroup},
            execute at end
            node={\egroup\eqmakebox[\tikzmatrixname\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn][c]{\copy\matrixcellbox}}}},
left align per column/.style={nodes={execute at begin
            node={\setbox\matrixcellbox=\hbox\bgroup},
            execute at end
            node={\egroup\eqmakebox[\tikzmatrixname\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn][l]{\copy\matrixcellbox}}}},
right align per column/.style={nodes={execute at begin
            node={\setbox\matrixcellbox=\hbox\bgroup},
            execute at end
            node={\egroup\eqmakebox[\tikzmatrixname\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn][r]{\copy\matrixcellbox}}}},                     
}

\begin{document}
    \tiny\begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix [draw,line width=1pt,inner sep=0pt,nodes in empty cells,
        nodes={
            draw,thin,anchor=center,inner sep=2pt,
            text depth={depth("g")},text height={height("H")},
        }, 
    column 1/.style={right align per column},
    column 2/.style={center align per column},
    column 3/.style={left align per column},
    column sep=-0.4pt, row sep=-0.4pt,
    matrix of nodes] (M) {
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        aaaaa & bbbb & cccccc \\
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newbox\matrixcellbox
\tikzset{column align/.style args={#1/#2}{column #1/.style={nodes={execute at begin
            node={\setbox\matrixcellbox=\hbox\bgroup},
            execute at end node={%
            \egroup\eqmakebox[\tikzmatrixname\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn][#2]{\copy\matrixcellbox}}}}
            }}

\begin{document}
    \tiny\begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix [draw,line width=1pt,inner sep=0pt,nodes in empty cells,
        nodes={
            draw,thin,anchor=center,inner sep=2pt,
            text depth={depth("g")},text height={height("H")},
        }, 
    column align/.list={1/r,2/c,3/l},
    column sep=-0.4pt, row sep=-0.4pt,
    matrix of nodes] (M) {
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        aaaaa & bbbb & cccccc \\
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note, however, that something like `\multicolumn` and/or `\multirow` is harder to implement (according to what I know).

Comment: Awesome, for the l,c,r definition, is it possible to use a argument rather than define 3 different style?

Comment: @beetlej Sure, these are all simple modifications. With the `/.list` key it becomes even more convenient. (I have collected all sorts of tricks somewhere, but unfortunately you cannot easily add `\multicolumn` or `\multirow`. Here, "easily" means without making too many assumptions. Everyone could add some `execute at end matrix` hacks but there are too many special cases that limit the scope.)

Answer (score 2):

I prefer plain matrix and remove unnecessary libraries, more simple to understand:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newbox\matrixcellbox
\tikzset{center align per column/.style={nodes={execute at begin
            node={\setbox\matrixcellbox=\hbox\bgroup},
            execute at end
            node={\egroup\eqmakebox[\tikzmatrixname\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn][c]{\copy\matrixcellbox}}}},
}
\begin{document}
    \tiny\begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix [draw,line width=1pt,inner sep=0pt,nodes in empty cells,
        nodes={
            draw,thin,anchor=center,inner sep=2pt,
            text depth={depth("g")},text height={height("H")},
        }, 
    center align per column,
    column sep=-0.4pt, row sep=-0.4pt,
    matrix of nodes] (M) {
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        a & b & cccccc \\
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, the style `center align per column` is just copied from my answer, isn't it?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Correct, your answer is great. BTW, how to align text in left?

Comment: You only need to change the second optional argument `[c]` of `\eqmakebox` to either `[l]` or `[r]`. I added this to the answer above.