# Annotate elements of matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, tikz-arrows

I need your help to create this picture in Latex[image]

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40333/134144

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the [latest version of the `circledsteps` package](https://github.com/Rmano/circledsteps) which appeared on CTAN just now you can do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{circledsteps}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{bmatrix}
 \textcolor{magenta}{1} & 2 & -1 & 1 \\ 
 \Circled[outer color=cyan]{3} & 2 & -1 & 1 \\ 
 \Circled[outer color=cyan]{-2} & 2 & -1 & 1 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to run this code you need to update your LaTeX installation (or download the package from [here](https://github.com/Rmano/circledsteps)).

Comment: Thanks for sharing about the package `circledsteps,sty`, its one of a new update for me...

Comment: Thanks so much Schrödinger's cat.