# How to add these arrows on this Matrix

Tags: matrices

Consider the following matrix :
[image]

I have no problem in constructing the matrix and I have no problem in circling the first and the fifth row, but I have no idea how to insert these arrows outside this matrix. I hope someone can help me out.

Here is what I wrote :

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
$$
\begin{bNiceMatrix}%
[code-after = { \tikz \node [draw, rounded corners, fit = (5-1) (5-7)] { };  \tikz \node [draw, rounded corners, fit = (1-1) (1-7)] { } ;},  left-margin = 7pt, right-margin = 7pt] 
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \ddots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bNiceMatrix}
$$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. There are nicematrix, kbordermatrix and other options. Please, can you put your complete code of your work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Highlight elements in the matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40028/highlight-elements-in-the-matrix)

Comment: Hello. no since my concern is how to add the arrows on the right of the matrix.

Comment: Final update of my code is now completed, now to return to my main concern on how to draw these arrows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote,

> my concern is how to add the arrows on the right of the matrix.

Your objective may be achieved easily by adding a one-column, left-aligned `array` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{old-arrows} % optional (for smaller arrowheads)
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \smash{\ddots} & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{l}
\gets 1 \\
\gets 2 \\
\smash{\vdots} \\
\gets i_1-1 \\
\gets i_1 \\
\smash{\vdots} \\
\gets n
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting approach, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Use `last-col`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[
  code-after = {
   \tikz \node [draw, rounded corners, fit = (5-1) (5-7)] { };
   \tikz \node [draw, rounded corners, fit = (1-1) (1-7)] { } ;
  },
  left-margin = 7pt,
  right-margin = 7pt,
  last-col,
] 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & \leftarrow 1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \leftarrow 2\\
0 & 0 & \smash{\ddots} & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \smash{\vdots} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \leftarrow i_1-1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \leftarrow i_1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \smash{\vdots} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \leftarrow n
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! your answer is much appreciated.