# Shear transform a "box"

Tags: graphics

Using the `graphicx` package, I can make any arbitrary box rotated using the `\rotatebox{...}{...}` command. Is there a comparable command in any package that lets me shear a box, i.e., producing a kind of general slanting?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

With a slightly more recent pdfTeX than in David's answer, you can more directly do affine transforms using `\pdfsetmatrix`.  I don't claim to know anything about this, but here is roughly what graphicx does under the hood in `\rotatebox` (with a different matrix, of course).

```
\documentclass{article}
\newsavebox{\foobox}
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][.5]
  {%
    \mbox
      {%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
      }%
  }
\begin{document}
\slantbox{Hello, world!}

\slantbox[-2]{Hello, world!}
\slantbox[-1]{Hello, world!}
\slantbox[-.8]{Hello, world!}
\slantbox[-.6]{Hello, world!}
\slantbox[-.4]{Hello, world!}
\slantbox[-.2]{Hello, world!}

\slantbox[.2]{Hello, world!}
\slantbox[.4]{Hello, world!}
\slantbox[.6]{Hello, world!}
\slantbox[.8]{Hello, world!}
\slantbox[1]{Hello, world!}
\slantbox[2]{Hello, world!}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the code above: text that is slanted by various amounts]

EDIT: as pointed out by quark67, to use this code with LuaLaTeX, you just need to first load the package `luatex85`, which provides the commands `\pdfsave`, `\pdfsetmatrix`, `\pdfrestore` (see section 2.5 of the manual).

Comment: Do we want this for LaTeX3? It should be pretty easy to code as I've already got the basics sorted.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. How do those four numbers correspond to a transformation matrix? Is it just a list of elements of the matrix left to right, row by row? Would `\slantbox[0]{}` amount to the identity transformation?

Comment: @Seamus: yes, the four numbers `1`, `0`, `#1`, and `1` are the entries in the 2×2 matrix defining the linear transformation.  David's answer with `\pdfliteral` allows arbitrary affine transformation (so the 4 coefficients for the linear part, and 2 coefficients for the offset, I think).

Comment: @Joseph: I was thinking of it (I didn't upvote your comment, so at least one other person would like that), but I'm not sure whether we should give `\box_linear_transform:Nnnnn` for arbitrary parameters, or `\box_vertical_shear:Nn` and `\box_horizontal_shear:Nn`, or...

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch If we provide a mechanism here, we should have the 'general case' shear, something like `\box_shear:Nnn` or even as you say a totally-general transformation (`\box_affine:Nnnnn`?). One for LaTeX-L

Comment: @JosephWright Yes, for LaTeX-L, and probably after the CTAN upload.  I'd say `linear` is better than `affine`.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch If the offset is present it's in my opinion better to call it affine to emphasize the difference between `y=ax` and `y=ax+b`

Comment: @percusse If the offset is present, you need 6 arguments: 4 for the matrix, 2 for the offset vector.  I have to admit that I'm not sure around which corner/center of the box we should rotate/scale/shear/do a linear transform, nor what the size of the box should be as a result (there is more than just affine transformations at play, since the box is not just defined by one of its points).

Comment: Indeed I was thinking of `\pdfliteral`. I've confused your answer with David's probably. But maybe it is possible to use directly that command in your case too. Great answer anyway and I hope it goes into the L3 magic.

Comment: Was this function added to LaTeX3? If so what is its current form?

Comment: @Simon: No idea, but I can't find such a function.

Comment: @JosephWright: Can you say whether we have a shear function?

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch We do not have a dedicated interface for a shear: one can of course use scalings and rotations in combination. We could provide such an interface of course.

Comment: In fact, shears cannot be expressed in terms of scalings and rotations (for instance both of these preserve angles while shears don't), so maybe that's an argument for providing some interface.

Comment: For use this code with LuaLaTeX, you just need to first load the package [`luatex85`](https://ctan.org/pkg/luatex85), which provides the commands `\pdfsave`, `\pdfsetmatrix`, `\pdfrestore` (see section 2.5 of [the manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/luatex85/luatex85.pdf)). Perhaps this information can be added in your answer.

Comment: @quark67 Done, thanks.

Answer (score 20):

Aha, TikZability opportunity!

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[cm={1,0,1,1,(0,0)}] % Sets the coordinate trafo matrix entries.
\node[transform shape] at (0,0) {ABC};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[cm={1,0,-1,1,(0,0)}]
\node[transform shape] at (3,0) {Hello};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[cm={1,0,-1,-1,(0,0)}]
\node[transform shape] at (2,2) {World};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[cm={1,0,1,-1,(0,0)}]
\node[transform shape] at (1,2) {FOObar?};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You can put into nodes instead of boxes (with less risk :P).

[image]

Comment: 'transform shape' is not needed

Answer (score 19):

[image]

You can mess with the coordinate matrix, but at your own risk...

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


ABC\pdfliteral{ q 2 0.1 0.6 .4 0 0 cm}\rlap{XYZ}\pdfliteral{ Q}


\end{document}
```

Comment: `q` (`\pdfsave`) and `Q` (`\pdfrestore`) should be used at the *same* place. Otherwise the coordinate system of TeX and its output device get indeed messed up.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek ah yes I wrote some driver graphics back end files once, clearly I forgot everything, I'll add an rlap....

Answer (score 15):

A little late, but perhaps useful. An easier solution is the use of `xslant` and `yslant` in the node options.

### Example 1

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[yslant=0.5, draw] (1) {Latex};
    \node[xslant=0.5, draw, anchor=south] at ([yshift=10]1.north) {Latex};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

### Result 1

[image: Result example 1]

Then I wanted to use it for a 3D view of a box, where on one plane I project an external *.png image.

### Example 2

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\w}{4 cm} % width of the box
\newcommand{\dep}{1 cm} % depth of the box
\newcommand{\h}{0.7 cm} % height of the box

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Front side of the box
    \node[minimum width = \w, minimum height=\h, fill=gray, outer sep =0] (front) {};
    \begin{scope}       
        \pgftransformxslant{1}
        \pgfset{minimum width=\w, minimum height= \dep, outer sep = 0}
        \pgftransformshift{\pgfpointanchor{front}{north}}
        \pgfnode{rectangle}{south}{}{clip}{\pgfusepath{clip}}
        % Image on top of the box
        \node[anchor=south, inner sep =0, xslant=1, outer sep = 0] (img) at (front.north) 
            {\includegraphics[width=\w, height=\dep]{Example_image.png}}; 
    \end{scope}
    % Side of the box
    \node[anchor=west, yslant=1, minimum height =\h, minimum width=\dep,
          inner sep=0, outer sep=0, fill=black!70] at (front.east) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Result 2

[image: Result example 2]

Comment: "For every problem, there is a Ti*k*Z-attribute". This should be the higher-rated Ti*k*Z-answer, w.r.t. to it's simplicity.

Comment: I completely agree @Bubaya ;)

Answer (score 7):

Shear transforms can be decomposed into scalings and rotations.

```
% \hshearbox{vertical_prescale_times_shearfactor}{one_divide_by_shearfactor}{content}
% an initial vertical downscale is often necessary for a 3d projection
\newcommand{\hshearbox}[3]{\scalebox{0.866025}[#2]{\rotatebox{210}%
{\scalebox{1.73205}[-0.57735]{\rotatebox{60}{\scalebox{-1.1547}[#1]{#3}}}}}}
% \vshearbox{horizontal_prescale_times_shearfactor}{one_divide_by_shearfactor}{content}
% an initial horizontal downscale is often necessary for a 3d projection
\newcommand{\vshearbox}[3]{\scalebox{#2}[0.866025]{\rotatebox{210}%
{\scalebox{-0.57735}[1.73205]{\rotatebox{60}{\scalebox{#1}[-1.1547]{#3}}}}}}
```