# Define \shearbox with \rotatebox and \scalebox

Tags: boxes, rotating, scaling

Similar to [this problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63179/8956), I want to define `\shearbox` with `\rotatebox` and `\scalebox` using singular value decomposition:
[image: singular value decomposition]

The latex code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\xshearbox[2]{%
  \FPeval{\sheark}{(root(2,(#1)*(#1)+4)+#1)/2}\FPeval{\shearl}{1/\sheark}%
  \FPeval{\sheara}{arctan(-\sheark)*180/pi}\FPeval{\shearb}{90+\sheara}%
  \rotatebox{\shearb}{\scalebox{\sheark}[\shearl]{\rotatebox{\sheara}{#2}}}%
}
\begin{document}
pefgh\xshearbox{0.2}{pefgh}pefgh\xshearbox{0.4}{pefgh}pefgh\xshearbox{0.6}{pefgh}%
pefgh\xshearbox{0.8}{pefgh}pefgh\xshearbox{1}{pefgh}pefgh
\end{document}
```

[image]

But there are still two problems here:

1. There are extra spaces between shearing text and normal text;
2. The baselines of shearing text is a little higher than normal text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problems are caused by the height and depth of the original box.  You can ignore these by smashing the contents `\smash{#2}`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\xshearbox[2]{%
  \FPeval{\sheark}{(root(2,(#1)*(#1)+4)+#1)/2}\FPeval{\shearl}{1/\sheark}%
  \FPeval{\sheara}{arctan(-\sheark)*180/pi}\FPeval{\shearb}{90+\sheara}%
  \rotatebox{\shearb}{\scalebox{\sheark}[\shearl]{{\rotatebox{\sheara}{\smash{#2}}}}}%
}
\begin{document}
pefgh\xshearbox{0.2}{pefgh}pefgh\xshearbox{0.4}{pefgh}pefgh\xshearbox{0.6}{pefgh}%
pefgh\xshearbox{0.8}{pefgh}pefgh\xshearbox{1}{pefgh}pefgh

\end{document}
```

Comment: The correct height and depth can be taken into account with `\vphantom{#2}`. Probably wrapping the whole construction like with `\mbox{\vphantom{#2}\rotatebox{\shearb}{...}}`