# How do I display pi in LaTeX like Don?

Tags: math-mode, fontsize, typography

Way back in 1979, Donald Knuth, tried to give the feeling that π is irrational using the idea of infinite sequence of smaller and smaller font sizes like what I have tried to do here using HTML and CSS. How do I do the same using LaTeX?

Now to the very difficult part, how do I some how create the feeling using typesetting that π is transcendental (not a solution of any finite polynomial having integer coefficients).

.pi sub { vertical-align: baseline; font-size: 96%; }

π = 3.14159<sub>2<sub>6<sub>5<sub>3<sub>5<sub>8<sub>9<sub>7<sub>9<sub>3<sub>2<sub>3<sub>8<sub>4<sub>6<sub>2<sub>6<sub>4<sub>3<sub>3<sub>8<sub>3<sub>2<sub>7<sub>9<sub>5<sub>0<sub>2<sub>88419716939937510</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub>

Comment: Thanks for all those interesting answers. I am humbled by all your answers.

Comment: 856142 repeats, so they usually indicate this repeat by $1/7=0.142\overline{856142}$. I think any rational number has these repeats.

Comment: You could think of transcendence as lack of rootedness.

Comment: Blabbering along the same vein, since polynomials with rational coefficients are countable, these rootless transcendental numbers are what fills the real line. Looks more like our modern society?

Comment: I know that the decimal representation of any rational number ultimately repeats (and of irrationals it doesn't ultimately repeat). However there is no way one can see from an initial segment whether it ultimately repeats. Which is why I needed to indicate that what I wrote was supposed to be the (repeating) representation of 1/7.

Comment: @Sukii: Or More directly as $1/7=0.\overline{142856}$. And yes, any rational number is of that form (if you count a repeating 0 the same way, although it would be highly unusual to set $1/4=0.25\overline{0}$). The same way, the continued fraction of any algebraic of degree 2 is eventually repeating.

Comment: One way transcendence can be indicated subtly using
.pi sub { vertical-align: top; font-size: 96%; }
showing that it is not rooted to baseline. Can you do that in LaTeX?

Comment: @Maesumi: Yes I knew that; I can't figure out why I wrote that or even what I meant at the time. I guess I'll just delete the silly comment.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

EDITED to allow repeat invocations without having to reset parameters, using the syntax

`\diminish[scale-down-ratio]{string}`

The value of `\defaultstartht` sets the strut height of the first letter (default is set to `\baselineskip`), and the scale-down ratio defaults to 0.98, but may be supplied as an optional parameter.

Beware that arithmetic underflows are possible, if things get teeny enough.

**See addendum for pseudo 3-D effect:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newlength\curht
\def\defaultdimfrac{.98}
\def\defaultstartht{\baselineskip}
\newcommand\diminish[2][\defaultdimfrac]{%
  \curht=\defaultstartht\relax
  \def\dimfrac{#1}%
  \diminishhelpA{#2}%
}
\newcommand\diminishhelpA[1]{%
  \expandafter\diminishhelpB#1\relax%
}
\def\diminishhelpB#1#2\relax{%
  \scaleto{\strut#1}{\curht}%
  \curht=\dimfrac\curht\relax%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\diminishhelpA{#2}\fi%
}
\begin{document}
\def\defaultstartht{14pt}
\def\pinum{3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510}
\diminish{\pinum}\par
\diminish[0.96]{\pinum}\par
\diminish[0.94]{\pinum}\par
\def\defaultstartht{38pt}
\diminish[0.92]{\pinum}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**

Based on Yori's desire to see something more "3-D", I have EDITED to incorporate Bruno's `\slantbox` at [Shear transform a "box"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63179/shear-transform-a-box/63188#63188).  Combining that with a `\raisebox` allows the effect which some *may* find more 3-D.  The additional user parameters to control it are `\slantvalue` which is Bruno's model parameter and `\zshft`, which is an added vertical shift per letter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newlength\curht
\newlength\zshft
\newcounter{letcount}
\def\defaultdimfrac{.98}
\def\slantvalue{0}
\zshft=0pt\relax
\def\defaultstartht{\baselineskip}
\newcommand\diminish[2][\defaultdimfrac]{%
  \curht=\defaultstartht\relax
  \def\dimfrac{#1}%
  \setcounter{letcount}{0}
  \diminishhelpA{#2}%
}
\newcommand\diminishhelpA[1]{%
  \expandafter\diminishhelpB#1\relax%
}
\def\diminishhelpB#1#2\relax{%
  \raisebox{\value{letcount}\zshft}{\scaleto{\strut\slantbox{#1}}{\curht}}%
  \stepcounter{letcount}%
  \curht=\dimfrac\curht\relax%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\diminishhelpA{#2}\fi%
}
\newsavebox{\foobox}
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][\slantvalue]{\mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
}}
\begin{document}
\def\pinum{3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510}
\def\defaultstartht{14pt}
  \diminish{\pinum}\par
\def\slantvalue{.15}
\zshft=.1pt\relax
  \diminish[0.96]{\pinum}\par
  \diminish[0.94]{\pinum}\par
\def\slantvalue{.35}
\zshft=.4pt\relax
\def\defaultstartht{38pt}
  \diminish[0.92]{\pinum}
\end{document}
```

[image]

While the curvy tail gives a certain stylistic fading, it might be preferable to follow the rules of perspective and have the numbers vanish along a linear path to the vanishing point.  What this means is that rather than an additional `\zshft` added for each letter, the `\zshft` should also get smaller with each letter, so that the total shift (dZ) on the nth letter (after the 1st) should be

dZ = dz + k dz + k^2 dz + ... + k^(n-1) dz

where dz is the specified `\zshft`, and k is the scale-down parameter given by `\dimfrac`.  Simple manipulation reveals that the shift for the nth letter (after the 1st) is:

dZ = dz (1 - k^n)/(1-k)

This can be calculated in LaTeX, but requires the much more computationally intensive `fp` package.  So, at the expense of compilation time, we can achieve the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,fp}
\newlength\curht
\newlength\zshft
\newcounter{letcount}
\def\defaultdimfrac{.98}
\def\slantvalue{0}
\zshft=0pt\relax
\def\defaultstartht{\baselineskip}
\newcommand\diminish[2][\defaultdimfrac]{%
  \curht=\defaultstartht\relax
  \def\dimfrac{#1}%
  \setcounter{letcount}{0}
  \diminishhelpA{#2}%
}
\newcommand\diminishhelpA[1]{%
  \expandafter\diminishhelpB#1\relax%
}
\def\diminishhelpB#1#2\relax{%
  \FPpow\localshift{\dimfrac}{\theletcount}\unskip%
  \FPsub\localshift{1}{\localshift}%
  \FPsub\localdenom{1}{\dimfrac}%
  \FPdiv\localshift{\localshift}{\localdenom}%
  \raisebox{\localshift\zshft}{\scaleto{\strut\slantbox{#1}}{\curht}}%
  \stepcounter{letcount}%
  \curht=\dimfrac\curht\relax%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\diminishhelpA{#2}\fi%
}
\newsavebox{\foobox}
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][\slantvalue]{\mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
}}
\begin{document}
\def\pinum{3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510}
\def\defaultstartht{14pt}
  \diminish{\pinum}\par
\def\slantvalue{.15}
\zshft=.3pt\relax
  \diminish[0.96]{\pinum}\par
  \diminish[0.94]{\pinum}\par
\def\slantvalue{.35}
\zshft=1.7pt\relax
\def\defaultstartht{38pt}
  \diminish[0.92]{\pinum}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Oops!! Spill in aisle 1! (coding left to the student)

[image]

Comment: In some sense the "right" value for `scale-down-ratio` would be 0.1.

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to make this look more "3D", i.e., making it look like an infinite row of numbers vanishing at the horizon?

Comment: @NateEldredge A factor of 0.1 in each numeral's area, perhaps, so a factor of 0.3 in character height. Cute.

Comment: @Yori Does the addendum achieve what you desire?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Haha, pretty cool!!

Comment: @NateEldredge Like reals on the number line, I am dense.  While 6 people liked your comment about the right value for scale-down parameter being 0.1, I still don't understand the comment at all.  I couldn't even say whether there is a joke hidden it it or some greater mathematical truth?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Since we're working in base 10, the value of each successive decimal place is 1/10 the value of the one before it.  So maybe one should make the heights diminish in the same proportion.  (Or, as rob, suggests, the areas.)

Comment: @NateEldredge D'oh!  So your comment contained both a joke and a greater mathematic truth!

Answer (score 28):

Mark Wibrow enhanced the text decoration library of TikZ greatly and you can do all kinds of stuff based on formulas regarding the character number and total count of words and so on.

Here is a wacky take on it, (thus a simple monotone scaling along a path is very simple and is possible just by playing with the formula with `scale` instead of `yscale`)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\tikzset{pi decoration/.style={
decoration={text effects along path,
text={3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510},
text align=center,
text effects/.cd,
character total=\n,character count=\i,
path from text,
characters={yscale=10*sin(deg(5*\i/\n))-\i/\n,inner sep=0,anchor=base}
}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[pi decoration,decorate] (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Because, because, because .... because of the wonderful things TikZ does!  (PS Thanks for the edit on my recent post.)

Comment: @LoopSpace The pleasure is mine.

Comment: Seeing this, I find myself wanting to ask the question "How do I display phi in LaTeX like Fibonacci?".  I'd like to see a golden spiral with the digits of phi scaled so that when it reaches the second square then it is exactly 1/phi the size it was when it set out.

Comment: @LoopSpace, please do!

Comment: @LoopSpace: Now I have that song stuck in my head. `:)` Where's my copy of DSOTM? `:)`

Comment: Best I can get of an evening: https://plus.google.com/110765980098077923527/posts/M2d5M3v1Xyu

Comment: @LoopSpace Sweet! Now I understand what you mean :)

Comment: I think you can remove `text align=center`, add `text along path` after `path from text`, and then remove `inner sep=0,anchor=base` from the `characters` key (as the `text effects/text along path` does that for you).

Comment: @MarkWibrow Right. I just copied the example from the manual and fiddled with it. I'll have a proper look in the evening.

Comment: My phi code is now on github: https://github.com/loopspace/golden

Answer (score 24):

A recursive macro:

```
\documentclass[border=2]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathptmx} % a scalable font is needed

\makeatletter
\def\makesmaller#1#2{%
  \dimen0=\dimexpr\dimen0-.08pt\relax
  \ifx#2\relax
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    {\fontsize{\dimen0}{0}\selectfont#1}%
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  {\makesmaller{#2}}%
}
\def\decreasingpi{%
  {\dimen0=16pt\fontsize{\dimen0}{0}\selectfont
  3.\makesmaller1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253
  \relax}
}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
\decreasingpi
\end{document}
```

[image]

One might first count the number of digits and decide the minimum size, so as to adjust the decrease step. I leave this as an exercise.

---

### UPDATE

A different version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\vanishing}{O{1}m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { . } { #2 }
  \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 1 } .
  \seq_set_split:Nnx \l_tmpb_seq { } { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 2 } }
  \fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { \seq_count:N \l_tmpb_seq }
  \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l_tmpb_seq
   {
    \scalebox{\fp_eval:n { 1 - ##1/(\seq_count:N \l_tmpb_seq + #1) } } { ##2 }
   }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { Nnx }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$e=\vanishing[10]{2.71828 18284 59045 23536 02874 71352 66249 77572 47093 69995}$

$e=\vanishing{2.71828 18284 59045 23536 02874 71352 66249 77572 47093 69995}$

\end{document}
```

The optional argument (default 1) is for avoiding the last digit becomes too small.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Just another way...

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\newdimen\dx
\def\dm#1#2{\dx=1em\relax\def\rt{#1}{\Dm#2\dm}}
\def\Dm#1{\ifx#1\dm\else\fontsize\dx\dx\selectfont#1\dx=\rt\dx\expandafter\Dm\fi}
\begin{document}
\dm{0.95}{3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually this approach is almost identical to [egreg's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208437/232).

Answer (score 3):

For example, in plain TeX:

```
\input apnum

\apFRAC=80

\evaldef\Pi{\PI}
\evaldef\E{\EXP{1}}

\def\printsmaller#1{\ifx\end#1\else #1\pdfsetmatrix{.97 0 0 .97}%
   \expandafter\printsmaller\fi}

\noindent\pdfsave\rlap{\expandafter\printsmaller\E\end}\pdfrestore
\bigskip
\noindent\pdfsave\rlap{\expandafter\printsmaller\Pi\end}\pdfrestore

\bye
```