# Variable font size of a text string

Tags: pstricks, fontsize, loops, text-decorations, text

I was wondering if it is possible to use `\fontsize{<size>}{<line space>}`
in a loop in order to create a text string of strictly decreasing/increasing font size from, say, 30 to 2.

Surely such a snippet would start by counting the characters of the string in order to make a nice delta of the size shift.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297873/how-to-raise-or-lower-text/297883#297883

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208426/how-do-i-display-pi-in-latex-like-don

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for *edit*  and for the useful link.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thanks for the useful link.