# How to make text margins follow a specific shape?

Tags: shapes

How can text be formatted as in this example from Alice in Wonderland, where the margins for the text seems to follow a specific shape (if that's what's actually happening..sorry if I'm clueless here), while also the text size decreases? I think I can find out how to manage the shrinking text (like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208426/how-do-i-display-pi-in-latex-like-don)) but not the margin-shape.

[image: Alice in Wonderland example]

Comment: @CampanIgnis Yes, thanks! I tried to search but that page didn't show up.

Comment: Should I delete this question now?

Comment: No, it's better to have this be a signpost to the other question.

Comment: @Teepeemm Ok thanks!

Comment: @user202323 Your are welcome. I am d'accord with Teepeemm.

Comment: The `verse` package manual includes an example of typesetting the **Mouse's Tale**.

Comment: @PeterWilson Haha, that's amazing! I'll take a look at that too.