# Math mode in document title

Tags: math-mode, titles

The title of the LaTeX document I'm writing has some math-mode expressions. However, its font type does not match that in the rest of words, which are not in math-mode.

Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\title{From $7-8$~$\mu$m}
\author{Baister}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

As you can see, "From" and "m" looks different than the rest of the letters.

I'm forced to use a concrete class (provided by a company), so that I can't use `titlepage` environment.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: The thing is, that in maths a bold face letter usually has a different meaning than a *normal* roman letter. So, you could live with the difference (i think this is `\mcro\meter`?, the `m` should be in math mode as well), make the whole title not in bold, or use package `siunitx` and let it take care of the font.

Answer (score 4):

You could `\unslant` the `\mu`, using Bruno's `\slantbox` described at [Shear transform a "box"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63179/shear-transform-a-box/63188#63188).  I also set the number range as `7--8` in text mode, since the math version of your MWE was typeset as seven minus eight.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\def\slantvalue{0}
\newsavebox{\foobox}
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][\slantvalue]{\mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
}}
\def\unslant#1{\slantbox[-.25]{$#1$}}

\title{From 7--8~\unslant{\mu}m}
\author{Baister}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

There is also the `upgreek` package; however, its font may not match the underlying font either:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{upgreek}

\title{From 7--8~$\upmu$m}
\author{Baister}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work. It shows the right boldface `\mu` letter, but its size is much smaller than the rest of the words.

Comment: @baister I don't know why that would be.  Without seeing the actual code that you are using, the only thing I could suggest would be to alter the definition to `\def\unslant#1{\slantbox[-.25]{#1}}` and invoke it as, for example, `\title{From 7--8~\unslant{\Huge$\mu$}m}`.  That would force the greek letter into the specified size.

Answer (score 3):

If you can load the `siunitx` package, `\SIrange{}` might solve your problem. You can adjust the appearance with `\sisetup{}`, and the option `detect-all` will match the appearance to that of the surroundings.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{range-phrase=--,range-units=single,detect-all}

\title{\bfseries From \SIrange{7}{8}{\micro\meter}}
\author{Baister}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work. From the point of view of font size and boldface, it shows "7-8 um" the same way as my original example. The problem is that the "7-8 um" size is much smaller than the rest of the words. What marks the difference is the `\bfseries` command, but it changes all the title style.

Comment: @baister I just put the `\bfseries` in there to demonstrate how the font will match the surrounding style/weight if you use the `detect-all` option in `siunitx`. If you remove it the appearance should match that in your document. Sorry for not making that more clear.