# Italic Cyrillic in Times

Tags: fonts, pdftex, languages, cyrillic, times

I am using pdftex (not XeTeX or LuaTeX) and I need to submit a camera-ready article in Times.  My article is in English but needs to briefly quote Russian sources, some of which have inline italics.  When I use the `mathptmx` package, however, none of the Cyrillic text is in italics.

For example, the following produces "Неприкосновенный запас", not "*Неприкосновенный* запас" as desired:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\foreignlanguage{russian}{\textit{Неприкосновенный} запас}
\end{document}
```

I suppose this is because the Times font doesn't provide italic Cyrillic glyphs.  However, it's not a big deal if my Russian text is in a slightly different serif font.  What's the easiest way to set up my document so that I can produce Cyrillic text in both upright and italic variants (in addition to the default Times for the Latin text)?

Comment: There's no free Cyrillic Times available in TeX distributions. You need to use some substitute, I'm afraid.

Comment: Is a slanted font that doesn't linebreak a workable solution?  If so, you could use `\slantbox[.25]{}` instead of `\textit{}`, as found in Bruno's answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63179/shear-transform-a-box/63188#63188

Comment: `ebgaramond` has cyrillic glyphs in upshape and italic shpae (but purposely no bold version). It has a `scaled=`  option that allows to match x-height with the height of another font.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no Cyrillic Times freely available in the current TeX distributions, so I suggest a different font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc} % or OT1 instead of T1
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\cyrins}[1]{%
  \begingroup\fontfamily{erewhon-TLF}%
  \foreignlanguage{russian}{#1}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
Some text in English,
\cyrins{\textit{Неприкосновенный} запас},
back in Latin script.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here Erewhon (based on Utopia) is used, which is not too distant from Times.

If the standard Computer Modern Cyrillic is acceptable as well, just change `\fontfamily{erewhon-TLF}` into `\fontfamily{cmr}`, but the result is definitely poorer.

[image]

I'd suggest

```
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```

instead of `mathptmx`.

### Update

There *is* a free Times-like font supporting Cyrillic!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc} % or OT1 instead of T1
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{T2A}{\familydefault}{Tempora-TLF}%
}

\begin{document}

Some text in English,
\foreignlanguage{russian}{\textit{Неприкосновенный} запас},
back in Latin script.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can also use the `substitutefont` package.

Comment: @Davislor I’m in the course of removing the package from my answers, because it has been withdrawn.

Comment: Thanks for telling me; I wasn’t aware. Do you know how come?

Comment: The package was superseded by a kernel function, but I think it was a bad idea to withdraw it.

Comment: Shouldn’t there be one that calls the kernel function, just for backwards compatibility? That’ll break a lot of existing documents.

Comment: Which raises a larger question: can anyone stop a maintainer from damaging the TeX ecosystem? Or do the licenses most projects use require CTAN to let them?