# Using inputenc/fontenc for Cyrillic changes the style of the paper defined in the stylefile

Tags: cyrillic

I am preparing a camera-ready version of a paper where I am required to use a specific style file. I am also allowed to write an abstract in Russian, but the example I am provided with uses CJKutf8 (a package for e.g. Chinese), which doesn't quite help me with Russian (it actually is capable of displaying Russian characters but in an ugly manner, so this won't do).

When I try to use other packages instead, such as the babel/inputenc cobination, the required style seems to get overridden throughout the paper (e.g. bolding disappears, the English font looks different throughout the paper).

How do I modify the template so that the resulting PDF displays Russian nicely but the remaining style remains unchanged?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{coling2018}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{latexsym}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\raggedbottom

\newcommand\BibTeX{B{\sc ib}\TeX}

\title{Paper Title}

\author{Author 1 \\
University 1/ City, State \\
  Department \\
  {\tt email@uni1.edu} \\\And
  Author 2 \\
  University 1/ City, State \\
  Department  \\
  {\tt email@uni2.edu} \\}

%\usepackage[russian]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\slname{Russian}

\sltitle{
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}COLING-2018 
格 
русский
\end{CJK}
}

\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
  English abstract
\end{abstract}

\makesltitle
\begin{slabstract}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}
  格
  Русский.
\end{CJK}
\end{slabstract}

\section{Introduction}
Text of the Introduction... 

\end{document}
```

The code above produces the following picture, where Cyrillic characters are awkwardly spaced:

[image]

Commenting out the CJKutf8 package and the corresponding environment and uncommenting inputenc+babel (and removing the Chinese character) produces the following picture, with the entire style changed:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{coling2018}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{latexsym}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\raggedbottom

\newcommand\BibTeX{B{\sc ib}\TeX}

\title{Paper Title}

 \author{Author 1 \\
  University 1/ City, State \\
  Department \\
  {\tt email@uni1.edu} \\\And
  Author 2 \\
  University 1/ City, State \\
  Department  \\
  {\tt email@uni2.edu} \\}

\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\slname{Russian}
\sltitle{
%\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}COLING-2018 
%格 
русский
%\end{CJK}
}
%{gbsn}

\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
  English abstract
\end{abstract}

\makesltitle
 \begin{slabstract}
%\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}
%  格
  Русский.
%\end{CJK}
\end{slabstract}


\section{Introduction}
Text of the Introduction...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's the stylefile:

```
% File coling2018.sty

% This is the LaTeX style file for Coling 2018. It is identical to
% the style file for Coling 2016.

% This is the LaTeX style file for Coling 2016. It is identical to
% the style file for Coling 2014.

% This is the LaTeX style file for Coling 2014. It is nearly identical to
% the style file for ACL 2014.
%
% Changes made: switched to single column format and removed margin around
% abtract

% This is the LaTeX style file for ACL 2014. It is nearly identical to
% the style files for ACL 2013, EACL 2006, ACL2005, ACL 2002, ACL
% 2001, ACL 2000, EACL 95 and EACL 99. 
%
% Changes made include: adapt layout to A4 and centimeters, widen abstract

% This is the LaTeX style file for ACL 2000.  It is nearly identical to the
% style files for EACL 95 and EACL 99.  Minor changes include editing the
% instructions to reflect use of \documentclass rather than \documentstyle
% and removing the white space before the title on the first page
% -- John Chen, June 29, 2000

% To convert from submissions prepared using the style file aclsub.sty
% prepared for the ACL 2000 conference, proceed as follows:
% 1) Remove submission-specific information:  \whichsession, \id,
%    \wordcount, \otherconferences, \area, \keywords
% 2) \summary should be removed.  The summary material should come
%     after \maketitle and should be in the ``abstract'' environment
% 3) Check all citations.  This style should handle citations correctly
%    and also allows multiple citations separated by semicolons.
% 4) Check figures and examples.  Because the final format is double-
%    column, some adjustments may have to be made to fit text in the column
%    or to choose full-width (\figure*} figures.
% 5) Change the style reference from aclsub to acl2000, and be sure
%    this style file is in your TeX search path


% This is the LaTeX style file for EACL-95.  It is identical to the
% style file for ANLP '94 except that the margins are adjusted for A4
% paper.  -- abney 13 Dec 94

% The ANLP '94 style file is a slightly modified
% version of the style used for AAAI and IJCAI, using some changes
% prepared by Fernando Pereira and others and some minor changes 
% by Paul Jacobs.

% Papers prepared using the aclsub.sty file and acl.bst bibtex style
% should be easily converted to final format using this style.  
% (1) Submission information (\wordcount, \subject, and \makeidpage)
% should be removed.
% (2) \summary should be removed.  The summary material should come
% after \maketitle and should be in the ``abstract'' environment
% (between \begin{abstract} and \end{abstract}).
% (3) Check all citations.  This style should handle citations correctly
% and also allows multiple citations separated by semicolons.
% (4) Check figures and examples.  Because the final format is double-
% column, some adjustments may have to be made to fit text in the column
% or to choose full-width (\figure*} figures.

% Place this in a file called aclap.sty in the TeX search path.  
% (Placing it in the same directory as the paper should also work.)

% Prepared by Peter F. Patel-Schneider, liberally using the ideas of
% other style hackers, including Barbara Beeton.
% This style is NOT guaranteed to work.  It is provided in the hope
% that it will make the preparation of papers easier.
%
% There are undoubtably bugs in this style.  If you make bug fixes,
% improvements, etc.  please let me know.  My e-mail address is:
%       pfps@research.att.com

% Papers are to be prepared using the ``acl'' bibliography style,
% as follows:
%       \documentclass[11pt]{article}
%       \usepackage{acl2000}
%       \title{Title}
%       \author{Author 1 \and Author 2 \\ Address line \\ Address line \And
%               Author 3 \\ Address line \\ Address line}
%       \begin{document}
%       ...
%       \bibliography{bibliography-file}
 %       \bibliographystyle{acl}
 %       \end{document}

% Author information can be set in various styles:
% For several authors from the same institution:
% \author{Author 1 \and ... \and Author n \\
%         Address line \\ ... \\ Address line}
% if the names do not fit well on one line use
%         Author 1 \\ {\bf Author 2} \\ ... \\ {\bf Author n} \\
% For authors from different institutions:
% \author{Author 1 \\ Address line \\  ... \\ Address line
%         \And  ... \And
%         Author n \\ Address line \\ ... \\ Address line}
% To start a seperate ``row'' of authors use \AND, as in
% \author{Author 1 \\ Address line \\  ... \\ Address line
%         \AND
%         Author 2 \\ Address line \\ ... \\ Address line \And
%         Author 3 \\ Address line \\ ... \\ Address line}

% If the title and author information does not fit in the area allocated,
% place \setlength\titlebox{<new height>} right after
% \usepackage{coling2018}
% where <new height> can be something larger than 5cm

\typeout{Conference Style for COLING 2018 -- prepared 15th Oct. 2017}

% NOTE:  Some laser printers have a serious problem printing TeX output.
% These printing devices, commonly known as ``write-white'' laser
% printers, tend to make characters too light.  To get around this
% problem, a darker set of fonts must be created for these devices.
%



% A4 modified by Eneko; again modified by Alexander for 5cm titlebox
\setlength{\paperwidth}{21cm}   % A4
\setlength{\paperheight}{29.7cm}% A4
\setlength\topmargin{-0.5cm}    
\setlength\oddsidemargin{0cm}   
\setlength\textheight{24.7cm} 
\setlength\textwidth{16.0cm}
\setlength\columnsep{0.6cm}  
\newlength\titlebox 
\setlength\titlebox{5cm}
\setlength\headheight{5pt}   
\setlength\headsep{0pt}
\thispagestyle{empty}        
\pagestyle{empty}


\flushbottom \sloppy

% We're never going to need a table of contents, so just flush it to
% save space --- suggested by drstrip@sandia-2
\def\addcontentsline#1#2#3{}

% Footnote without marker for copyright/licence statement
% Code taken from
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30720/footnote-without-a-marker
% which claims to have taken it, in turn, from
% http://help-csli.stanford.edu/tex/latex-footnotes.shtml#unnumber
% Note the comment that there may be numbering problems if
% you are using the hyperref package. 
\def\blfootnote{\xdef\@thefnmark{}\@footnotetext}

% Title stuff, taken from deproc.
\def\maketitle{\par
% \vbox to 0.5\textheight\bgroup
 \begingroup
   \def\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
   \def\@makefnmark{\hbox to 0pt{$^{\@thefnmark}$\hss}}
   \@maketitle \@thanks
 \endgroup
 \setcounter{footnote}{0}
 \let\maketitle\relax \let\@maketitle\relax
  \gdef\@thanks{}\gdef\@author{}\gdef\@title{}\let\thanks\relax}
\def\@maketitle{\vbox to \titlebox{\hsize\textwidth
 \linewidth\hsize \vskip 0.125in minus 0.125in \centering
 {\Large\bf \@title \par} \vskip 0.2in plus 1fil minus 0.1in
 {\def\and{\unskip\enspace{\rm and}\enspace}%
  \def\And{\end{tabular}\hss \egroup \hskip 1in plus 2fil 
           \hbox to 0pt\bgroup\hss \begin{tabular}[t]{c}\bf}%
  \def\AND{\end{tabular}\hss\egroup \hfil\hfil\egroup
         \vskip 0.25in plus 1fil minus 0.125in
           \hbox to \linewidth\bgroup\large \hfil\hfil
              \hbox to 0pt\bgroup\hss \begin{tabular}[t]{c}\bf}
   \hbox to \linewidth\bgroup\large \hfil\hfil
    \hbox to 0pt\bgroup\hss \begin{tabular}[t]{c}\bf\@author 
                             \end{tabular}\hss\egroup
    \hfil\hfil\egroup}
  \vskip 0.3in plus 2fil minus 0.1in
 }}

% margins for abstract
\renewenvironment{abstract}%
         {\centerline{\large\bf Abstract}%
          \begin{list}{}%
             {\setlength{\rightmargin}{0.6cm}%
              \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.6cm}}%
           \item[]\ignorespaces}%
         {\unskip\end{list}%
          % \egroup%
          }


\newcommand{\slname}[1]{\def\@slname{#1}}
\newcommand{\sltitle}[1]{\def\@sltitle{#1}}

\def\makesltitle{\par
 \centerline{\large\bf Title and Abstract in \@slname}%
 \let\@slname\relax\vskip 10pt
 \centerline{\@sltitle}%
 \let\makesltitle\relax
 \gdef\@sltitle{}}


 \newenvironment{slabstract}%
     {\begin{list}{}%
         {\setlength{\rightmargin}{0.6cm}%
          \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.6cm}}%
       \item[]\ignorespaces}%
     {\unskip\end{list}}

%\renewenvironment{abstract}{\centerline{\large\bf  
% Abstract}\vspace{0.5ex}\begin{quote}}{\par\end{quote}\vskip 1ex}


% bibliography

\def\thebibliography#1{\section*{References}
  \global\def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
               \labelwidth\leftmargini \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
               \topsep 1pt plus 2pt minus 1pt
               \parsep 0.25ex plus 1pt \itemsep 0.25ex plus 1pt}
  \list {[\arabic{enumi}]} 
 {\settowidth\labelwidth{[#1]}\leftmargin\labelwidth
    \advance\leftmargin\labelsep\usecounter{enumi}}
    \def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus -.07em}
    \sloppy
    \sfcode`\.=1000\relax}

\def\@up#1{\raise.2ex\hbox{#1}}

% most of cite format is from aclsub.sty by SMS

% don't box citations, separate with ; and a space
% also, make the penalty between citations negative: a good place to break
% changed comma back to semicolon pj 2/1/90
% 
\def\@citex[#1]#2{\if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{#2}}\fi
% \def\@citea{}\@cite{\@for\@citeb:=#2\do
%   {\@citea\def\@citea{;\penalty\@citeseppen\ }\@ifundefined
%      {b@\@citeb}{{\bf ?}\@warning
%      {Citation `\@citeb' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
% {\csname b@\@citeb\endcsname}}}{#1}}

% don't box citations, separate with ; and a space
% Replaced for multiple citations (pj) 
% don't box citations and also add space, semicolon between multiple citations

\def\@citex[#1]#2{\if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{#2}}\fi
  \def\@citea{}\@cite{\@for\@citeb:=#2\do
     {\@citea\def\@citea{; }\@ifundefined
       {b@\@citeb}{{\bf ?}\@warning
        {Citation `\@citeb' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
 {\csname b@\@citeb\endcsname}}}{#1}}

% Allow short (name-less) citations, when used in
% conjunction with a bibliography style that creates labels like
%       \citename{<names>, }<year>
% 
\let\@internalcite\cite
\def\cite{\def\citename##1{##1, }\@internalcite}
\def\shortcite{\def\citename##1{}\@internalcite}
\def\newcite{\def\citename##1{{\frenchspacing##1} (}\@internalciteb}

% Macros for \newcite, which leaves name in running text, and is
% otherwise like \shortcite.



\def\@citexb[#1]#2{\if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{#2}}\fi

  \def\@citea{}\@newcite{\@for\@citeb:=#2\do
    {\@citea\def\@citea{;\penalty\@m\ }\@ifundefined
       {b@\@citeb}{{\bf ?}\@warning
       {Citation `\@citeb' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
{\csname b@\@citeb\endcsname}}}{#1}}
\def\@internalciteb{\@ifnextchar [{\@tempswatrue\@citexb} 
{\@tempswafalse\@citexb[]}}

\def\@newcite#1#2{{#1\if@tempswa, #2\fi)}}

\def\@biblabel#1{\def\citename##1{##1}[#1]\hfill}

%%% More changes made by SMS (originals in latex.tex)
% Use parentheses instead of square brackets in the text.
\def\@cite#1#2{({#1\if@tempswa , #2\fi})}

% Don't put a label in the bibliography at all.  Just use the unlabeled format
 % instead.
\def\thebibliography#1{\vskip\parskip%
\vskip\baselineskip%
\def\baselinestretch{1}%
\ifx\@currsize\normalsize\@normalsize\else\@currsize\fi%
\vskip-\parskip%
\vskip-\baselineskip%
\section*{References\@mkboth
 {References}{References}}\list
 {}{\setlength{\labelwidth}{0pt}\setlength{\leftmargin}{\parindent}
 \setlength{\itemindent}{-\parindent}}
 \def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus -.07em}
 \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000
 \sfcode`\.=1000\relax}
\let\endthebibliography=\endlist

% Allow for a bibliography of sources of attested examples
\def\thesourcebibliography#1{\vskip\parskip%
\vskip\baselineskip%
\def\baselinestretch{1}%
\ifx\@currsize\normalsize\@normalsize\else\@currsize\fi%
\vskip-\parskip%
\vskip-\baselineskip%
 \section*{Sources of Attested Examples\@mkboth
 {Sources of Attested Examples}{Sources of Attested Examples}}\list
 {}{\setlength{\labelwidth}{0pt}\setlength{\leftmargin}{\parindent}
 \setlength{\itemindent}{-\parindent}}
 \def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus -.07em}
 \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000
 \sfcode`\.=1000\relax}
\let\endthesourcebibliography=\endlist

\def\@lbibitem[#1]#2{\item[]\if@filesw 
      { \def\protect##1{\string ##1\space}\immediate
        \write\@auxout{\string\bibcite{#2}{#1}}\fi\ignorespaces}}

\def\@bibitem#1{\item\if@filesw \immediate\write\@auxout
       {\string\bibcite{#1}{\the\c@enumi}}\fi\ignorespaces}

% sections with less space
\def\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}{-2.0ex plus
    -0.5ex minus -.2ex}{1.5ex plus 0.3ex minus .2ex}{\large\bf\raggedright}}
\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}{-1.8ex plus
    -0.5ex minus -.2ex}{0.8ex plus .2ex}{\normalsize\bf\raggedright}}
%% changed by KO to - values to get teh initial parindent right
\def\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}{-1.5ex plus
   -0.5ex minus -.2ex}{0.5ex plus .2ex}{\normalsize\bf\raggedright}}
\def\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}{1.5ex plus
   0.5ex minus .2ex}{-1em}{\normalsize\bf}}
\def\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\parindent}{1.5ex plus
   0.5ex minus .2ex}{-1em}{\normalsize\bf}}

% Footnotes
\footnotesep 6.65pt %
\skip\footins 9pt plus 4pt minus 2pt
\def\footnoterule{\kern-3pt \hrule width 5pc \kern 2.6pt }
\setcounter{footnote}{0}

% Lists and paragraphs
\parindent 1em
\topsep 4pt plus 1pt minus 2pt
\partopsep 1pt plus 0.5pt minus 0.5pt
\itemsep 2pt plus 1pt minus 0.5pt
\parsep 2pt plus 1pt minus 0.5pt

\leftmargin 2em \leftmargini\leftmargin \leftmarginii 2em
\leftmarginiii 1.5em \leftmarginiv 1.0em \leftmarginv .5em \leftmarginvi .5em
\labelwidth\leftmargini\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep \labelsep 5pt

\def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini}
\def\@listii{\leftmargin\leftmarginii
   \labelwidth\leftmarginii\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
   \topsep 2pt plus 1pt minus 0.5pt
   \parsep 1pt plus 0.5pt minus 0.5pt
   \itemsep \parsep}
\def\@listiii{\leftmargin\leftmarginiii
    \labelwidth\leftmarginiii\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
    \topsep 1pt plus 0.5pt minus 0.5pt 
    \parsep \z@ \partopsep 0.5pt plus 0pt minus 0.5pt
    \itemsep \topsep}
\def\@listiv{\leftmargin\leftmarginiv
     \labelwidth\leftmarginiv\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep}
\def\@listv{\leftmargin\leftmarginv
     \labelwidth\leftmarginv\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep}
\def\@listvi{\leftmargin\leftmarginvi
     \labelwidth\leftmarginvi\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep}

\abovedisplayskip 7pt plus2pt minus5pt%
\belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
\abovedisplayshortskip  0pt plus3pt%   
\belowdisplayshortskip  4pt plus3pt minus3pt%

% Less leading in most fonts (due to the narrow columns)
% The choices were between 1-pt and 1.5-pt leading
\def\@normalsize{\@setsize\normalsize{11pt}\xpt\@xpt}
\def\small{\@setsize\small{10pt}\ixpt\@ixpt}
\def\footnotesize{\@setsize\footnotesize{10pt}\ixpt\@ixpt}
\def\scriptsize{\@setsize\scriptsize{8pt}\viipt\@viipt}
\def\tiny{\@setsize\tiny{7pt}\vipt\@vipt}
\def\large{\@setsize\large{14pt}\xiipt\@xiipt}
\def\Large{\@setsize\Large{16pt}\xivpt\@xivpt}
\def\LARGE{\@setsize\LARGE{20pt}\xviipt\@xviipt}
\def\huge{\@setsize\huge{23pt}\xxpt\@xxpt}
\def\Huge{\@setsize\Huge{28pt}\xxvpt\@xxvpt}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cyrillic glyphs use the T2A font encoding instead of the default T1 (or OT1) for Roman glyphs. However, the T2A version of the Times font does not provide bold, italic, or typewriter glyphs, so when T2A is used as the default encoding, the `\bf` commands don’t work.

---

One solution to the problem is to not use T2A as the default encoding. This is done with the `fontenc` package while using a specific order of package parameters. Here you need to put T2A before T1, because LaTeX treats the last encoding as the default one. So, put the following in your preamble:

```
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
```

Whenever Cyrillic characters are needed, put them in a separate group (i.e. in brackets) and temporarily switch the encoding, like this:

```
\begin{slabstract}
    \fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont  % add this line here
    Русский.
\end{slabstract}
```

---

Another solution is to substitute the default T2A font with another one that looks like Times but do provide bold glyphs. The `Tempora-TLF` font is a nice substitute. Font substitution can be performed with the `substitutefont` package, just add the following to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{substitutefont}
\substitutefont{T2A}{\familydefault}{Tempora-TLF}
```

The only problem is that it does not provide typewriter fonts so the author emails look strange. But this solution can be combined with the one above, which gives you the correct format and bold Cyrillic glyphs when you need them.

---

Credits:

1. [How does LaTeX know which of multiple loaded output encodings to use?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73849/how-does-latex-know-which-of-multiple-loaded-output-encodings-to-use)
2. [Italic Cyrillic in Times](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241096/italic-cyrillic-in-times)

Answer (score 1):

If at all possible, use the modern toolchain with XeTeX or LuaTeX.  In Babel, you would want to wrap short phrases in Russian with `\foreignlanguage{russian}{...}` and longer passages in Russian with `\begin{otherlanguage}{russian}...\end{otherlanguage}`.

I also re-enabled Chinese without CJKutf8.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[russian, english]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{coling2018}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{arydshln}

% Babel 3.22 has a bug where it does not pass fontspec the correct Script =
% or Language = options for some languages.  This workaround overrides it.
\babelprovide[script=CJK, language={Chinese Simplified}]{chinese-simplified}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchUppercase, Ligatures=TeX}
\babelfont{rm}[Scale=1.0]{Times New Roman}
\babelfont[chinese-simplified]{rm}{Noto Serif CJK SC}

\raggedbottom

\newcommand\BibTeX{B{\sc ib}\TeX}

\title{Paper Title}

\slname{Russian}

\sltitle{\foreignlanguage{russian}{русский}}

 \author{Author 1 \\
  University 1/ City, State \\
  Department \\
  {\tt email@uni1.edu} \\ \And
  Author 2 \\
  University 1/ City, State \\
  Department  \\
  {\tt email@uni2.edu} \\}

\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
  English abstract
\end{abstract}

\makesltitle
\begin{slabstract}
  COLING-2018
  \foreignlanguage{chinese-simplified}{格}
  \foreignlanguage{russian}{русский}
\end{slabstract}

\section{Introduction}
Text of the Introduction...

\end{document}
```

[image: Times New Roman/Noto Serif CJK SC sample]

This allows you to set your font to any desktop font.  (You could also select different fonts for English and Russian, and have them scale automatically.)  I went with Times New Roman for English and Russian, since it supports Cyrillic, and Noto Serif CJK SC for simplified Chinese.  I also went ahead and added `microtype`, which should work better for you in LuaLaTeX than XeLaTeX.

I did need to fix an apparent error with the definition of `@citex` in `coling2018.sty`.

Another option is to use `polyglossia` instead of `babel`.

If you are forced to use PDFTeX and the legacy 8-bit fonts, you must load the T2A encoding and a Times-compatible Cyrillic font, such as Tempora.  (This is similar to Zecong Hu’s answer.)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T2A, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % The default since 2018
\usepackage[russian, english]{babel}
\usepackage{substitutefont}
\usepackage{tempora}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{coling2018}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\substitutefont{T2A}{\rmdefault}{Tempora-TLF} % use Tempora to render Russian

\raggedbottom

\newcommand\BibTeX{B{\sc ib}\TeX}

\title{Paper Title}

\slname{Russian}

\sltitle{\foreignlanguage{russian}{русский}}

 \author{Author 1 \\
  University 1/ City, State \\
  Department \\
  {\tt email@uni1.edu} \\ \And
  Author 2 \\
  University 1/ City, State \\
  Department  \\
  {\tt email@uni2.edu} \\}

\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
  English abstract
\end{abstract}

\makesltitle
\begin{slabstract}
  \begin{otherlanguage}{russian}
  русский
  \end{otherlanguage}
\end{slabstract}

\section{Introduction}
Text of the Introduction...

\end{document}
```

[image: Tempora font sample]