# Left handed writing

Tags: fonts, italic, italic-correction

Is there a way in LaTeX, which would make some text look like it has been written by a left hander. In italic fonts, is there a distinction between left handed and right handed writing(you can visualize what i am trying to say)?

Comment: In case this means that you believe that left handed writing is slanted to the left: That's wrong.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer is correct that left-handers should not, by convention, slant cursive writing to the left.  However, it is not particularly uncommon amongst lefties to do so anyway.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes - Some righties have hand-writing that slopes to the left...

Comment: an actual font that has this tendency is `cmu` -- computer modern "upright italic".  it's not slanted to the left, but has the italic lettershapes with an upright orientation.  in tugboat, it's used for the headers for "editor's notes", and for this reason is called `\EdNoteFont`; can be tried out with `\documentclass{ltugboat}`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**REVISED ANSWER USING A TOKEN CYCLE**

Here, I revise my original answer (see below) to process the character iteration inside a token cycle (`tokcycle` package).  This allows an easier definition for the user as well as preserving functionality inside groups, such as `\textbf` as shown in the MWE.  It also handles paragraph breaks seamlessly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{emerald,tokcycle}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newsavebox\foobox
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][.5]{\mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
}}

\newcommand\currentslant{-.7}

\newcommand\chariterate[2][\currentslant]{%
  \begingroup
  \resettokcycle%
  \Characterdirective{\addcytoks{\slantbox[#1]{##1}}}%
  \tokcyclexpress{#2}%
  \the\cytoks
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
Let us check the slanting token cycle.

\chariterate[-.4]{Let us see if it \textbf{works in bold}?}

Now let us do it in a handwriting font!

\ECFSkeetch
If my goal is to make something look like actual handwritten text,
then this might suffice.\par
\chariterate{While not technically correct, some left handers will
slant their handwriting to the left, anyway.  Let's see if this works in multiline?

And let us also see if it works in a separate paragraph?}

\chariterate[.2]{Extra right slant}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

1st paragraph is normal slant handwriting, while the second is leftward slant handwriting.

By convention, left-slant handwriting is not taught (and therefore it does not exist in pre-defined fonts), but a number of lefties and (as Mico notes) some righties adopt the style in their handwriting.

Here, I implement a character iteration scheme, where `\charop{}` is applied to each character of the sentence (the iteration is needed to allow line-breaking of the result).  I define `\charop` to employ Bruno's `\slantbox` code ([Shear transform a "box"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63179/shear-transform-a-box/63188#63188)) to take the hand-written character and slant it leftward.  The slant value may be changed with `\renewcommand\currentslant{}`.

EDITED to correct parsing when encountering a letter repetition in the input.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{emerald}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newsavebox\foobox
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][.5]{\mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
}}
\newcommand\chariterate[2][c]{\chariteratehelpA#2 \relax\relax}
\def\chariteratehelpA#1 #2\relax{%
  \chariteratehelpB#1\relax\relax%
  \ifx\relax#2\else\ \chariteratehelpA#2\relax\fi
}
\def\chariteratehelpB#1#2\relax{%
  \charop{#1}%
  \ifx\relax#2\else
    \chariteratehelpB#2\relax%
  \fi
}
\def\currentslant{-.7}
\def\charop#1{\slantbox[\currentslant]{#1}}
\begin{document}
\ECFSkeetch
If my goal is to make something look like actual handwritten text,
then this might suffice.\par
\chariterate{While not technically correct, some left handers will
slant their handwriting to the left, anyway.  Let's see if this works in multiline?}\par
%\renewcommand\currentslant{.2}
%\chariterate{Extra right slant}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

And here it is using a different, less scratchy, font (and slight adjustments on default slant)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{aurical}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newsavebox\foobox
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][.5]{\mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
}}
\newcommand\chariterate[2][c]{\chariteratehelpA#2 \relax\relax}
\def\chariteratehelpA#1 #2\relax{%
  \chariteratehelpB#1\relax\relax%
  \ifx\relax#2\else\ \chariteratehelpA#2\relax\fi
}
\def\chariteratehelpB#1#2\relax{%
  \charop{#1}%
  \ifx\relax#2\else
    \chariteratehelpB#2\relax%
  \fi
}
\def\currentslant{-.6}
\def\charop#1{\slantbox[\currentslant]{#1}}
\begin{document}
\Fontskrivan\slshape
If my goal is to make something look like actual handwritten text,
then this might suffice.\par
\chariterate{While not technically correct, some left handers will
slant their handwriting to the left, anyway.  Let's see if this works in multiline?}\par
\renewcommand\currentslant{.2}
\chariterate{Extra rightward slant.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ Steven Thanks for providing this solution. I am sure that just by changing the sign in the \slantbox[] command, we can reverse the slant direction. Is that right?

Comment: @maulik If you want normal text, just avoid the `\chariterate` altogether.  But indeed, if one sets the slant value positive, it will slant even more to the right than what it started at.

Comment: @maulik Please see my revision, in which I introduce `\currentslant` as a definition.  By changing the value of that, you can affect the slant.