# Adding random padding/rotation into texts so it gives it a handwriting feel

Tags: fonts, fontspec

[image: example of handwriting font which is what we want to applicate]
The image above is of an handwriting example, it shows the random font size and the random padding/rotation between them.

[image: example of latex texts]

The image above is an example of a LaTeX generated texts.

How can I make my LaTeX document use random paddings and rotation like the first image? Other tips about how to make it look more like a handwriting would be greatly appreciated too, thanks.

I use macOS and XeTeX.

Comment: These questions might give you some ideas: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245751/left-handed-writing and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317190/handwritten-comments-and-annotations-in-margin

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/344272/2388