# Is there a good reason to switch to the 2022 version of TeXLive? Some things aren't working, it seems

Tags: page-breaking, overleaf

I am using overleaf with PDFLaTeX and I get  ``` ``undefined control sequence'' ``` as in the following answered question.  ['Undefined control sequence' error when writing \newpage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/633344/undefined-control-sequence-error-when-writing-newpage). I've used this same kind of code many times before with no problem, in and out of overleaf, but today it's giving me fits.  Every variant of page break command that I try today fails and gives me this error message.  I can only fix it by changing to a legacy version of TexLive (I switched to the 2018 version and it works).

Is there a good reason to switch to the 2022 version?  When I started writing this question, I was not aware that the default had been changed to the new version so my question was going to be something like ``The solution in that answered question does not work for me because I'm already using PDFLaTeX, so what should I do now?''  I changed my question when I found out by a last-minute check that some of my old documents were using the legacy version of TeXLive and now the latest new project in Overleaf defaults to the 2022 version.  If I switch, what must I do to my legacy documents to make them work in the 2022 version, specifically in terms of page breaks?

Comment: the vast majority of documents will work unchanged. If you get an error show the input and the error you get.

Comment: A version of TeX Live not only includes the kernel and the compilers, but also specific versions of all packages from that year. Therefore your problem could also be caused by a package that has introduced a backwards incompatibility somewhere during the last four years. However, this is one of the reasons to use the latest version: when you find a problem with a legacy document, it should be reported in order for unintended backwards incompatibilities in the kernel or in packages to be fixed.

Comment: Of course it may be the case that a package author intentionally deprecates a feature or changes details of the syntax. Sometimes you can easily modify existing documents to use the new syntax, but in other cases this would be a lot of work - for those cases using a legacy version may of course be a viable option.