# How to produce a 3D-like commutative diagram using xymatrix?

Tags: xy-pic

Could somebody give an idea how to create the following 3D commutative diagram?
[image]

Comment: Welcome! Please post the code you've got so far. Right now, this is just another do-it-for-me. You may get lucky. Or you may not. If you can make your diagrammatic needs cuter and more visually appealing (e.g. include a small dragon or a large duck), you may stand a better chance. However, you may also get only the dragons and ducks, so this might be a problem if they are not the main focus of your work. I recommend specialising in dragon-duck interactions for maximum do-it-for-me yields. Otherwise, a Minimum Working Example is the way to go. Why do you need `xy-pic` especially?

Comment: Are you only looking for a `xy-pic` solution?

Comment: Any other solution as convenient as the xy-pic one is welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `tikz` based solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,row sep=2em,column sep=4em]{
     & S(n) & S(n) & \cdots\\
TM   &      &      &       \\
     &      \mathfrak{X}(n, n+q) & \mathfrak{X}(n, n+q+1) & \cdots\\
M    &      &      &       \\};
\path[-stealth]
(m-2-1) edge (m-1-2);  
\path[-stealth]
(m-1-2) edge (m-1-3);
\path[-stealth]
(m-1-3) edge (m-1-4);
\path[-stealth]
(m-4-1) edge (m-3-2);  
\path[-stealth]
(m-3-2) edge (m-3-3);
\path[-stealth]
(m-3-3) edge (m-3-4);
\path[-stealth]
(m-2-1) edge (m-4-1);
\path[-stealth]
(m-1-2) edge (m-3-2);
\path[-stealth]
(m-1-3) edge (m-3-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

You can simplify this even using one `\path`. See an example [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/commutative-diagram/).

---

[EDITED by Steven B. Segletes to add `\slantbox` feature from [Shear transform a "box"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63179/shear-transform-a-box/63188#63188])

For 3-D effect, one can use Bruno's `\slantbox`.  Note in this case, for the isometric effect, the optional argument to `\slantbox` is the tangent of the rotation angle.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\newsavebox\foobox
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][.2]{\mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,row sep=2em,column sep=4em]{
     & S(n) & S(n) & \cdots\\
\rotatebox{25}{\slantbox[.466]{TM}}   &      &      &       \\
     &      \mathfrak{X}(n, n+q) & \mathfrak{X}(n, n+q+1) & \cdots\\
\rotatebox{25}{\slantbox[.466]{M}}    &      &      &       \\};
\path[-stealth]
(m-2-1) edge (m-1-2);  
\path[-stealth]
(m-1-2) edge (m-1-3);
\path[-stealth]
(m-1-3) edge (m-1-4);
\path[-stealth]
(m-4-1) edge (m-3-2);  
\path[-stealth]
(m-3-2) edge (m-3-3);
\path[-stealth]
(m-3-3) edge (m-3-4);
\path[-stealth]
(m-2-1) edge (m-4-1);
\path[-stealth]
(m-1-2) edge (m-3-2);
\path[-stealth]
(m-1-3) edge (m-3-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I added a 3-D supplement to your answer.  If you don't like it, you or I can roll it back to your prior posting.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Its a pleasure :-)

Comment: OMG, there is even 3D effect!  That is more than what I am looking for!  Many thanks for your answer and I am so impressed by your TeX skills!

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to use four rows, reducing the spacing between rows.

Take your pick among Xy-pic and `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

This is the diagram using Xy-pic
\[
\xymatrix@R-.8pc{
  & S(n) \ar[rr] \ar[dd] && S(n) \ar[rr] \ar[dd] && \cdots \\
T(M) \ar[ur] \ar[dd] \\
  & \mathcal{X}(n,n+q) \ar[rr] && \mathcal{X}(n,n+q+1) \ar[rr] && \cdots \\
M \ar[ur]
}
\]

This is the diagram using tikz-cd
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=4ex]
  & S(n) \arrow[rr] \arrow[dd] && S(n) \arrow[rr] \arrow[dd] && \cdots \\
T(M) \arrow[ur] \arrow[dd] \\
  & \mathcal{X}(n,n+q) \arrow[rr] && \mathcal{X}(n,n+q+1) \arrow[rr] && \cdots \\
M \arrow[ur]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks great even though it is not really 3D diagram.  But the trick greatly reduces the amount of coding!  Many thanks!  And I also appreciate very much the comparison!