# A particular big Delta

Tags: symbols, greek

I would like to insert the below mathematical symbol, it looks like a big Delta but different. Is there command to obtain a similar shape?

[image]

Comment: It seems to be a big delta in italics. Have you tried detexify?

Comment: @TeXnician, after your comment, I tried it but it only gives variants of the ordinary big Delta which are all like equilateral triangles. But the above image look likes  very near to a right triangle (but not exactly). The below solution of c.p. is very near.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is the following Greek character: `\varDelta`. It requieres `amsmath`.

Comment: Thank this is very near, however I have the impression that the right side of the triangle in the image is more upright. Hence let me wait a little bit for possible alternative solutions before accepting your answer.

Comment: Sure.  The angles could be font-dependent as well.

Answer (score 8):

Pick your own desired slant, using Bruno's `\slantbox`, given at [Shear transform a "box"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63179/shear-transform-a-box/63188#63188) (pdflatex only)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newsavebox\foobox
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][.5]{\mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
}}
\begin{document}
$\Delta \varDelta $ versus $
\slantbox[.4]{$\Delta$}
\slantbox[.45]{$\Delta$}
\slantbox[.5]{$\Delta$}
\slantbox[.55]{$\Delta$}
\slantbox[.6]{$\Delta$}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]