# How to Create an A without horizontal bar

Tags: symbols, math-operators

I am currently writing about limit sets of Fuchsian Groups and the source that I'm using uses a Symbol for this, that looks Like an A without the horizontal bar.
So let \Gamma be a Fuchsian Group then A(\Gamma) is the limit set.

I know, that I can just define it to be any other symbol, but I'd like to know how to add this symbol to my repertoire.

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't is just `\Lambda`?

Comment: You are right LMAO. Im stupid, thank you. 
But would there be a way to manipulate an existing symbol like this? Just in case i would like to add another symbol.

Comment: Since symbols that get typeset come from the font itself, it is not always easy.  You have subtractive methods, where some part of an existing glyph has to be clipped, or overwritten (in white), or you have additive methods, where two or more glyphs can be combined to form something newer.  Of these methods, the additive is generally easier and preferred.  p.s.  The irony of your name = @Lambda is funny, given the question.

Comment: I guess there is actually a third method, where an existing glyph can be transformed by way of scale/stretch/shift or other distortion, to achieve a new result.  There are questions for all types on this site.  Tools at your disposal include `\ooalign`, packages `tikz`, `stackengine`, `trimclip`.  Also pdf specials can be useful, e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/a-particular-big-delta/369041#369041

Comment: When looking for a symbol I always go to https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

In this case, I found `\textturnv` from the `tipa` package, for instance, along with `\wedge`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was answered in the comments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to look up a symbol or identify a letter from a math alphabet or other character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-letter-from-a-math-alphabet-or-other-chara)