# How to skew (slant) a box with the graphics/graphicx package?

Tags: graphics, pdf, postscript

In the `graphics`/`graphicx` packages there are commands `\rotatebox`, `\resizebox`, `\scalebox` and even `\reflectbox`. But how can I slant/skew something in the same way? (I'm missing a `\skewbox` command.)

(Incidentally I looked in the PostScript manual (736 pages). The word "slant" never appears in it, and the word "skew" appears three times, one of them in the sentence "The operators in this group manipulate the CTM to achieve any combination of translation, scaling, rotation, reflection, and skewing of user coordinates onto device coordinates", which proves that at some time some Adobe engineer thought of skewing, but in fact never documented it or wrote any code. Fortunately in the PDF manual version 1.7 there is mention of skewing and even an illustration, on page 118 (the transformation matrix is `[1 tan a tan b 1 0 0]`, I'm interested in horizontal skewing, so that *a* is 0), so this time Adobe took it seriously. How come this operator has never been included in `graphicx`? or maybe I overlooked it? Is it because there is no "native" PostScript support for it?)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63179/shear-transform-a-box/63188#63188

Comment: Incredible! `tex.stackexchange` has become like Borges' infinite library: for every question there is already an answer. Thanks David, once again! (*some day I will have to send you a chocolate box, there should be a button for that in StackExchange “physically send chocolate box”*)

Comment: Skews can be decomposed into rotations and scalings

Comment: I have used that linked answer so many times...you can see from all the "Linked" questions in the right-hand column of that answer.  It is truly a great answer!