# How to insert an image under a graph in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

How a sample map figure could be inserted under the graph in Tikz like below:
[image]

The below code plots the 3d coordination.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[x={(20,0)},y={(0,20),z={(0,20)}},z={({-20/sqrt(6)},{-20/sqrt(8)})},
grid = both,minor tick num=1,xmin=0,xmax=14,ymin=0,ymax=.01,zmin=0,zmax=17,
ticks=none,clip=false,tick style={opacity=0}]

\draw[-latex, >=latex,  thick] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,18) node[left]{};
\draw[-latex, >=latex,  thick] (0,0,0) -- (15,0,0) node[below]{};
\draw[-latex, >=latex,  thick] (0,0,0) -- (0,8,0) node[left]{};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63179/shear-transform-a-box

Comment: Yes, Thank you!