# Make up Greek font italic

Tags: packages, greek, italic, txfonts

I am using the command \upvarphi in the package TXfonts, which provides a rather old fashioned variant of Greek letter phi. I uploaded the picture here. The result is nice, but it seems that it is not italic.
I would like to know is it possible to change the definition of this character (as a new character) to make it italic?
This is the definition of this character as I found in the .sty file of the package TXfonts:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{lettersA}{U}{txmia}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{lettersA}{bold}{U}{txmia}{bx}{it}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{txmia}{m}{it}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\varphiup}{\mathord}{lettersA}{39}
```

[image]

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I know what up means in upvarphi. I'm looking for a (font for) \varphi that looks like this this picture in italic. The usual \varphi looks rather different.

Comment: If all else fails, you can [apply a shear transform.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63179/shear-transform-a-box/63188#63188)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I know \varphi. Honestly, I just temped to have an old fashioned varphi in the text of my thesis, as it found currently in somewhere yet. But all my tries almost failed. This is much more like what I want, but it is not italic. The middle one you mentioned is very common. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Davislor what a cool method!

Comment: As @Davislor notes, the shear transform can be used.  You can do the exact reverse of this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145926/upright-greek-font-fitting-to-computer-modern/230220#230220